# Hidden features of Python

Tags: python, hidden-features

What are the lesser-known but useful features of the Python programming language?

- Try to limit answers to Python core.
- One feature per answer.
- Give an example and short description of the feature, not just a link to documentation.
- Label the feature using a title as the first line.

### Quick links to answers:

- [Argument Unpacking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#111176)
- [Braces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#112303)
- [Chaining Comparison Operators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101945)
- [Decorators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101447)
- [Default Argument Gotchas / Dangers of Mutable Default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113198)
- [Descriptors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#102062)
- [Dictionary default `.get` value](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#111970)
- [Docstring Tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#102065)
- [Ellipsis Slicing Syntax](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/112316#112316)
- [Enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#117116)
- [For/else](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#114420)
- [Function as iter() argument](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#102202)
- [Generator expressions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101310)
- [`import this`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101276)
- [In Place Value Swapping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#102037)
- [List stepping](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101840)
- [`__missing__` items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#112286)
- [Multi-line Regex](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101537)
- [Named string formatting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113164)
- [Nested list/generator comprehensions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101549)
- [New types at runtime](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#108297)
- [`.pth` files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113833)
- [ROT13 Encoding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#1024693)
- [Regex Debugging](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#143636)
- [Sending to Generators](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101739)
- [Tab Completion in Interactive Interpreter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#168270)
- [Ternary Expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#116480)
- [`try/except/else`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#114157)
- [Unpacking+`print()` function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#3267903)
- [`with` statement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#109182)

Answer (score 739):

### Chaining comparison operators:

```
>>> x = 5
>>> 1 < x < 10
True
>>> 10 < x < 20 
False
>>> x < 10 < x*10 < 100
True
>>> 10 > x <= 9
True
>>> 5 == x > 4
True
```

In case you're thinking it's doing `1 < x`, which comes out as `True`, and then comparing `True < 10`, which is also `True`, then no, that's really not what happens (see the last example.) It's really translating into `1 < x and x < 10`, and `x < 10 and 10 < x * 10 and x*10 < 100`, but with less typing and each term is only evaluated once.

Comment: Isn't `10 > x <= 9` the same as `x <= 9` (ignoring overloaded operators, that is)

Comment: Of course. It was just an example of mixing different operators.

Comment: This applies to other comparison operators as well, which is why people are sometimes surprised why code like (5 in [5] is True) is False (but it's unpythonic to explicitly test against booleans like that to begin with).

Comment: Lisp does not have anything similar?

Comment: Not that I know of.  Perl 6 does have this feature, though :)

Comment: Good but watch out for equal prcedence, like 'in' and '='.   'A in B == C in D' means '(A in B) and (B == C) and (C in D)' which might be unexpected.

Comment: Azafe: Lisp's comparisons naturally work this way.  It's not a special case because there's no other (reasonable) way to interpret `(< 1 x 10)`.  You can even apply them to single arguments, like `(= 10)`: http://www.cs.cmu.edu/Groups/AI/html/hyperspec/HyperSpec/Body/fun_eqcm_sleq__lteqcm_gteq.html

Comment: @Miles a less confusing example might be "a == b in c" which is equivalent to "a == b and b in c".  See  http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#notin

Comment: @Charles Merriam for me its not unexpected, just logical. Although its ugly to use `A in B == C in D`.

Comment: This is also great for tests.  You can do `a == b == c`, and it will return True only if all three items are equal.

Comment: `is not` and `not in` are similarly surprisingly good too. Apparently `is not` is **1** binary operator, not a binary and then a unary. `not in` is the same too. This makes code like `'foo' is not 'bar'` so much more readable.

Comment: Ken: I like Python's version better than Lisp's, since it allows for mixing different kinds of comparisons, such as a <= b < c. Mathematica, which is more or a dialect of Lisp, does allow you to use different comparisons --it uses what would in Lisp syntax be (inequality a '<= b '< c).

Answer (score 511):

**Get the python regex parse tree to debug your regex.**

Regular expressions are a great feature of python, but debugging them can be a pain, and it's all too easy to get a regex wrong.

Fortunately, python can print the regex parse tree, by passing the undocumented, experimental, hidden flag `re.DEBUG` (actually, 128) to `re.compile`.

```
>>> re.compile("^\[font(?:=(?P<size>[-+][0-9]{1,2}))?\](.*?)[/font]",
    re.DEBUG)
at at_beginning
literal 91
literal 102
literal 111
literal 110
literal 116
max_repeat 0 1
  subpattern None
    literal 61
    subpattern 1
      in
        literal 45
        literal 43
      max_repeat 1 2
        in
          range (48, 57)
literal 93
subpattern 2
  min_repeat 0 65535
    any None
in
  literal 47
  literal 102
  literal 111
  literal 110
  literal 116
```

Once you understand the syntax, you can spot your errors.  There we can see that I forgot to escape the `[]` in `[/font]`.

Of course you can combine it with whatever flags you want, like commented regexes:

```
>>> re.compile("""
 ^              # start of a line
 \[font         # the font tag
 (?:=(?P<size>  # optional [font=+size]
 [-+][0-9]{1,2} # size specification
 ))?
 \]             # end of tag
 (.*?)          # text between the tags
 \[/font\]      # end of the tag
 """, re.DEBUG|re.VERBOSE|re.DOTALL)
```

Comment: Except parsing HTML using regular expression is slow and painful. Even the built-in 'html' parser module doesn't use regexes to get the work done. And if the html module doesn't please you, there is plenty of XML/HTML parser modules that does the job without having to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: A link to documentation on the output syntax would be great.

Comment: This should be an official part of Python, not experimental... RegEx is always tricky and being able to trace what's happening is really helpful.

Answer (score 459):

**enumerate**

Wrap an iterable with enumerate and it will yield the item along with its index.

For example:

```
>>> a = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e']
>>> for index, item in enumerate(a): print index, item
...
0 a
1 b
2 c
3 d
4 e
>>>
```

References:

- [Python tutorial—looping techniques](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#looping-techniques)
- [Python docs—built-in functions—`enumerate`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate)
- [PEP 279](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0279/)

Comment: i think it's been deprecated in python3

Comment: And all this time I was coding this way: for i in range(len(a)): ... and then using a[i] to get the current item.

Comment: @Berry Tsakala: To my knowledge, it has not been deprecated.

Comment: shorter than using zip and count

    for index, item in zip(itertools.count(), a): print(index,item)

Comment: Great feature, +1. @Draemon: this is actually covered in the Python tutorial that comes installed with Python (there's a section on various looping constructs), so I'm always surprised that this is so little known.

Comment: The nice thing about this is when you're iterating through more than one loop simultaneously

Comment: @Berry Tsakala: definitely not deprecated.

Comment: Sorry my ignorance, but isn't it enough to just do: `a = ["a","b","c"]
>>> for  x in enumerate(a):
...     print x` why do you do `for index, item in enumerate(a): print index, item`

Comment: I always hacked `idx, elem in itertools.izip(itertools.count(), iterable):`...

Comment: @Tufa: You might not want to use the index and item in the same statement. In this simple example your code is equivalent, but in a more sophisticated scenario it won't be able to do all that `for inx, itm in enumerate(a):` can do.

Comment: `for i in range(len(a))` is still a lot better than `for (int i=0;i<a.size();i++)` ....

Comment: enumerate can start from arbitrary index, not necessary 0. Example: 'for i, item in enumerate(_list_, start=1): print i, item' will start enumeration from 1, not 0.

Comment: Not deprecated in Py3K
http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/functions.html?highlight=enumerate#enumerate

Answer (score 418):

**Creating generators objects**

If you write

```
x=(n for n in foo if bar(n))
```

you can get out the generator and assign it to x. Now it means you can do

```
for n in x:
```

The advantage of this is that you don't need intermediate storage, which you would need if you did

```
x = [n for n in foo if bar(n)]
```

In some cases this can lead to significant speed up.

You can append many if statements to the end of the generator, basically replicating nested for loops:

```
>>> n = ((a,b) for a in range(0,2) for b in range(4,6))
>>> for i in n:
...   print i 

(0, 4)
(0, 5)
(1, 4)
(1, 5)
```

Comment: You could also use a nested list comprehension for that, yes?

Comment: Of particular note is the memory overhead savings. Values are computed on-demand, so you never have the entire result of the list comprehension in memory. This is particularly desirable if you later iterate over only part of the list comprehension.

Comment: I use ifilter for this kind of thing: http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter

Comment: This is not particularly "hidden" imo, but also worth noting is the fact that you could not rewind a generator object, whereas you can reiterate over a list any number of times.

Comment: ditto susmits.
Although these are extremely cool, it's a documented feature of Python
http://docs.python.org/tutorial/classes.html
Using callbacks with your generators, also documented, adds to the coolness of generators. http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0255/

Comment: The "no rewind" feature of generators can cause some confusion.  Specifically, if you print a generator's contents for debugging, then use it later to process the data, it doesn't work.  The data is produced, consumed by print(), then is not available for the normal processing.

This doesn't apply to list comprehensions, since they're completely stored in memory.

Comment: Similar (dup?) answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/165138#165138 Note, however, that the answer I linked here mentions a REALLY GOOD presentation about the power of generators. You really should check it out.

Comment: Here's a good article in using generator in solving real-world problems http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/Generators.pdf

Answer (score 352):

**iter() can take a callable argument**

For instance:

```
def seek_next_line(f):
    for c in iter(lambda: f.read(1),'\n'):
        pass
```

The `iter(callable, until_value)` function repeatedly calls `callable` and yields its result until `until_value` is returned.

Comment: As a newbie to python, can you please explain why the `lambda` keyword is necessary here?

Comment: @SiegeX without the lambda, f.read(1) would be evaluated (returning a string) before being passed to the iter function. Instead, the lambda creates an anonymous function and passes that to iter.

Answer (score 339):

**Be careful with mutable default arguments**

```
>>> def foo(x=[]):
...     x.append(1)
...     print x
... 
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1]
>>> foo()
[1, 1, 1]
```

Instead, you should use a sentinel value denoting "not given" and replace with the mutable you'd like as default:

```
>>> def foo(x=None):
...     if x is None:
...         x = []
...     x.append(1)
...     print x
>>> foo()
[1]
>>> foo()
[1]
```

Comment: That's definitely one of the more nasty hidden features. I've run into it from time to time.

Comment: I found this a lot easier to understand when I learned that the default arguments live in a tuple that's an attribute of the function, e.g. `foo.func_defaults`.  Which, being a tuple, is immutable.

Comment: Could you explain how it happens in detail?

Comment: @grayger:  As the def statement is executed its arguments are evaluated by the interpreter.  This creates (or rebinds) a name to a code object (the suite of the function).  However, the default arguments are instantiated as objects at the time of definition.  This is true of any time of defaulted object, but only significant (exposing visible semantics) when the object is mutable.  There's no way of re-binding that default argument name in the function's closure although it can obviously be over-ridden for any call or the whole function can be re-defined).

Comment: @Robert of course the arguments tuple might be immutable, but the objects it point to are not necessarily immutable.

Comment: One quick hack to make your initialization a little shorter: x = x or []. You can use that instead of the 2 line if statement.

Comment: Default values also become nasty if you use more than one of them. For example - say you wrote a function like: <function> def f(a=[], b=[], c=[]): a.append(3) </ function>. You will have inadvertently changed the values of a, b and c without having touched them. This is because similar default values seem to point to the same thing in memory. Nasty bugs arise

Comment: this feature / wart or what you'd call it is one of the most important things to understand when you start learning python. it directly connects you to understanding what is done when in a program, and without that knowledge, any code beyond a pretty low threshold of complexity cannot be written.

Comment: This seems like a bug in the compiler, right?

Comment: Just a comment that pylint complains vigorously about usage like this, as it should.

Comment: @davemankoff: I think that's a bad habit to get into, because sooner or later you'll reject a valid falsey value by mistake.

Comment: This was literally an interview question for my current job. :)  It is probably *the* classic Python gotcha.

Answer (score 316):

[Sending values into generator functions](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0342/). For example having this function:

```
def mygen():
    """Yield 5 until something else is passed back via send()"""
    a = 5
    while True:
        f = (yield a) #yield a and possibly get f in return
        if f is not None: 
            a = f  #store the new value
```

You can:

```
>>> g = mygen()
>>> g.next()
5
>>> g.next()
5
>>> g.send(7)  #we send this back to the generator
7
>>> g.next() #now it will yield 7 until we send something else
7
```

Comment: Agreed. Let's treat this as a nasty example of a hidden feature of Python :)

Comment: In other languages, I believe this magical device is called a "variable".

Comment: coroutines should be coroutines and genenerator should be themselves too, without mixing. Mega-great link and talk and examples about this here: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/

Comment: @finnw: the example implements something that's similar to a variable.  However, the feature could be used in many other ways ... unlike a variable.  It should also be obvious that similar semantics can be implemented using objects (a class implemting Python's __call__ method, in particular).

Comment: This is too trivial an example for people who've never seen (and probably won't understand) co-routines.
The example that implements the running average without risk of sum variable overflow is a good one.

Comment: More on the yield topic here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/231767/the-python-yield-keyword-explained

Comment: @finnw and his upvoters, I think you've misundetstood the point of this examble. The important bit is not storing a value in 'a', it's that 'mygen' is acting like a function with multiple entry points, and with the ability to suspend execution halfway through, and return a value to the caller, but then resume execution later, from that same point, with all local variables intact. You can read more about them here http://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coroutine

Answer (score 312):

If you don't like using whitespace to denote scopes, you can use the C-style {} by issuing:

```
from __future__ import braces
```

Comment: That's evil.  :)

Comment: >>> from \_\_future\_\_ import braces
      File "<stdin>", line 1
    SyntaxError: not a chance

:P

Comment: Wait, isn't the future package future additions to the language? So are they planning to add braces at some point?

Comment: Dynamic whitespace is half of python's goodness.  That's... twisted.

Comment: that's blasphemy!

Comment: I think that we may have a syntactical mistake here, shouldn't that be "from **\_\_past\_\_** import braces"?

Comment: from **\_\_cruft\_\_** import braces

Comment: I admit that's funny, but inversely what about the blind?  I remember reading a while back of an individual who was blind and frustrated that he/she couldn't use Python due to the lack of brackets for statements.

Comment: I can understand the use of braces for minification of code :)

Comment: Totally breaks the Python idiom

Comment: @David: How are braces better for the blind? In the best-case scenario (Well-indented code, which Python enforces), braces would only add a minuscule amount of clarity. A block of text with whitespace before would be in my opinion much easier to notice than the presence of a small typographical character. 
The legibility of braces depends on which version of the OTBS that person believes in. The inline braces I prefer would be horrible to read without proper vision.

Comment: @Alex: How does the text reader say the indentation level? You would need a Python specific text reader to tell you "for <stuff> colon newline indent pass newline <next statement>". Now add some indents: "indent indent indent for <stuff> colon newline indent indent indent indent pass newline indent indent indent <next statement>"

Comment: jmucchiello: Yes you need something python-specific. The screen reader should speak the tokens that the python interpreter uses, "intent in", "indent out".

Comment: @David, @jmucchiello: there is a script that adds braces to every block in a comment (`# }`), and in fact I've read of blind people that uses it to allow them to write Python :)

Comment: @David, @jmucchiello: Ah, you meant blind-blind, not just "horribly bad eyesight"-blind.

Comment: I know a few devs that are learning Python (but know a c style language) who would love this. It's just because they don't know any better ;)

Comment: Blind programmer can use this syntax: http://www.python.org/doc/humor/#python-block-delimited-notation-parsing-explained

Comment: A strange feature indeed. Props for sharing the first thing I didn't know as I read through this thread.

Comment: I had my braces removed when I grew up!

Comment: There is [pybraces](http://timhatch.com/projects/pybraces/), an encoding you can use for your python source code files in order to really enable braces. ;)

Comment: That's one hell of an easter egg. I love oss communities...

Answer (score 305):

The step argument in slice operators. For example:

```
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
>>> a[::2]  # iterate over the whole list in 2-increments
[1,3,5]
```

The special case `x[::-1]` is a useful idiom for 'x reversed'.

```
>>> a[::-1]
[5,4,3,2,1]
```

Comment: much clearer, in my opinion, is the reversed() function.
>>> list(reversed(range(4)))
[3, 2, 1, 0]

Comment: then how to write "this i a string"[::-1] in a better way? reversed doesnt seem to help

Comment: "".join(reversed("this i a string"))

Comment: The problem with reversed() is that it returns an iterator, so if you want to preserve the type of the reversed sequence (tuple, string, list, unicode, user types...), you need an additional step to convert it back.

Comment: def reverse_string(string): return string[::-1]

Comment: @pi I think if one knows enough to define reverse_string as you have then one can leave the [::-1] in your code and be comfortable with its meaning and the feeling it is appropriate.

Comment: Is there a speed difference between `[::-1]` and `reversed()`?

Comment: -1, because it is not hidden and you learn it early enought, but its an useful feature

Comment: ooh, noticed that `[1,2,3,4,5][::-2]` also works as expected, which is quite cool

Comment: You can make a cool palindrome finder with this!

Comment: @Berry list(reversed('blah blah'))

Comment: @Austin: yes a huge difference with strings: http://pastebin.com/ZV6cHYhP

Comment: @Trufa: yeah very easy to find a palindrome: if `someseq == (someseq[::-1])` then it's a palindrome, and this would work with any sequence type (strings, lists, etc).

Answer (score 288):

**Decorators**

[Decorators](http://docs.python.org/ref/function.html#tok-decorators) allow to wrap a function or method in another function that can add functionality, modify arguments or results, etc. You write decorators one line above the function definition, beginning with an "at" sign (@).

Example shows a `print_args` decorator that prints the decorated function's arguments before calling it:

```
>>> def print_args(function):
>>>     def wrapper(*args, **kwargs):
>>>         print 'Arguments:', args, kwargs
>>>         return function(*args, **kwargs)
>>>     return wrapper

>>> @print_args
>>> def write(text):
>>>     print text

>>> write('foo')
Arguments: ('foo',) {}
foo
```

Comment: When defining decorators, I'd recommend decorating the decorator with @decorator. It creates a decorator that preserves a functions signature when doing introspection on it. More info here: http://www.phyast.pitt.edu/~micheles/python/documentation.html

Comment: How is this a hidden feature?

Comment: Well, it's not present in most simple Python tutorials, and I stumbled upon it a long time after I started using Python. That is what I would call a hidden feature, just about the same as other top posts here.

Comment: vetler,
the questions asks for "lesser-known but useful features of the Python programming language."

How do you measure 'lesser-known but useful features'?  I mean how are any of these responses hidden features?

Comment: @vetler Most of the thing here are hardly "hidden".

Comment: Hidden? this is a documented feature
http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0318/

Comment: If the standard is whether or not a feature is documented, then this question should be closed.

Comment: I thought we were supposed to list hidden features of python not the awesome features of python. ;-)

Comment: why would this be useful except in the very rare situations? Why not just redefine the function and add optional parameters?

Comment: @Dexter: Because that decorator may be universal -- it can be attached to any function for a short moment, e.g. when you need to debug it, and then very easily removed. Besides, there are many uses of decorators other than debugging.

Comment: Decorating a decorator with the decorator decorator? We must go deeper.

Comment: As for useful (arguable), some more common ones: @ property, @ classmethod, @ staticmethod, @ coroutine, @ _o (monocle)

Comment: Decorators are extremely handy, but they can be a PITA to write. There's so many variations -- class based vs not class based, decorators which can decorate methods vs functions (or both), adding descriptors, decorators which take arguments, etc.  So while the simple example above may not be a "hidden" feature of Python, I'd say consider it a starting point for learning about a rather beefy topic in the language, and should be in the list.

Answer (score 288):

The for...else syntax (see http://docs.python.org/ref/for.html )

```
for i in foo:
    if i == 0:
        break
else:
    print("i was never 0")
```

The "else" block will be normally executed at the end of the for loop, unless the break is called.

The above code could be emulated as follows:

```
found = False
for i in foo:
    if i == 0:
        found = True
        break
if not found: 
    print("i was never 0")
```

Comment: I think the for/else syntax is awkward. It "feels" as if the else clause should be executed if the body of the loop is never executed.

Comment: It becomes less awkward if we think of it as for/if/else, with the else belonging to the if. And it's so useful an idiom that I wonder other language designers didn't think of it!

Comment: ah. Never saw that one! But I must say it is a bit of a misnomer. Who would expect the else block to execute only if break never does? I agree with codeape: It looks like else is entered for empty foos.

Comment: I've added an equivalent code that is not using `else`.

Comment: I find this much less useful than if the else clause executed if the for loop didn't. I've wanted that so many times, but I've never found a case I wanted to use this.

Comment: Anyone remember the FOR var … NEXT var … END FOR var of Sinclair QL's SuperBasic? Everything between NEXT and END FOR would execute at the end of the loop, unless an EXIT FOR was issued. *That* syntax was cleaner :)

Comment: seems like the keyword should be finally, not else

Comment: Except finally is already used in a way where that suite is always executed.

Comment: This is really convenient, and I use it, but it needs an explaining comment each time.

Comment: Should definately not be 'else'. Maybe 'then' or something, and then 'else' for when the loop was never executed.

Comment: I used this on a programming assignment for a class and lost points because the grader had never seen it before... totally got those back.

Comment: Hey, people forgot to mention that this idiom also works for `while` loops.

Comment: I've always thought a `for...then...else` construct would be better, where `then` is only executed if the `for` is successful, `else` when the for cannot be entered (eg: `for i in []; pass; else; print "empty list"`. But then I'm a novice. :)

Comment: Does this work ONLY if there is a break statement in the for loop or are there any other circumstances where this trick works this way?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: it works fine without a break... but serves no purpose if there's no break. (The code in the else might as well just be outdented one level)

Comment: @jkerian: Many thanks. I observed that behavior, but was wondering more along the lines of "would this work the same way if return was used instead of break?"

Comment: i shun this feature. every time i want to use it i have to read up on it, and then i still find it hard to get right.

Comment: Yeah, using this syntax got me screamed at by a couple of PHP and C programmers. Go figure. :-)

Comment: Never use for-else. It does not do what the next programmer to see your code thinks it does.

Comment: I used to be confused by this behavior as well until I thought of it in terms of `try.. except.. else..`  Python's `for.. else..` behavior is consistent with how try blocks are executed.  If the contents of try or for succeed, jump to else.

Comment: Control flow altering statements (like break) are generally poor choices to begin with, combine this with an unusual use of a keyword (in this case "else") and you end up with code that is even harder to read, especially for novices.  I'd definitely shy away from this one.

Comment: `if any(i == 0 for i in foo): ...`  Would be my choice of phrasing for this kind of code.  Maybe it's my Haskell influence.

Answer (score 258):

From 2.5 onwards dicts have a special method `__missing__` that is invoked for missing items:

```
>>> class MyDict(dict):
...  def __missing__(self, key):
...   self[key] = rv = []
...   return rv
... 
>>> m = MyDict()
>>> m["foo"].append(1)
>>> m["foo"].append(2)
>>> dict(m)
{'foo': [1, 2]}
```

There is also a dict subclass in `collections` called `defaultdict` that does pretty much the same but calls a function without arguments for not existing items:

```
>>> from collections import defaultdict
>>> m = defaultdict(list)
>>> m["foo"].append(1)
>>> m["foo"].append(2)
>>> dict(m)
{'foo': [1, 2]}
```

I recommend converting such dicts to regular dicts before passing them to functions that don't expect such subclasses.  A lot of code uses `d[a_key]` and catches KeyErrors to check if an item exists which would add a new item to the dict.

Comment: This is where I put fork bombs.

Comment: I prefer using setdefault. m={} ; m.setdefault('foo',1)

Comment: @grayger meant this `m={}; m.setdefault('foo', []).append(1)`.

Comment: There are however cases where passing the defaultdict is very handy. The function may for example iter over the value and it works for undefined keys without extra code, as the default is an empty list.

Comment: defaultdict is better in some circumstances than setdefault, since it doesn't create the default object **unless** the key is missing. setdefault creates it whether it's missing or not. If your default object is expensive to create this can be a performance hit - I got a decent speedup out of one program simply by changing all setdefault calls.

Comment: `defaultdict` is also more powerful than the `setdefault` method in other cases. For example, for a counter—`dd = collections.defaultdict(int) ... dd[k] += 1` vs `d.setdefault(k, 0) += 1`.

Answer (score 247):

**In-place value swapping**

```
>>> a = 10
>>> b = 5
>>> a, b
(10, 5)

>>> a, b = b, a
>>> a, b
(5, 10)
```

The right-hand side of the assignment is an expression that creates a new tuple. The left-hand side of the assignment immediately unpacks that (unreferenced) tuple to the names `a` and `b`.

After the assignment, the new tuple is unreferenced and marked for garbage collection, and the values bound to `a` and `b` have been swapped.

As noted in the [Python tutorial section on data structures](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences),

> Note that multiple assignment is really just a combination of tuple packing and sequence unpacking.

Comment: Does this use more real memory than the traditional way? I would guess do since you are creating a tuple, instead of just one swap variable

Comment: It doesn't use more memory. It uses less.. I just wrote it both ways, and de-compiled the bytecode.. the compiler optimizes, as you'd hope it would. dis results showed it's setting up the vars, and then ROT_TWOing. ROT_TWO means 'swap the two top-most stack vars'...  Pretty snazzy, actually.

Comment: You also inadvertently point out another nice feature of Python, which is that you can implicitly make a tuple of items just by separating them by commas.

Comment: I would prefer `(a, b) = (b, a)`. I don't think it is necessarily clear whether `,` or `=` has higher precedence.

Comment: Dana the Sane: assignment in Python is a statement, not an expression, so that expression would be invalid if = had higher priority (i.e. it was interpreted as a, (b = b), a).

Comment: royal: it did actually create tuples in older versions of Python (I think pre-2.4).

Comment: This is the least hidden feature I've read here. Nice, but explicitly described in every Python tutorial.

Comment: I love this feature, but we have to be careful about the semantics of the objects being swapped. I got bitten when doing `foo[x:y], bar[x:y] = bar[x:y], foo[x:y]` with `foo` and `bar` being numpy arrays, because slicing numpy arrays creates views, not copies of the data!

Answer (score 235):

**Readable regular expressions**

In Python you can split a regular expression over multiple lines, name your matches and insert comments.

Example verbose syntax (from [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.net/regular_expressions/index.html)):

```
>>> pattern = """
... ^                   # beginning of string
... M{0,4}              # thousands - 0 to 4 M's
... (CM|CD|D?C{0,3})    # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 C's),
...                     #            or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 C's)
... (XC|XL|L?X{0,3})    # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 X's),
...                     #        or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 X's)
... (IX|IV|V?I{0,3})    # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 I's),
...                     #        or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 I's)
... $                   # end of string
... """
>>> re.search(pattern, 'M', re.VERBOSE)
```

Example naming matches (from [Regular Expression HOWTO](http://www.amk.ca/python/howto/regex/))

```
>>> p = re.compile(r'(?P<word>\b\w+\b)')
>>> m = p.search( '(((( Lots of punctuation )))' )
>>> m.group('word')
'Lots'
```

You can also verbosely write a regex without using `re.VERBOSE` thanks to string literal concatenation.

```
>>> pattern = (
...     "^"                 # beginning of string
...     "M{0,4}"            # thousands - 0 to 4 M's
...     "(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})"  # hundreds - 900 (CM), 400 (CD), 0-300 (0 to 3 C's),
...                         #            or 500-800 (D, followed by 0 to 3 C's)
...     "(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})"  # tens - 90 (XC), 40 (XL), 0-30 (0 to 3 X's),
...                         #        or 50-80 (L, followed by 0 to 3 X's)
...     "(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})"  # ones - 9 (IX), 4 (IV), 0-3 (0 to 3 I's),
...                         #        or 5-8 (V, followed by 0 to 3 I's)
...     "$"                 # end of string
... )
>>> print pattern
"^M{0,4}(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})(XC|XL|L?X{0,3})(IX|IV|V?I{0,3})$"
```

Comment: I don't know if I'd really consider that a Python feature, most RE engines have a verbose option.

Comment: Yes, but because you can't do it in grep or in most editors, a lot of people don't know it's there. The fact that other languages have an equivalent feature doesn't make it not a useful and little known feature of python

Comment: In a large project with lots of optimized regular expressions (read: optimized for machine but not human beings), I bit the bullet and converted all of them to verbose syntax. Now, introducing new developers to projects is much easier. From now on we enforce verbose REs on every project.

Comment: I'd rather just say: hundreds = "(CM|CD|D?C{0,3})" # 900 (CM), 400 (CD), etc. The language already has a way to give things names, a way to add comments, and a way to combine strings. Why use special library syntax here for things the language already does perfectly well? It seems to go directly against Perlis' Epigram 9.

Comment: @Ken: a regex may not always be directly in the source, it could be read from settings or a config file. Allowing comments or just additional whitespace (for readability) can be a great help.

Comment: If you're writing a Python program and your config file isn't Python, then (Yegge would say and I'd agree that) "you're talking out of both sides of your mouth" re OO: http://sites.google.com/site/steveyegge2/the-emacs-problem

Comment: Nice!  With the string literal concatenation, the comments are parsed as actual comments.

Comment: I start my verbose patterns with `(?x) # Use verbose mode`, which feels more self-documenting than using `re.VERBOSE` at the compile step.  These must be the very first characters in the pattern - no leading whitespace.

Also, when using a verbose pattern, remember to us `\s` or `[ ]` to signify spaces (depending on if you want to capture all whitespace or just spaces).  It can be easy to forget when converting from standard to verbose patterns.

Comment: +1 for string literal concatenation, but -1 for Python even having the `re.VERBOSE` flag, which I think leads to terrible-to-read code.

Answer (score 222):

**Function argument unpacking**

You can unpack a list or a dictionary as function arguments using `*` and `**`.

For example:

```
def draw_point(x, y):
    # do some magic

point_foo = (3, 4)
point_bar = {'y': 3, 'x': 2}

draw_point(*point_foo)
draw_point(**point_bar)
```

Very useful shortcut since lists, tuples and dicts are widely used as containers.

Comment: Use this all the time, love it.

Comment: * is also known as the splat operator

Comment: I like this feature, but pylint doesn't sadly.

Comment: pylint's advice is not a law. The other way, apply(callable, arg_seq, arg_map), is deprecated since 2.3.

Comment: pylint's advice may not be law, but it's damn good advice. Debugging code that over-indulges in stuff like this is pure hell. As the original poster notes, this is a useful _shortcut_.

Comment: I saw this being used in code once and wondered what it did. Unfortunately it's hard to google for "Python **"

Comment: It's called the splat operator. So you can google for "python splat", but it's unlikely anybody would know the name if he doesn't know the feature :-p

Comment: @andrew: Pylint tends to complain for a lot of classic idioms like try/except ImportError

Comment: @e-satis: that's because a lot of those "classic idioms" are poor practice.  I agree that Pylint can be overly "nitpicky", but the vast majority of the time unless you have a clear reason to not adhere to its suggestions it's best to comply (and for the cases where you have a good reason, you can always do a pylint-disable to suppress the warning in the specific case)

Comment: @Adam: don't get me wrong, I actually have pylint run everytime my document is saved automatically.  but Try/ except error is really useful. Dictionary comprehensions as well, and pylint don't understand them. Pylint typically complains a lot in unittest as well were you set variables without using them, because the test actually require to. It's important not to get psycho with pylint alerts, or you will just stop coding. And using * or ** is actually clean code, not dirty one.

Comment: Weird, I never have Pylint complain about dict comprehensions & I use those all the time. Most of the unit test warnings are due to the fact that the unittest module isn't PEP-8 compliant (ex: forced to name setup method "setUp" instead of "set_up").  But yeah, I agree Pylint can be (shall we say) overzealous at times. What I do is everytime I put in a disable-pylint directive I follow it with a comment justifying its use. I find this works well & there's been a few times where my team has challenged me & in the end I discovered a better way to do something.

Comment: If pylint complains about dict comprehensions, then it is running under python 2.6 (the version built in to vim.) To fix this, run pylint using 2.7 (which for me on OSX meant I had to compile macvim myself http://tartley.com/?p=1355 but on other  platforms I think vim binaries with 2.7 support are out there. You need 2.7 installed for this to work, macvim uses it.

Comment: Yeah, the pylint warning about "** magic" is dumb and can be turned off globally.

Answer (score 205):

ROT13 is a valid encoding for source code, when you use the right coding declaration at the top of the code file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
# -*- coding: rot13 -*-

cevag "Uryyb fgnpxbiresybj!".rapbqr("rot13")
```

Comment: Great! Notice how byte strings are taken literally, but unicode strings are decoded: try `cevag h"Uryyb fgnpxbiresybj!"`

Comment: unfortunately it is removed from py3k

Comment: This is good for bypassing antivirus.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the encoding, it is just Python written in Welsh. :-P

Comment: Ph'nglui mglw'nafh Cthulhu R'lyeh wgah'nagl fhtagn!

Comment: see? you can write unintelligible code in any languages, even in python

Comment: Uryyb fgnpxbiresybj! -> Hello stackoverflow!

Comment: @Manuel Ferreria : sry, but i couldn't figure what u said... is it ROT13 ??

Comment: @amyassin I too was flumoxxed, until I remembered about google, and found  http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/ph'nglui_mglw'nafh_Cthulhu_R'lyeh_wgah'nagl_fhtagn

Answer (score 183):

### Creating new types in a fully dynamic manner

```
>>> NewType = type("NewType", (object,), {"x": "hello"})
>>> n = NewType()
>>> n.x
"hello"
```

which is exactly the same as

```
>>> class NewType(object):
>>>     x = "hello"
>>> n = NewType()
>>> n.x
"hello"
```

Probably not the most useful thing, but nice to know.

**Edit**: Fixed name of new type, should be `NewType` to be the exact same thing as with `class` statement.

**Edit**: Adjusted the title to more accurately describe the feature.

Comment: This has a lot of potential for usefulness, e.g., JIT ORMs

Comment: I use it to generate HTML-Form classes based on a dynamic input. Very nice!

Comment: I also used it to generate dynamic django forms (until i discovered formsets)

Comment: Note: all classes are created at runtime. So you can use the 'class' statement within a conditional, or within a function (very useful for creating families of classes or classes that act as closures). 

The improvement that 'type' brings is the ability to neatly define a dynamically generated set of attributes (or bases).

Comment: Extremely useful, in Django, for generating dynamic models that wrap existing sets of tables with similar structures.

Comment: You can also create anonymous types with a blank string like:
type('', (object,), {'x': 'blah'})

Comment: Could be very useful for code injections.

Comment: You can also instantiate this class in one line too. `x = type("X", (object,), {'val':'Hello'})()`

Answer (score 179):

**Context managers and the "`with`" Statement**

Introduced in [PEP 343](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/), a [context manager](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#context-manager-types) is an object that acts as a run-time context for a suite of statements.

Since the feature makes use of new keywords, it is introduced gradually: it is available in Python 2.5 via the [`__future__`](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-future.html) directive. Python 2.6 and above (including Python 3) has it available by default.

I have used the ["with" statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) a lot because I think it's a very useful construct, here is a quick demo:

```
from __future__ import with_statement

with open('foo.txt', 'w') as f:
    f.write('hello!')
```

What's happening here behind the scenes, is that the ["with" statement](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0343/) calls the special `__enter__` and `__exit__` methods on the file object. Exception details are also passed to `__exit__` if any exception was raised from the with statement body, allowing for exception handling to happen there.

What this does for you in this particular case is that it guarantees that the file is closed when execution falls out of scope of the `with` suite, regardless if that occurs normally or whether an exception was thrown. It is basically a way of abstracting away common exception-handling code.

Other common use cases for this include locking with threads and database transactions.

Comment: I wouldn't approve a code review which imported anything from __future__. The features are more cute than useful, and usually they just end up confusing Python newcomers.

Comment: Yes, such "cute" features as nested scopes and generators are better left to those who know what they're doing.  And anyone who wants to be compatible with future versions of Python.  For nested scopes and generators, "future versions" of Python means 2.2 and 2.5, respectively.  For the with statement, "future versions" of Python means 2.6.

Comment: This may go without saying, but with python v2.6+, you no longer need to import from __future__.  with is now a first class keyword.

Comment: In 2.7 you can have multiple `withs` :)  

        `with open('filea') as filea and open('fileb') as fileb:
            ...`

Comment: @Austin i could not get that syntax to work on 2.7.  this however did work:  `with open('filea') as filea,  open('fileb') as fileb: ...`

Comment: It could be useful to explain why, in which cases, this `with` statement is different from `f = open('foo.txt', 'w')`.

Answer (score 168):

### Dictionaries have a get() method

Dictionaries have a 'get()' method. If you do d['key'] and key isn't there, you get an exception. If you do d.get('key'), you get back None if 'key' isn't there. You can add a second argument to get that item back instead of None, eg: d.get('key', 0).

It's great for things like adding up numbers:

`sum[value] = sum.get(value, 0) + 1`

Comment: also, checkout the setdefault method.

Comment: also, checkout collections.defaultdict class.

Comment: If you are using Python 2.7 or later, or 3.1 or later, check out the Counter class in the collections module. http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.Counter

Comment: Oh man, this whole time I've been doing `get(key, None)`. Had no idea that `None` was provided by default.

Answer (score 152):

### Descriptors

They're the magic behind a whole bunch of core Python features.

When you use dotted access to look up a member (eg, x.y), Python first looks for the member in the instance dictionary. If it's not found, it looks for it in the class dictionary. If it finds it in the class dictionary, and the object implements the descriptor protocol, instead of just returning it, Python executes it. A descriptor is any class that implements the `__get__`, `__set__`, or `__delete__` methods.

Here's how you'd implement your own (read-only) version of property using descriptors:

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return self.fget(obj)
```

and you'd use it just like the built-in property():

```
class MyClass(object):
    @Property
    def foo(self):
        return "Foo!"
```

Descriptors are used in Python to implement properties, bound methods, static methods, class methods and slots, amongst other things. Understanding them makes it easy to see why a lot of things that previously looked like Python 'quirks' are the way they are.

Raymond Hettinger has [an excellent tutorial](http://users.rcn.com/python/download/Descriptor.htm) that does a much better job of describing them than I do.

Comment: This is a duplicate of decorators, isn't it!? (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#101447 )

Comment: no, decorators and descriptors are totally different things, though in the example code, i'm creating a descriptor decorator. :)

Comment: The other way to do this is with a lambda: `foo = property(lambda self: self.__foo)`

Comment: @PetePeterson Yes, but `property` itself is implemented with descriptors, which was the point of my post.

Answer (score 142):

**Conditional Assignment**

```
x = 3 if (y == 1) else 2
```

It does exactly what it sounds like: "assign 3 to x if y is 1, otherwise assign 2 to x". Note that the parens are not necessary, but I like them for readability. You can also chain it if you have something more complicated:

```
x = 3 if (y == 1) else 2 if (y == -1) else 1
```

Though at a certain point, it goes a little too far.

Note that you can use if ... else in any expression. For example:

```
(func1 if y == 1 else func2)(arg1, arg2)
```

Here func1 will be called if y is 1 and func2, otherwise. In both cases the corresponding function will be called with arguments arg1 and arg2.

Analogously, the following is also valid:

```
x = (class1 if y == 1 else class2)(arg1, arg2)
```

where class1 and class2 are two classes.

Comment: The assignment is not the special part.  You could just as easily do something like: return 3 if (y == 1) else 2.

Comment: An alternate way to do this is: y == 1 and 3 or 2

Comment: That alternate way is fraught with problems. For one thing, normally this works:
    if y == 1: #3
    else if y == 70: #2

Why? y == 1 is only evaluated, THEN y == 70 if y == 1 is false.

In this statement: y == 1 and 3 or 2 - 3 and 2 are evaluated as well as y == 1.

Comment: That alternate way is the first time I've seen obfuscated Python.

Comment: Kylebrooks: It doesn't in that case, boolean operators short circuit.  It will only evaluate 2 if bool(3) == False.

Comment: this backwards-style coding confusing me. something like `x = ((y == 1) ? 3 : 2)` makes more sense to me

Comment: I feel just the opposite of @Mark, C-style ternary operators have always confused me, is the right side or the middle what gets evaluated on a false condition?  I much prefer Python's ternary syntax.

Comment: @Mark "x = (y == 1) and 3 or 2" is also valid.

Comment: I think C-style ternary operators are simpler, more english-like: `'am I drunk' ? 'yes, make out with her' : 'no, dont even think about it'`

Comment: `x = 3 if (y == 1) else 2` - I find that in many cases, `x = (2, 3)[y==1]` is actually more readable (normally with really long statements, so you can keep the results (2, 3) together).

Comment: Somehow Guido and the Python folks managed to make one of the most contorted parts of the C language readable and easily understandable, even if you don't know what it is.

Comment: @Infinity, you should consult with a doctor to replace the always-true constant 'am I drunk' with a non-deterministic function am_i_drunk().

Comment: The first time I saw the ternary op in Python I found it confusing to read, largely due to my familiarity with the C-style one. Not sure which one is better ("the grass is wet if it is raining otherwise the grass is dry" vs "if it is raining then the grass is wet otherwise the grass is dry")

Answer (score 141):

### [Doctest](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-doctest.html): documentation and unit-testing at the same time.

Example extracted from the Python documentation:

```
def factorial(n):
    """Return the factorial of n, an exact integer >= 0.

    If the result is small enough to fit in an int, return an int.
    Else return a long.

    >>> [factorial(n) for n in range(6)]
    [1, 1, 2, 6, 24, 120]
    >>> factorial(-1)
    Traceback (most recent call last):
        ...
    ValueError: n must be >= 0

    Factorials of floats are OK, but the float must be an exact integer:
    """

    import math
    if not n >= 0:
        raise ValueError("n must be >= 0")
    if math.floor(n) != n:
        raise ValueError("n must be exact integer")
    if n+1 == n:  # catch a value like 1e300
        raise OverflowError("n too large")
    result = 1
    factor = 2
    while factor <= n:
        result *= factor
        factor += 1
    return result

def _test():
    import doctest
    doctest.testmod()    

if __name__ == "__main__":
    _test()
```

Comment: Doctests are certainly cool, but I really dislike all the cruft you have to type to test that something should raise an exception

Comment: Doctests are overrated and pollute the documentation. How often do you test a standalone function without any setUp() ?

Comment: who says you can't have setup in a doctest? write a function that generates the context and returns `locals()` then in your doctest do `locals().update(setUp())` =D

Comment: These are nice for making sure examples in docstrings don't go out of sync.

Comment: If a standalone function requires a setUp, chances are high that it should be decoupled from some unrelated stuff or put into a class. Class doctest namespace can then be re-used in class method doctests, so it's a bit like setUp, only DRY and readable.

Comment: http://bemusement.org/diary/2008/October/24/more-doctest-problems - doctests make for ok docs, bad tests

Comment: "How often do you test a standalone function" - lots.  I find doctests often emerge naturally from the design process when I am deciding on facades.

Comment: Doctest is hard to use with some modules and frameworks, such as Django. Usually, which makes Doctest hard to use is some point of the API design that is heavyweight, overcoupled to other components or has a lot of dependencies. Doctest has some problems and limitations but most of the time I feel that an API that makes it hard to use Doctest is more complex than it is needed.

Comment: I think doctests are misnamed. They are really useful if you look at them as small usage examples, coming with a guarantee that they run.

Comment: I've never understood the point of doctests, if you have a snippet of code that tests a function then put it into a proper unit test.

Answer (score 138):

### Named formatting

% -formatting takes a dictionary (also applies %i/%s etc. validation).

```
>>> print "The %(foo)s is %(bar)i." % {'foo': 'answer', 'bar':42}
The answer is 42.

>>> foo, bar = 'question', 123

>>> print "The %(foo)s is %(bar)i." % locals()
The question is 123.
```

And since locals() is also a dictionary, you can simply pass that as a dict and have % -substitions from your local variables. I think this is frowned upon, but simplifies things..

**New Style Formatting**

```
>>> print("The {foo} is {bar}".format(foo='answer', bar=42))
```

Comment: Will be phased out and eventually replaced with string's format() method.

Comment: Named formatting is very useful for translators as they tend to just see the format string without the variable names for context

Comment: Appears to work in python 3.0.1 (needed to add parenttheses around print call).

Comment: a *hash*, huh? I see where you came from.

Comment: %-formatting won't go away any time soon, but the "format" method on strings is the new (current) best-practices method.  It supports everything %-formatting does and most people think the API and the formatting syntax is much nicer.  (Myself included.)  Python has a third method, string.Template added in 2.4; basically nobody likes that one.

Comment: %s formatting will not be phased out. str.format() is certainly more pythonic, however is actually 10x's slower for simple string replacement.

My belief is %s formatting is still best practice.

Comment: For completeness, the `locals()`-equivalent for new-style formatting is of course `print "The {foo} is {bar}".format(**locals())`.

Comment: I love locals(), but it has the annoying side-effect that if you use pylint, you will often get errors for not using a variable in the scope of the function.

Comment: As of Python 3.2, the `locals()` equivalent is `print("The {foo} is {bar}".format_map(locals()))`

Comment: That format is slower should be fixable. After all it does the same as % formatting. And in 3.1.3 timeit gives me these speed measurements: `>>> timeit('''"a %(b)s" % {"b": "c"}''')  
0.2503829002380371  
>>> timeit('''"a {b}".format(b="c")''')  
0.41667699813842773`

Comment: Hey @matt, it's not clear which kind of formatting you're recommending against, and it's especially not clear why.

Answer (score 132):

To add more python modules (espcially 3rd party ones), most people seem to use PYTHONPATH environment variables or they add symlinks or directories in their site-packages directories. Another way, is to use *.pth files. Here's the official python doc's explanation:

> "The most convenient way [to modify
>   python's search path] is to add a path
>   configuration file to a directory
>   that's already on Python's path,
>   usually to the .../site-packages/
>   directory. Path configuration files
>   have an extension of .pth, and each
>   line must contain a single path that
>   will be appended to sys.path. (Because
>   the new paths are appended to
>   sys.path, modules in the added
>   directories will not override standard
>   modules. This means you can't use this
>   mechanism for installing fixed
>   versions of standard modules.)"

Comment: I never made the connection between that .pth file in the site-packages directory from setuptools and this idea.  awesome.

Answer (score 122):

Exception **else** clause:

```
try:
  put_4000000000_volts_through_it(parrot)
except Voom:
  print "'E's pining!"
else:
  print "This parrot is no more!"
finally:
  end_sketch()
```

The use of the else clause is better than adding additional code to the try clause because it avoids accidentally catching an exception that wasn’t raised by the code being protected by the try ... except statement.

See http://docs.python.org/tut/node10.html

Comment: +1 this is awesome. If the try block executes without entering any exception blocks, then the else block is entered. And then of course, the finally block is executed

Comment: It would make more sense to use continue, but I guess it's already taken ;)

Comment: Note that on older versions of Python2 you can't have both else: and finally: clauses for the same try: block

Comment: @Paweł Prażak:  I don't think it would.  As continue and break refer to loops and this is a single conditional statement.

Comment: @IsaacRemuant you are right. Maybe something like expected or default or action or normal? :)

Comment: @Paweł Prażak, as Kevin Horn mentioned, this syntax was introduced after the initial release of Python and adding new reserved keywords to existing language is always problematic. That's why an existing keyword is usually reused (c.f. "auto" in recent C++ standard).

Answer (score 113):

**Re-raising exceptions**:

```
# Python 2 syntax
try:
    some_operation()
except SomeError, e:
    if is_fatal(e):
        raise
    handle_nonfatal(e)

# Python 3 syntax
try:
    some_operation()
except SomeError as e:
    if is_fatal(e):
        raise
    handle_nonfatal(e)
```

The 'raise' statement with no arguments inside an error handler tells Python to re-raise the exception *with the original traceback intact*, allowing you to say "oh, sorry, sorry, I didn't mean to catch that, sorry, sorry."

If you wish to print, store or fiddle with the original traceback, you can get it with sys.exc_info(), and printing it like Python would is done with the 'traceback' module.

Comment: Sorry but this is a well known and common feature of almost all languages.

Comment: Note the italicized text. Some people will do `raise e` instead, which doesn't preserve the original traceback.

Comment: Maybe more magical, `exc_info = sys.exc_info(); raise exc_info[0], exc_info[1], exc_info[2]` is equivalent to this, but you can change those values around (e.g., change the exception type or message)

Comment: @Lucas S. Well, I didn't know it, and I'm glad it's written here.

Comment: i may be showing my youth here, but i have always used the python 3 syntax in python 2.7 with no issue

Comment: The Python 3 syntax works in 2.6 and 2.7 as well, yes.

Answer (score 106):

**Main messages :)**

```
import this
# btw look at this module's source :)
```

---

[De-cyphered](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/this.py?view=markup):

> The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters
>
> Beautiful is better than ugly.
>   Explicit is better than implicit.
>   Simple is better than complex.
>   Complex is better than complicated.
>   Flat is better than nested.
>   Sparse is better than dense.
>   Readability counts.
>   Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
>   Although practicality beats purity.
>   Errors should never pass silently.
>   Unless explicitly silenced.
>   In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
>   There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
>   Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
>   Now is better than never.
>   Although never is often better than *right* now.
>   If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
>   If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
>   Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!

Comment: Loving the source for that :D

Comment: Any idea why the source was cyphered that way?  Was it just for fun, or was there some other reason?

Comment: the way the source is written goes against the zen!

Comment: http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/this.py?view=markup

Comment: It should be easier to understand if instead of 65 it used ord("A"), ord("a") instead of 97 and ord("z")-ord("a") instead of 26. The rest is just a Caesar cipher by 13 (A.K.A. ROT13). But indeed it would have been more pythonic to use the str.translate method :-p

Comment: I've updated my /usr/lib/python2.6/this.py replacing the old code with this `print s.translate("".join(chr(64<i<91 and 65+(i-52)%26 or 96<i<123 and 97+(i-84)%26 or i) for i in range(256)))` and it looks much better now!! :-D

Comment: year, that's called irony. (the reason, why they made it)

Comment: @MiniQuark: quick history lesson: http://www.wefearchange.org/2010/06/import-this-and-zen-of-python.html

Comment: I found this history of `import this` the other day.  Rather interesting: http://www.wefearchange.org/2010/06/import-this-and-zen-of-python.html

Comment: @Dan: Damn.  I didn't see your comment until just now.

Comment: http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Lib/this.py

Comment: I think the source was obfuscated to disguise the commit, so the easter egg really would be a surprise, even to people skimming commits.

Answer (score 105):

**Interactive Interpreter Tab Completion**

```
try:
    import readline
except ImportError:
    print "Unable to load readline module."
else:
    import rlcompleter
    readline.parse_and_bind("tab: complete")


>>> class myclass:
...    def function(self):
...       print "my function"
... 
>>> class_instance = myclass()
>>> class_instance.<TAB>
class_instance.__class__   class_instance.__module__
class_instance.__doc__     class_instance.function
>>> class_instance.f<TAB>unction()
```

You will also have to set a PYTHONSTARTUP environment variable.

Comment: This is a very useful feature. So much so I've a simple script to enable it (plus a couple of other introspection enhancements):
http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/inpy

Comment: IPython gives you this plus tons of other neat stuff

Comment: This would have been more useful at pdb prompt than the regular python prompt (as IPython serves that purpose anyway). However, this doesn't seem to work at the pdb prompt, probably because pdb binds its own for tab (which is less useful). I tried calling parse_and_bind() at the pdb prompt, but it still didn't work. The alternative of getting pdb prompt with IPython is more work so I tend to not use it.

Comment: Found this recipe, but this didn't work for me (using python 2.6): http://code.activestate.com/recipes/498182/

Comment: @haridsv -- `easy_install ipdb` -- then you can use `import ipdb; ipdb.set_trace()`

Comment: For me the best tip was to use the try:except:else:. I've forgotten about the else in the try block

Comment: On osx [and i imagine other systems which use libedit] you have to do `readline.parse_and_bind ("bind ^I rl_complete")`

Answer (score 91):

Nested list comprehensions and generator expressions:

```
[(i,j) for i in range(3) for j in range(i) ]    
((i,j) for i in range(4) for j in range(i) )
```

These can replace huge chunks of nested-loop code.

Comment: "for j in range(i)" - is this a typo? Normally you'd want fixed ranges for i and j. If you're accessing a 2d array, you'd miss out on half your elements.

Comment: I'm not accessing any arrays in this example. The only purpose of this code is to show that the expressions from the inner ranges can access those from the outer ones. The by-product is a list of pairs (x,y) such that 4>x>y>0.

Comment: sorta like double integration in calculus, or double summation.

Comment: Key point to remember here (which took me a long time to realize) is that the order of the ``for`` statements are to be written in the order you'd expect them to be written in a standard for-loop, from the outside inwards.

Comment: To add on to sykora's comment: imagine you're starting with a stack of `for`s and `if`s with `yield x` inside. To convert that to a generator expression, move `x` first, delete all the colons (and the `yield`), and surround the whole thing in parentheses. To make a list comprehension instead, replace the outer parens with square brackets.

Comment: Great comment, Ken, I have trouble visualizing this as well but anyone could grasp from your comment.

Answer (score 91):

**Operator overloading for the `set` builtin:**

```
>>> a = set([1,2,3,4])
>>> b = set([3,4,5,6])
>>> a | b # Union
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6}
>>> a & b # Intersection
{3, 4}
>>> a < b # Subset
False
>>> a - b # Difference
{1, 2}
>>> a ^ b # Symmetric Difference
{1, 2, 5, 6}
```

More detail from the standard library reference: [Set Types](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset)

Comment: In the tutorial, partly http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#sets

Answer (score 85):

**Negative round**

The `round()` function rounds a float number to given precision in decimal digits, but precision can be negative:

```
>>> str(round(1234.5678, -2))
'1200.0'
>>> str(round(1234.5678, 2))
'1234.57'
```

*Note:* `round()` always returns a float, `str()` used in the above example because floating point math is inexact, and under 2.x the second example can print as `1234.5700000000001`. Also see the [`decimal`](http://docs.python.org/library/decimal.html#module-decimal) module.

Comment: So often I have to round a number to a multiple. Eg, round 17 to a multiple of 5 (15). But Python's round doesn't let me do that! IMO, it should be structured as `round(num, precision=1) - round "num" to the nearest multiple of "precision"`

Comment: @wallacoloo what's the matter with (17 / 5)*5 ? Isn't it short and expressive?

Comment: @silviot try that with (19 / 5)*5. 19 rounded to the nearest 5 should be 20, right? But that seems to return 15. Also, that's relying on the integer division rules of Python 2.x. It won't work the same in 3.x. The most concise, correct solution imo is: `roundNearest = lambda n, m: round(float(n)/m)*m`

Comment: Or in general, `roundNearest = lambda n, m: (n + (m/2)) / m * m`.  It's twice as fast as using `round(float)` on my system.

Answer (score 81):

**Multiplying by a boolean**

One thing I'm constantly doing in web development is optionally printing HTML parameters. We've all seen code like this in other languages:

```
class='<% isSelected ? "selected" : "" %>'
```

In Python, you can multiply by a boolean and it does exactly what you'd expect:

```
class='<% "selected" * isSelected %>'
```

This is because multiplication coerces the boolean to an integer (0 for False, 1 for True), and in python multiplying a string by an int *repeats* the string N times.

Comment: +1, that's a nice one.  OTOH, as it's just a bit arcane, it's easy to see why you might not want to do this, for readability reasons.

Comment: I would write `bool(isSelected)` both for reliability and readability.

Comment: you could also use something like:
`('not-selected', 'selected')[isSelected]`
if you need an option for False value too..

Comment: Proper [conditional expressions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103667/python-ternary-operator) were added to Python in 2.5.  If you're using 2.5+ you probably shouldn't use these tricks for readability reasons.

Answer (score 74):

Python's advanced slicing operation has a barely known syntax element, the ellipsis:

```
>>> class C(object):
...  def __getitem__(self, item):
...   return item
... 
>>> C()[1:2, ..., 3]
(slice(1, 2, None), Ellipsis, 3)
```

Unfortunately it's barely useful as the ellipsis is only supported if tuples are involved.

Comment: see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python for more info

Comment: Actually, the ellipsis is quite useful when dealing with multi-dimensional arrays from `numpy` module.

Comment: This is supposed to be more useful in Python 3, where the ellipsis will become a literal.  (Try it, you can type `...` in a Python 3 interpreter and it will return `Eillipsis`)

Answer (score 72):

## re can call functions!

The fact that you can call a function every time something matches a regular expression is very handy.
Here I have a sample of replacing every "Hello" with "Hi," and "there" with "Fred", etc.

```
import re

def Main(haystack):
  # List of from replacements, can be a regex
  finds = ('Hello', 'there', 'Bob')
  replaces = ('Hi,', 'Fred,', 'how are you?')

  def ReplaceFunction(matchobj):
    for found, rep in zip(matchobj.groups(), replaces):
      if found != None:
        return rep

    # log error
    return matchobj.group(0)

  named_groups = [ '(%s)' % find for find in finds ]
  ret = re.sub('|'.join(named_groups), ReplaceFunction, haystack)
  print ret

if __name__ == '__main__':
  str = 'Hello there Bob'
  Main(str)
  # Prints 'Hi, Fred, how are you?'
```

Comment: This is insane. I had no idea this existed. awesome. thanks a lot.

Comment: Never seen this before, but a better example might be `re.sub('[aeiou]', lambda match: match.group().upper()*3, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz')`

Answer (score 70):

**tuple unpacking in python 3**

in python 3, you can use a syntax identical to optional arguments in function definition for tuple unpacking:

```
>>> first,second,*rest = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
>>> first
1
>>> second
2
>>> rest
[3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
```

but a feature less known and more powerful allows you to have an unknown number of elements **in the middle of the list**:

```
>>> first,*rest,last = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8)
>>> first
1
>>> rest
[2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7]
>>> last
8
```

Comment: Quite haskellish :) cool one :)

Comment: i like it , bummer it doesn't work in 2.7..

Answer (score 67):

**Multi line strings**

One approach is to use backslashes:

```
>>> sql = "select * from some_table \
where id > 10"
>>> print sql
select * from some_table where id > 10
```

Another is to use the triple-quote:

```
>>> sql = """select * from some_table 
where id > 10"""
>>> print sql
select * from some_table where id > 10
```

Problem with those is that they are not indented (look poor in your code). If you try to indent, it'll just print the white-spaces you put.

A third solution, which I found about recently, is to divide your string into lines and surround with parentheses:

```
>>> sql = ("select * from some_table " # <-- no comma, whitespace at end
           "where id > 10 "
           "order by name") 
>>> print sql
select * from some_table where id > 10 order by name
```

note how there's no comma between lines (this is not a tuple), and you have to account for any trailing/leading white spaces that your string needs to have. All of these work with placeholders, by the way (such as `"my name is %s" % name`).

Comment: have been looking for this for a long time

Comment: That's a gooood thing when writing long stuff in code, while keeping a low line length!

Answer (score 63):

This answer has been moved into the question itself, as requested by many people.

Answer (score 59):

- The underscore, it contains the most recent output value displayed by the interpreter (in an interactive session):

```
>>> (a for a in xrange(10000))
<generator object at 0x81a8fcc>
>>> b = 'blah'
>>> _
<generator object at 0x81a8fcc>
```

- A convenient Web-browser controller:

```
>>> import webbrowser
>>> webbrowser.open_new_tab('http://www.stackoverflow.com')
```

- A built-in http server. To serve the files in the current directory:

```
python -m SimpleHTTPServer 8000
```

- AtExit

```
>>> import atexit
```

Comment: Why not just SimpleHTTPServer?

Comment: worth noting that the `_` is available only in interactive mode.  when running scripts from a file, `_` has no special meaning.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: Actually, you can define `_` to be a variable in a file (just in case you _do_ want to go for obfuscated Python).

Comment: note: you can also use __ for the second-last and ___ for the third last

Comment: @asmeurer I frequently use `_` as a name for variables I do not care about (eg `for _, desired_value, _ in my_tuple_with_some_irrelevant_values`). Yes, ike a prologger :)

Answer (score 56):

#### pow() can also calculate (x ** y) % z efficiently.

There is a lesser known third argument of the built-in `pow()` function that allows you to calculate x<sup>y</sup> modulo z more efficiently than simply doing `(x ** y) % z`:

```
>>> x, y, z = 1234567890, 2345678901, 17
>>> pow(x, y, z)            # almost instantaneous
6
```

In comparison, `(x ** y) % z` didn't given a result in one minute on my machine for the same values.

Comment: I've always wondered what the use case is for this. I haven't encountered one, but then again I don't do scientific computing.

Comment: @buzkor: it's pretty useful for cryptography, too

Comment: Remember, this is the **built-in** `pow()` function. This is **not** the `math.pow()` function, which accepts only 2 arguments.

Comment: I remember stating very adamantly that I could not code cryptography in pure Python without this feature.  This was in 2003, and so the version of Python I was working with was 2.2 or 2.3.  I wonder if I was making a fool of myself and `pow` had that third parameter then or not.

Comment: `pow` had that third parameter at least since Python 2.1. However, according to the documentation, "[i]n Python 2.1 and before, floating 3-argument `pow()` returned platform-dependent results depending on floating-point rounding accidents."

Comment: The cool thing here is that you can *override* this behavior in your own objects using `__pow__`. You just have to define an optional third argument.  And for more information on where this would be used, see http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation.

Comment: Fermats little theorem made quick!

Answer (score 52):

You can easily transpose an array with zip.

```
a = [(1,2), (3,4), (5,6)]
zip(*a)
# [(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, 6)]
```

Comment: Basically, `zip(*a)` _unzips_ `a`.  So if `b = zip(a)`, then `a == zip(*b)`.

Comment: map(None, *a) can come in handy if your tuples are of differing lengths: map(None, *[(1,2), (3,4,5), (5,)]) =>
[(1, 3, 5), (2, 4, None), (None, 5, None)]

Comment: Just found this feature at http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html and was about to share it on here. Looks like ya beat me to the chase.

Comment: The way I remember how this works is that "zip* turns a list of pairs in to a pair of lists" (and vice versa)

Answer (score 52):

#### enumerate with different starting index

`enumerate` has partly been covered in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/117116#117116), but recently I've found an even more hidden feature of `enumerate` that I think deserves its own post instead of just a comment.

Since Python 2.6, you can specify a starting index to `enumerate` in its second argument:

```
>>> l = ["spam", "ham", "eggs"]
>>> list(enumerate(l))
>>> [(0, "spam"), (1, "ham"), (2, "eggs")]
>>> list(enumerate(l, 1))
>>> [(1, "spam"), (2, "ham"), (3, "eggs")]
```

One place where I've found it utterly useful is when I am enumerating over entries of a symmetric matrix. Since the matrix is symmetric, I can save time by iterating over the upper triangle only, but in that case, I have to use `enumerate` with a different starting index in the inner `for` loop to keep track of the row and column indices properly:

```
for ri, row in enumerate(matrix):
    for ci, column in enumerate(matrix[ri:], ri):
        # ci now refers to the proper column index
```

Strangely enough, this behaviour of `enumerate` is not documented in `help(enumerate)`, only in the [online documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#enumerate).

Comment: `help(enumerate)` has this proper function signature in python2.x, but not in py3k. I guess, a bug needs to be filled.

Comment: `help(enumerate)` is definitely wrong in Python 2.6.5. Maybe they have fixed it already in Python 2.7.

Comment: `help(enumerate)` from Python 3.1.2 says *class enumerate(object) |  enumerate(iterable) -> iterator for index, value of iterable*, but the trick from the answer works fine.

Comment: It looks like this was added in Python 2.6 as it does not work in Python 2.5.

Answer (score 49):

You can use [property](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#property) to make your class interfaces more strict.

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo # read-write property
        self.bar = bar # simple attribute

    def _set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

    def _get_foo(self):
        return self._foo

    def _del_foo(self):
        del self._foo

    # any of fget, fset, fdel and doc are optional,
    # so you can make a write-only and/or delete-only property.
    foo = property(fget = _get_foo, fset = _set_foo,
                   fdel = _del_foo, doc = 'Hello, I am foo!')

class D(C):
    def _get_foo(self):
        return self._foo * 2

    def _set_foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value / 2

    foo = property(fget = _get_foo, fset = _set_foo,
                   fdel = C.foo.fdel, doc = C.foo.__doc__)
```

In Python [2.6 and 3.0](http://docs.python.org/dev/whatsnew/2.6.html):

```
class C(object):
    def __init__(self, foo, bar):
        self.foo = foo # read-write property
        self.bar = bar # simple attribute

    @property
    def foo(self):
        '''Hello, I am foo!'''

        return self._foo

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value

    @foo.deleter
    def foo(self):
        del self._foo

class D(C):
    @C.foo.getter
    def foo(self):
        return self._foo * 2

    @foo.setter
    def foo(self, value):
        self._foo = value / 2
```

To learn more about how property works refer to [descriptors](http://docs.python.org/howto/descriptor.html).

Comment: It would be nice if your pre-2.6 and your 2.6 and 3.0 examples would actually present the exact same thing: classname is different, there are comments in the pre-2.6 version, the 2.6 and 3.0 versions don't contain initialization code.

Answer (score 48):

Many people don't know about the "dir" function. It's a great way to figure out what an object can do from the interpreter. For example, if you want to see a list of all the string methods:

```
>>> dir("foo")
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', (snipped a bunch), 'title',
 'translate', 'upper', 'zfill']
```

And then if you want more information about a particular method you can call "help" on it.

```
>>> help("foo".upper)
    Help on built-in function upper:

upper(...)
    S.upper() -> string

    Return a copy of the string S converted to uppercase.
```

Comment: dir() is essential for development. For large modules I've enhanced it to add filtering. See http://www.pixelbeat.org/scripts/inpy

Comment: You can also directly use help: help('foo')

Comment: If you use IPython, you can append a question mark to get help on a variable/method.

Comment: see: An alternative to Python's dir(). Easy to type; easy to read! For humans only: http://github.com/inky/see

Comment: I call this python's man pages and can also be implemented to work when 'man' is called rather than 'help'

Comment: @compie -- see() is very handy. Very nice!  So much easier to read than the output of dir()

Answer (score 47):

[**set/frozenset**](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set)

Probably an easily overlooked python builtin is "set/frozenset".

Useful when you have a list like this, [1,2,1,1,2,3,4] and only want the uniques like this [1,2,3,4].

Using set() that's exactly what you get:

```
>>> x = [1,2,1,1,2,3,4] 
>>> 
>>> set(x) 
set([1, 2, 3, 4]) 
>>>
>>> for i in set(x):
...     print i
...
1
2
3
4
```

And of course to get the number of uniques in a list:

```
>>> len(set([1,2,1,1,2,3,4]))
4
```

You can also find if a list is a subset of another list using set().issubset():

```
>>> set([1,2,3,4]).issubset([0,1,2,3,4,5])
True
```

As of Python 2.7 and 3.0 you can use curly braces to create a set:

```
myset = {1,2,3,4}
```

as well as set comprehensions:

```
{x for x in stuff}
```

For more details:
http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set

Comment: Also useful in cases where a dictionary were used only to test if a value is there.

Comment: I use set about as much as tuple and list.

Comment: for subsets, i believe it is `issubset` not `isasubset`.  either way, the subset operator `<=` is nicer anyway.

Comment: you can do dict comprehension too in python 2.7 like this { x:x*2 for x in range(3) } It's probably sort of confusing if you don't know what you are doing imho

Answer (score 46):

**Built-in base64, zlib, and rot13 codecs**

Strings have `encode` and `decode` methods.  Usually this is used for converting `str` to `unicode` and vice versa, e.g. with `u = s.encode('utf8')`.  But there are some other handy builtin codecs.  Compression and decompression with zlib (and bz2) is available without an explicit import:

```
>>> s = 'a' * 100
>>> s.encode('zlib')
'x\x9cKL\xa4=\x00\x00zG%\xe5'
```

Similarly you can encode and decode base64:

```
>>> 'Hello world'.encode('base64')
'SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=\n'
>>> 'SGVsbG8gd29ybGQ=\n'.decode('base64')
'Hello world'
```

And, of course, you can rot13:

```
>>> 'Secret message'.encode('rot13')
'Frperg zrffntr'
```

Comment: Sadly this will stop working in Python 3

Comment: Oh, will it stop working? That's too bad :/. I was just thinking how great this feature was. Then I saw your comment.

Comment: Awe, the base64 one was pretty useful in interactive sessions handling data from the web.

Comment: In my opionion it's some type of en/decoding, but on the other side there should "only one way to it" and I think, that these things are better put in its own module!

Answer (score 43):

**An interpreter within the interpreter**

The standard library's [code](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module let's you include your own read-eval-print loop inside a program, or run a whole nested interpreter. E.g. (copied my example from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/393871/scripting-inside-a-python-application#393921))

```
$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jan 17 2008, 19:35:17) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> shared_var = "Set in main console"
>>> import code
>>> ic = code.InteractiveConsole({ 'shared_var': shared_var })
>>> try:
...     ic.interact("My custom console banner!")
... except SystemExit, e:
...     print "Got SystemExit!"
... 
My custom console banner!
>>> shared_var
'Set in main console'
>>> shared_var = "Set in sub-console"
>>> import sys
>>> sys.exit()
Got SystemExit!
>>> shared_var
'Set in main console'
```

This is extremely useful for situations where you want to accept scripted input from the user, or query the state of the VM in real-time.

[TurboGears](http://turbogears.com/) uses this to great effect by having a WebConsole from which you can query the state of you live web app.

Answer (score 40):

```
>>> from functools import partial
>>> bound_func = partial(range, 0, 10)
>>> bound_func()
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> bound_func(2)
[0, 2, 4, 6, 8]
```

not really a hidden feature but partial is extremely useful for having late evaluation of functions.

you can bind as many or as few parameters in the initial call to partial as you want, and call it with any remaining parameters later (in this example i've bound the begin/end args to range, but call it the second time with a step arg)

See [the documentation](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/functools.html).

Comment: I wish curryfication add a decent operator in python though.

Answer (score 36):

While debugging complex data structures *pprint* module comes handy.

Quoting from the docs..

```
>>> import pprint    
>>> stuff = sys.path[:]
>>> stuff.insert(0, stuff)
>>> pprint.pprint(stuff)
[<Recursion on list with id=869440>,
 '',
 '/usr/local/lib/python1.5',
 '/usr/local/lib/python1.5/test',
 '/usr/local/lib/python1.5/sunos5',
 '/usr/local/lib/python1.5/sharedmodules',
 '/usr/local/lib/python1.5/tkinter']
```

Comment: pprint is also good for printing dictionaries in doctests, since it always sorts the output by keys

Answer (score 34):

**Python has GOTO**

...and it's implemented by [external pure-Python module](http://entrian.com/goto/) :)

```
from goto import goto, label
for i in range(1, 10):
    for j in range(1, 20):
        for k in range(1, 30):
            print i, j, k
            if k == 3:
                goto .end # breaking out from a deeply nested loop
label .end
print "Finished"
```

Comment: Maybe it is best that this feature remains hidden.

Comment: Well, the actual hidden feature here is mechanism used to implement GOTO.

Comment: Surely, for breaking out of a nested loop you can just raise an exception, no?

Comment: +1 first one I actually did not know about.

Comment: @shylent: Exceptions should be exceptional.  For that reason they are optimized for the case that they are not thrown.  If you expect the condition to occur in the course of normal processing, you should use another method

Comment: @shylent, the correct way to break out of a nested loop is to put the loop into a function, and return from the function

Comment: External modules should not be included in this list.  GOTO is not a feature of Python.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: not in Python. Exception are used internally to end loops using StopIteration. Exception are not exceptional at all.

Answer (score 32):

dict's constructor accepts keyword arguments:

```
>>> dict(foo=1, bar=2)
{'foo': 1, 'bar': 2}
```

Comment: So long as the keyword arguments are valid Python identifiers (names).  You can't use: dict(1="one", two=2 ...) because the "1" is not a valid identifier even though it's a perfectly valid dictionary key.

Comment: It's perfect for copy-and-update: base = {'a': 4, 'b': 5}; updated = dict(base, c=5)

Answer (score 29):

**Sequence multiplication and reflected operands**

```
>>> 'xyz' * 3
'xyzxyzxyz'

>>> [1, 2] * 3
[1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2]

>>> (1, 2) * 3
(1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2)
```

We get the same result with reflected (swapped) operands

```
>>> 3 * 'xyz'
'xyzxyzxyz'
```

It works like this:

```
>>> s = 'xyz'
>>> num = 3
```

To evaluate an expression **s * num** interpreter calls **s.___mul___(num)**

```
>>> s * num
'xyzxyzxyz'

>>> s.__mul__(num)
'xyzxyzxyz'
```

To evaluate an expression **num * s** interpreter calls **num.___mul___(s)**

```
>>> num * s
'xyzxyzxyz'

>>> num.__mul__(s)
NotImplemented
```

If the call returns ***NotImplemented*** then interpreter calls
a reflected operation **s.___rmul___(num)** if operands have different types

```
>>> s.__rmul__(num)
'xyzxyzxyz'
```

See [http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.**rmul**](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__rmul__)

Comment: +1 I knew about sequence multiplication, but the reflected operands are new to me.

Comment: @Space, it would be unpythonic to have `x * y != y * x`, after all :)

Comment: In python you **may** have x * y != y * x (it's just enough to play with the '__mul__' methods).

Comment: Seeing many questions about problems with `x= [] * 20`, i am thinking if it would be better to make shallow copies of the operands by default

Answer (score 28):

**Getter functions in module operator**

The functions `attrgetter()` and `itemgetter()` in module `operator` can be used to generate fast access functions for use in sorting and search objects and dictionaries

[Chapter 6.7](http://docs.python.org/lib/module-operator.html) in the Python Library Docs

Comment: This answer deserves good examples, for instance in conjunction with `map()`

Answer (score 28):

**Interleaving `if` and `for` in list comprehensions**

```
>>> [(x, y) for x in range(4) if x % 2 == 1 for y in range(4)]
[(1, 0), (1, 1), (1, 2), (1, 3), (3, 0), (3, 1), (3, 2), (3, 3)]
```

I never realized this until I learned Haskell.

Comment: way cool.  http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions

Comment: Not so cool, you are just having a list comprehension with two for loops. What is so surprising about that?

Comment: @Olivier: there's an if between the two for loops.

Comment: @Torsten: well, the list comprehension comprises already a for .. if, so what is so interesting? You can write: `[x for i in range(10) if i%2 for j in range(10) if j%2]`, nothing especially cool or interesting. The if in the middle of your example has nothing to do with the second for.

Comment: I was wondering, is there a way to do this with an else?

`[ a for (a, b) in zip(lista, listb) if a == b else: '-' ]`

Comment: in `[ _ for _ in _ if _ ]` the if is a filter for the example above it would need to be `[ _ if _ else _ for _ ]`

Answer (score 27):

Tuple unpacking:

```
>>> (a, (b, c), d) = [(1, 2), (3, 4), (5, 6)]
>>> a
(1, 2)
>>> b
3
>>> c, d
(4, (5, 6))
```

More obscurely, you can do this in function arguments (in Python 2.x; Python 3.x will not allow this anymore):

```
>>> def addpoints((x1, y1), (x2, y2)):
...     return (x1+x2, y1+y2)
>>> addpoints((5, 0), (3, 5))
(8, 5)
```

Comment: For what it's worth, tuple unpacking in function definitions is going aaway in python 3.0

Comment: Mostly because it makes the implementation really nasty, as far as I understand. (Eg.in inspect.getargs in the standard library - the normal path (no tuple args) is about 10 lines, and there are about 30 extra lines for handling tuple args (which only gets used occasionally).)
Makes me sad though.

Comment: Looks like they are removing some of the batteries in 3.0 :/ .

Comment: It's good, that they remove it, because it's ugly and you can just emulate this, by typing: `x1, x2 = x; y1, y2 = y` (if you have x,y arguments)

Comment: That's a shame. I was hoping support for * would be added for remaining arguments, so you could do stuff like a, b, *c = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5] (equivalent to a = 1, b = 2, c = [3, 4, 5]).

Comment: @yangyang: that *was* added. The only thing that was removed is the tuple unpacking in function definitions. Instead, you just move such unpacking to the first line of the function implementation.

Answer (score 27):

Obviously, the antigravity module.
[xkcd #353](http://xkcd.com/353/)

Comment: Probably my most used module. After the soul module, of course.

Comment: Which actually works. Try putting "import antigravity" in the newest Py3K.

Comment: @Andrew Szeto... what does it do?

Comment: @Jim Robert: It opens up the webbrowser to the xkcd site ;)

Comment: the skynet module is quite useful too…

Answer (score 26):

**The Python Interpreter**

```
>>>
```

Maybe not lesser known, but certainly one of my favorite features of Python.

Comment: The #1 reason Python is better than everything else. </fanboi>

Comment: Everything else you've seen. </smuglispweenie>

Comment: And it also has iPython which is much better than the default interpreter

Comment: I wish I could use iPython like SLIME in all of its glory

Answer (score 25):

Python sort function sorts tuples correctly (i.e. using the familiar lexicographical order):

```
a = [(2, "b"), (1, "a"), (2, "a"), (3, "c")]
print sorted(a)
#[(1, 'a'), (2, 'a'), (2, 'b'), (3, 'c')]
```

Useful if you want to sort a list of persons after age and then name.

Comment: This is a consequence of tuple comparison working correctly in general, i.e. (1, 2) < (1, 3).

Comment: This is useful for version tuples: (1, 9) < (1, 10).

Answer (score 25):

#### Referencing a list comprehension as it is being built...

You can reference a list comprehension as it is being built by the symbol '_[1]'.  For example, the following function unique-ifies a list of elements without changing their order by referencing its list comprehension.

```
def unique(my_list):
    return [x for x in my_list if x not in locals()['_[1]']]
```

Comment: Nifty trick. Do you know if this is accepted behavior or is it more of a dirty hack that may change in the future? The underscore makes me think the latter.

Comment: Interesting. I think it'd be a dirty hack of the locals() dictionary, but I'd be curious to know for sure.

Comment: Brilliant, I was literally just looking for this yesterday!

Comment: not a good idea for algorithmic as well as practical reasons. Algorithmically, this will give you a linear search of the list so far on every iteration, changing your O(n) loop into O(n**2); much better to just make the list into a set afterwards. Practically speaking, it's undocumented, may change, and probably doesn't work in ironpython/jython/pypy .

Comment: This is an undocumented implementation detail, not a hidden feature.  It would be a bad idea to rely on this.

Comment: If you want to reference the list as you're building it, use an ordinary loop. This is very implementation dependent - CPython uses a hidden name in the locals dict because it is convenient, but other implementations are under no obligation to do the same thing.

Answer (score 25):

The unpacking syntax has been upgraded in the recent version as can be seen in the example.

```
>>> a, *b = range(5)
>>> a, b
(0, [1, 2, 3, 4])
>>> *a, b = range(5)
>>> a, b
([0, 1, 2, 3], 4)
>>> a, *b, c = range(5)
>>> a, b, c
(0, [1, 2, 3], 4)
```

Comment: never seen this before, it's pretty nice!

Comment: which version? as this doesn't work in 2.5.2

Comment: works with 3.1, but not with 2.7

Comment: Nice - been hoping for that! Shame the destructuring went.

Answer (score 25):

The simplicity of :

```
>>> 'str' in 'string'
True
>>> 'no' in 'yes'
False
>>>
```

is something i love about Python, I have seen a lot of not very pythonic idiom like that instead :

```
if 'yes'.find("no") == -1:
    pass
```

Comment: I'm conflicted about this, because it's inconsistent with the `in` behavior on other kinds of sequences. `1 in [3, 2, 1]` is `True`, but `[2, 1] in [3, 2, 1]` is `False`, and it could really be a problem if it were `True`.  But that's what would be needed to make it consistent with the string behavior explained here. So I think the `.find()` approach is actually more Pythonic, although of course `.find()` ought to have returned `None` instead of -1.

Comment: Also note: 'str' not in 'abc' #true

Answer (score 24):

**Metaclasses**

of course :-) [What is a metaclass in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/100003/what-is-a-metaclass-in-python)

Answer (score 24):

I personally love the **3 different quotes**

```
str = "I'm a string 'but still I can use quotes' inside myself!"
str = """ For some messy multi line strings.
Such as
<html>
<head> ... </head>"""
```

Also cool: not having to escape regular expressions, avoiding horrible backslash salad by using **raw strings**:

```
str2 = r"\n" 
print str2
>> \n
```

Comment: _Four_ different quotes, if you include `'''`

Comment: I enjoy having `'` and `"` do pretty much the same thing in code.  My IDE highlights strings from the two in different colors, and it makes it easy to differentiate short strings (with `'`) from longer ones (with `"`).

Answer (score 23):

**Generators**

I think that a lot of beginning Python developers pass over generators without really grasping what they're for or getting any sense of their power.  It wasn't until I read David M. Beazley's PyCon presentation on generators (it's available [here](http://www.dabeaz.com/generators/)) that I realized how useful (essential, really) they are.  That presentation illuminated what was for me an entirely new way of programming, and I recommend it to anyone who doesn't have a deep understanding of generators.

Comment: Wow! My brain is fried and that was just the first 6 parts. Starting in 7 I had to start drawing pictures just to see if I really understood what was happening with multi-process / multi-thread / multi-machine processing pipelines. Amazing stuff!

Comment: +1 for the link to the presentation

Answer (score 22):

Implicit concatenation:

```
>>> print "Hello " "World"
Hello World
```

Useful when you want to make a long text fit on several lines in a script:

```
hello = "Greaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Hello " \
        "Word"
```

or

```
hello = ("Greaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa Hello " 
         "Word")
```

Comment: To make a long text fit on several lines, you can also use the triple quotes.

Comment: Your example is wrong and misleading. After running it, the "Word" part won't be on the end of the hello string. It won't concatenate. To continue on next line like that, you would need implicit line continuation and string concatenation and that only happens if you use some delimiter like () or [].

Comment: Only one thing was wrong here: the tab before "word" (typo). What's more, you are really unfriendly, espacially for somebody who didn't even take the time to check if it works (since you would have seen it does). You may want to read that : steve.yegge.googlepages.com/bambi-meets-godzilla

Comment: Anyone who has ever forgotten a comma in a list of strings knows how evil this 'feature' is.

Comment: Well, a PEP had been set to get rid of it but Guido decided finally to keep it. I guess it's more useful than hateful. Actually the drawbacks are no so dangerous (no safety issues) and for long strings, it helps a lot.

Comment: This is probably my favorite feature of Python. You can forget correct syntax and it's still correct syntax.

Comment: even better: hello = "Greaaaaa Hello \<pretend there's a line break here>World"

Comment: I always write a `+` at the end of the line (though I still do use the implicit line continuations from parentheses).  It just makes things clearer to read.

Answer (score 22):

When using the interactive shell, "_" contains the value of the last printed item:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> _
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>>
```

Comment: I always forget about this one! It's a great feature.

Comment: `_` automatic variable is the best feature when using Python shell as a calculator. Very powerful calculator, by the way.

Comment: I still try to use %% in the python shell from too much Mathematica in a previous life...  If only %% were a valid variable name, I'd set %% = _...

Comment: This was already given by someone (I don't know if it was earlier, but it is voted higher).

Comment: `__` for second-last and `___` for third-last

Answer (score 22):

The [`textwrap.dedent`](http://docs.python.org/library/textwrap.html#textwrap.dedent) utility function in python can come quite in handy testing that a multiline string returned is equal to the expected output without breaking the indentation of your unittests:

```
import unittest, textwrap

class XMLTests(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_returned_xml_value(self):
        returned_xml = call_to_function_that_returns_xml()
        expected_value = textwrap.dedent("""\
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
        <root_node>
            <my_node>my_content</my_node>
        </root_node>
        """)

        self.assertEqual(expected_value, returned_xml)
```

Answer (score 22):

### Zero-argument and variable-argument lambdas

Lambda functions are usually used for a quick transformation of one value into another, but they can also be used to wrap a value in a function:

```
>>> f = lambda: 'foo'
>>> f()
'foo'
```

They can also accept the usual `*args` and `**kwargs` syntax:

```
>>> g = lambda *args, **kwargs: args[0], kwargs['thing']
>>> g(1, 2, 3, thing='stuff')
(1, 'stuff')
```

Comment: The main reason I see to keep lambda around: `defaultdict(lambda: 1)`

Answer (score 21):

**Using keyword arguments as assignments**

Sometimes one wants to build a range of functions depending on one or more parameters. However this might easily lead to closures all referring to the same object and value:

```
funcs = [] 
for k in range(10):
     funcs.append( lambda: k)

>>> funcs[0]()
9
>>> funcs[7]()
9
```

This behaviour can be avoided by turning the lambda expression into a function depending only on its arguments. A keyword parameter stores the current value that is bound to it. The function call doesn't have to be altered:

```
funcs = [] 
for k in range(10):
     funcs.append( lambda k = k: k)

>>> funcs[0]()
0
>>> funcs[7]()
7
```

Comment: A less hackish way to do that (imho) is just to use a separate function to manufacture lambdas that don't close on a loop variable. Like this: `def make_lambda(k): return lambda: k`.

Comment: "less hackish"?....it's personal preference, I guess, but this is core Python stuff -- not really a hack.  You certainly can structure it ( using functions ) so that the reader does not need to understand how Python's default arguments work -- but if you do understand how default arguments work, you will read the `"lambda: k=k:k"` and understand immediately that it is "saving" the current value of "k" ( as the lambda is created ), and attaching it to the lambda itself.  This works the same with normal "def" functions, too.

Comment: Jason Orendorff's answer is correct, but this is how we used to emulate closures in Python before Guido finally agreed that nested scopes were a good idea.

Answer (score 20):

**Mod works correctly with negative numbers**

-1 % 5 is ***4***, as it should be, not -1 as it is in other languages like JavaScript. This makes "wraparound windows" cleaner in Python, you just do this:

```
index = (index + increment) % WINDOW_SIZE
```

Comment: In most languages, `number = coefficient x quotient + remainder`.  In Python (and Ruby), `quotient` is different than in JavaScript (or C or Java), because integer division in Python rounds towards negative infinity, but in JavaScript it rounds towards zero (truncates).  I agree that `%` in Python makes more sense, but I don't know if `/` does.  See http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modulo_operation for details on each language.

Comment: In general, if abs(increment) < WINDOW_SIZE, then you can say index = (index + WINDOW_SIZE + increment) in any language, and have it do the right thing.

Answer (score 19):

**First-class functions**

It's not really a hidden feature, but the fact that functions are first class objects is simply great. You can pass them around like any other variable.

```
>>> def jim(phrase):
...   return 'Jim says, "%s".' % phrase
>>> def say_something(person, phrase):
...   print person(phrase)

>>> say_something(jim, 'hey guys')
'Jim says, "hey guys".'
```

Comment: This also makes callback and hook creation (and, thus, plugin creation for your Python scripts) so trivial that you might not even know you're doing it.

Comment: Any langauge that doesn't have first class functions (or at least some good substitute, like C function pointers) it is a misfeature.  It is completely unbearable to go without.

Comment: This might be a stupider question than I intend, but isn't this essentially a function pointer? Or do I have this mixed up?

Comment: @inspectorG4dget: It's certainly related to function pointers, in that it can accomplish all of the same purposes, but it's slightly more general, more powerful, and more intuitive.  Particularly powerful when you combine it with the fact that functions can have attributes, or the fact that instances of certain classes can be called, but that starts to get arcane.

Answer (score 19):

**Ternary operator**

```
>>> 'ham' if True else 'spam'
'ham'
>>> 'ham' if False else 'spam'
'spam'
```

This was added in 2.5, prior to that you could use:

```
>>> True and 'ham' or 'spam'
'ham'
>>> False and 'ham' or 'spam'
'spam'
```

However, if the values you want to work with would be considered false, there is a difference:

```
>>> [] if True else 'spam'
[]
>>> True and [] or 'spam'
'spam'
```

Comment: Prior to 2.5, "foo = bar and 'ham' or 'spam'"

Comment: @a paid nerd - not quite: 1 == 1 and 0 or 3 => 3. The and short circuits on the 0 (as it equivalent to False - same deal with "" and None).

Answer (score 19):

Assigning and deleting slices:

```
>>> a = range(10)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a[:5] = [42]
>>> a
[42, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> a[:1] = range(5)
>>> a
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> del a[::2]
>>> a
[1, 3, 5, 7, 9]
>>> a[::2] = a[::-2]
>>> a
[9, 3, 5, 7, 1]
```

*Note*: when assigning to extended slices (`s[start:stop:step]`), the assigned iterable must have the same length as the slice.

Answer (score 19):

Not very hidden, but functions have attributes:

```
def doNothing():
    pass

doNothing.monkeys = 4
print doNothing.monkeys
4
```

Comment: It's because functions can be though of as objects with __call__() function defined.

Comment: It's because functions can be thought of as descriptors with __call__() function defined.

Comment: Wait, does `__call__()` also have a `__call__()` function?

Comment: I'll bet it's __call__() functions all the way down.

Answer (score 19):

### Passing tuple to builtin functions

Much Python functions accept tuples, also it doesn't seem like. For example you want to test if your variable is a number, you could do:

```
if isinstance (number, float) or isinstance (number, int):  
   print "yaay"
```

But if you pass us tuple this looks much cleaner:

```
if isinstance (number, (float, int)):  
   print "yaay"
```

Comment: cool, is this even documented?

Comment: Yes, but nearly nobody knows about that.

Comment: What other functions support this?? Good tip

Comment: Not sure about other functions, but this is supposed in `except (FooError, BarError)` clauses.

Answer (score 19):

Nice treatment of infinite recursion in dictionaries:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = {}
>>> a['b'] = b
>>> b['a'] = a
>>> print a
{'b': {'a': {...}}}
```

Comment: That is just the 'nice treatment' of "print", it doesn't imply a nice treatment across the language.

Comment: Both `str()` and `repr()` return the string you posted above. However, the `ipython` shell returns something a little different, a little more informative: {'b': {'a': <Recursion on dict with id=17830960>}}

Comment: @denilson: ipython uses pprint module, which is available whithin standard python shell.

Comment: +1 for the first one that I had absolutely no idea about whatsoever.

Answer (score 18):

reversing an iterable using negative step

```
>>> s = "Hello World"
>>> s[::-1]
'dlroW olleH'
>>> a = (1,2,3,4,5,6)
>>> a[::-1]
(6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 1)
>>> a = [5,4,3,2,1]
>>> a[::-1]
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
```

Comment: Good to know, but minor point: that only works with sequences not iterables in general.  I.e., `(n for n in (1,2,3,4,5))[::-1]` doesn't work.

Comment: That notation will actually create a new (reversed) instance of that sequence, which might be undesirable in some cases. For such cases, `reversed()` function is better, as it returns a reverse iterator instead of allocating a new sequence.

Answer (score 18):

Not "hidden" but quite useful and not commonly used

Creating string joining functions quickly like so

```
 comma_join = ",".join
 semi_join  = ";".join

 print comma_join(["foo","bar","baz"])
 'foo,bar,baz
```

and

Ability to create lists of strings more elegantly than the quote, comma mess.

```
l = ["item1", "item2", "item3"]
```

replaced by

```
l = "item1 item2 item3".split()
```

Comment: I think these both make the thing more long and obfuscated.

Comment: I don't know. I've found places where judicious use made things easier to read.

Answer (score 18):

Arguably, this is not a *programming* feature per se, but so useful that I'll post it nevertheless.

```
$ python -m http.server
```

...followed by `$ wget http://<ipnumber>:8000/filename` somewhere else.

If you are still running an older (2.x) version of Python:

```
$ python -m SimpleHTTPServer
```

You can also specify a port e.g. `python -m http.server 80` (so you can omit the port in the url if you have the root on the server side)

Answer (score 17):

**Multiple references to an iterator**

You can create multiple references to the same iterator using list multiplication:

```
>>> i = (1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10) # or any iterable object
>>> iterators = [iter(i)] * 2
>>> iterators[0].next()
1
>>> iterators[1].next()
2
>>> iterators[0].next()
3
```

This can be used to group an iterable into chunks, for example, as in this example from the [`itertools` documentation](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html)

```
def grouper(n, iterable, fillvalue=None):
    "grouper(3, 'ABCDEFG', 'x') --> ABC DEF Gxx"
    args = [iter(iterable)] * n
    return izip_longest(fillvalue=fillvalue, *args)
```

Comment: You can do the opposite with `itertools.tee` -- take one iterator and return `n` that yield the same but do not share state.

Comment: I actually don't see the difference to doing this one: "a = iter(i)" and subsequently "b = a" I also get multiple references to the same iterator -- there is no magic about that to me, no hidden feature it is just the normal reference copying stuff of the language. What is done, is creating the iterator, then (the list multiplication) copying this iterator several times. Thats all, its all in the language.

Comment: @Juergen: indeed, `a = iter(i); b = a` does the same thing and I could just as well have written that into the answer instead of `[iter(i)] * n`. Either way, there is no "magic" about it. That's no different from any of the other answers to this question - none of them are "magical", they are all in the language. What makes the features "hidden" is that many people don't realize they're possible, or don't realize interesting ways in which they can be used, until they are pointed out explicitly.

Comment: Well, for one thing, you can do it an arbitrary number of times with `[iter(i)]*n`.  Also, it isn't necessarily well known (to many people's peril) that `list*int` creates referential, not actual, copies of the elements of the list. It's good to see that that is actually useful somehow.

Answer (score 17):

From python 3.1 ( 2.7 ) dictionary and set comprehensions are supported :

```
{ a:a for a in range(10) }
{ a for a in range(10) }
```

Comment: there is no such thing as tuples comprehension, and this is not a syntax for dict comprehensions.

Comment: Edited the typo with dict comprehensions.

Comment: uh oh, looks like I have to upgrade my version of python so I can play with dict and set comprehensions

Comment: for dictionaries that way is better but `dict( (a,a) for a in range(10) )` works too and your error is probably due to remembering this form

Comment: I cannot *wait* to use this feature.

Answer (score 15):

Python [can understand any kind of unicode digits](http://bugs.python.org/issue6595), not just the ASCII kind:

```
>>> s = u'１０５８５'
>>> s
u'\uff11\uff10\uff15\uff18\uff15'
>>> print s
１０５８５
>>> int(s)
10585
>>> float(s)
10585.0
```

Answer (score 14):

`__slots__` is a nice way to save memory, but it's very hard to get a dict of the values of the object.  Imagine the following object:

```
class Point(object):
    __slots__ = ('x', 'y')
```

Now that object obviously has two attributes.  Now we can create an instance of it and build a dict of it this way:

```
>>> p = Point()
>>> p.x = 3
>>> p.y = 5
>>> dict((k, getattr(p, k)) for k in p.__slots__)
{'y': 5, 'x': 3}
```

This however won't work if point was subclassed and new slots were added.  However Python automatically implements `__reduce_ex__` to help the `copy` module.  This can be abused to get a dict of values:

```
>>> p.__reduce_ex__(2)[2][1]
{'y': 5, 'x': 3}
```

Comment: Oh wow, I might actually have good use for this!

Comment: Beware that `__reduce_ex__` can be overridden in subclasses, and since it's also used for pickling, it often is. (If you're making data containers, you should think of using it too! or it's younger siblings `__getstate__` and `__setstate__`.)

Comment: You can still do `object.__reduce_ex__(p, 2)[2][1]` then.

Answer (score 14):

**itertools**

This module is often overlooked.  The following example uses `itertools.chain()`
to flatten a list:

```
>>> from itertools import *
>>> l = [[1, 2], [3, 4]]
>>> list(chain(*l))
[1, 2, 3, 4]
```

See http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#recipes for more applications.

Answer (score 14):

### Manipulating sys.modules

You can manipulate the modules cache directly, making modules available or unavailable as you wish:

```
>>> import sys
>>> import ham
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ham

# Make the 'ham' module available -- as a non-module object even!
>>> sys.modules['ham'] = 'ham, eggs, saussages and spam.'
>>> import ham
>>> ham
'ham, eggs, saussages and spam.'

# Now remove it again.
>>> sys.modules['ham'] = None
>>> import ham
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named ham
```

This works even for modules that *are* available, and to some extent for modules that *already are imported*:

```
>>> import os
# Stop future imports of 'os'.
>>> sys.modules['os'] = None
>>> import os
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: No module named os
# Our old imported module is still available.
>>> os
<module 'os' from '/usr/lib/python2.5/os.pyc'>
```

As the last line shows, changing sys.modules only affects future `import` statements, not past ones, so if you want to affect other modules it's important to make these changes *before* you give them a chance to try and import the modules -- so before you import them, typically. `None` is a special value in `sys.modules`, used for negative caching (indicating the module was not found the first time, so there's no point in looking again.) Any other value will be the result of the `import` operation -- even when it is not a module object. You can use this to replace modules with objects that behave exactly like you want. Deleting the entry from `sys.modules` entirely causes the next `import` to do a normal search for the module, even if it was already imported before.

Comment: And you can do `sys.modules['my_module'] = MyClass()`, to implement read only attributes 'module' if MyClass has the right hooks.

Answer (score 14):

You can ask any object which module it came from by looking at its __ module__ property. This is useful, for example, if you're experimenting at the command line and have imported a lot of things.

Along the same lines, you can ask a module where it came from by looking at its __ file__ property.  This is useful when debugging path issues.

Answer (score 13):

Some of the **builtin** favorites, map(), reduce(), and filter(). All extremely fast and powerful.

Comment: Be careful of reduce(),  If you're not careful, you can write really slow reductions.

Comment: And be careful of map(), it's depreciated in 2.6 and removed in 3.0.

Comment: list comprehensions can achieve everything you can do with any of those functions.

Comment: It can also obfuscate Python code if you abuse them

Comment: @sil: map still exists in Python 3, as does filter, and reduce exists as functools.reduce.

Comment: @recursive: I defy you to produce a list comprehension/generator expression that performs the action of `reduce()`

Comment: The correct statement is "`reduce()` can achieve everything you can do with `map()`, `filter()`, or list comprehensions."

Answer (score 13):

One word: [IPython](http://ipython.scipy.org/moin/)

Tab introspection, pretty-printing, `%debug`, history management, `pylab`, ... well worth the time to learn well.

Comment: That's not built in python core is it?

Comment: You're right, it's not. And probably with good reason. But I recommend it without reservation to any Python programmer. (However, I heartily recommend turning off autocall. When it does something you don't expect, it can be very hard to realize why.)

Comment: I also love IPython. I've tried BPython, but it was too slow for me (although I agree it has some cool features).

Answer (score 13):

**Guessing integer base**

```
>>> int('10', 0)
10
>>> int('0x10', 0)
16
>>> int('010', 0)  # does not work on Python 3.x
8
>>> int('0o10', 0)  # Python >=2.6 and Python 3.x
8
>>> int('0b10', 0)  # Python >=2.6 and Python 3.x
2
```

Answer (score 12):

You can build up a dictionary from a set of length-2 sequences.  Extremely handy when you have a list of values and a list of arrays.

```
>>> dict([ ('foo','bar'),('a',1),('b',2) ])
{'a': 1, 'b': 2, 'foo': 'bar'}

>>> names = ['Bob', 'Marie', 'Alice']
>>> ages = [23, 27, 36]
>>> dict(zip(names, ages))
{'Alice': 36, 'Bob': 23, 'Marie': 27}
```

Comment: self.data = {}
_i = 0
for keys in self.VDESC.split():
    self.data[keys] = _data[_i]
    _i += 1

I replaced my code with this one-liner :)

self.data = dict(zip(self.VDESC.split(), _data))

Thanks for the handy tip.

Comment: Also helps in Python2.x where there is no dict comprehension syntax. Sou you can write `dict((x, x**2) for x in range(10))`.

Answer (score 12):

### Extending properties (defined as descriptor) in subclasses

Sometimes it's useful to extent (modify) value "returned" by descriptor in subclass. It can be easily done with `super()`:

```
class A(object):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return {'a': 1}

class B(A):
    @property
    def prop(self):
        return dict(super(B, self).prop, b=2)
```

Store this in `test.py` and run `python -i test.py` (**another hidden feature: `-i` option executed the script and allow you to continue in interactive mode**):

```
>>> B().prop
{'a': 1, 'b': 2}
```

Comment: +1 properties! Cant get enough of them.

Answer (score 11):

A slight misfeature of python.  The normal fast way to join a list of strings together is,

```
''.join(list_of_strings)
```

Comment: there are very good reasons that this is a method of string instead of a method of list. this allows the same function to join any iterable, instead of duplicating join for every iterable type.

Comment: Yes I know why it does - but would anyone discover this if they hadn't been told?

Comment: Discover? It's pretty hard to remember too, and I've used python since before there were methods om strings.

Comment: If this is too ugly for you to cope with, you can write the very same thing as `str.join('',list_of_strings)` but other pythonistas may scorn you for trying to write java.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy: the reason why ''.join([...]) is preferred is because many people often mixes up the order of the arguments in string.join(..., ...); by putting ''.join() things become clearer

Comment: I'm fairly certain that the only reason most pythonistas use `"".join(iterable)` over `str.join("",iterable)` is because it's 4 characters shorter.

Comment: @TokenMacGuy No. And what is wrong with having split and join in the str-class? It IS easy to remember and btw. this is an example of 'Although practicality beats purity.'

Answer (score 11):

**Creating enums**

In Python, you can do this to quickly create an enumeration:

```
>>> FOO, BAR, BAZ = range(3)
>>> FOO
0
```

But the "enums" don't have to have integer values. You can even do this:

```
class Colors(object):
    RED, GREEN, BLUE, YELLOW = (255,0,0), (0,255,0), (0,0,255), (0,255,255)

#now Colors.RED is a 3-tuple that returns the 24-bit 8bpp RGB 
#value for saturated red
```

Answer (score 11):

**The Object Data Model**

You can override *any* operator in the language for your own classes.  See [this page](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html) for a complete list.  Some examples:

- You can override any operator (`* + - / // % ^ == < > <= >= .` etc.). All this is done by overriding `__mul__`, `__add__`, etc. in your objects.  You can even override things like `__rmul__` to handle separately `your_object*something_else` and `something_else*your_object`.  `.` is attribute access (`a.b`), and can be overridden to handle any arbitrary `b` by using `__getattr__`.  Also included here is `a(…)` using `__call__`.
- You can create your own slice syntax (`a[stuff]`), which can be very complicated and quite different from the standard syntax used in lists (numpy has a good example of the power of this in their arrays) using any combination of `,`, `:`, and `…` that you like, using Slice objects.
- Handle specially what happens with many keywords in the language.  Included are `del`, `in`, `import`, and `not`.
- Handle what happens when many built in functions are called with your object.  The standard `__int__`, `__str__`, etc. go here, but so do `__len__`, `__reversed__`, `__abs__`, and the three argument `__pow__` (for modular exponentiation).

Comment: For `in` you have to override `__contains__`.

Answer (score 11):

The `re.Scanner` class. http://code.activestate.com/recipes/457664-hidden-scanner-functionality-in-re-module/

Answer (score 10):

**"Unpacking" to function parameters**

```
def foo(a, b, c):
        print a, b, c

bar = (3, 14, 15)
foo(*bar)
```

When executed prints:

```
3 14 15
```

Comment: This is the canonical alternative to the old "apply()" built-in.

Answer (score 10):

The `reversed()` builtin. It makes iterating much cleaner in many cases.

quick example:

```
for i in reversed([1, 2, 3]):
    print(i)
```

produces:

```
3
2
1
```

However, `reversed()` also works with arbitrary iterators, such as lines in a file, or generator expressions.

Answer (score 10):

**The Zen of Python**

```
>>> import this
The Zen of Python, by Tim Peters

Beautiful is better than ugly.
Explicit is better than implicit.
Simple is better than complex.
Complex is better than complicated.
Flat is better than nested.
Sparse is better than dense.
Readability counts.
Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules.
Although practicality beats purity.
Errors should never pass silently.
Unless explicitly silenced.
In the face of ambiguity, refuse the temptation to guess.
There should be one-- and preferably only one --obvious way to do it.
Although that way may not be obvious at first unless you're Dutch.
Now is better than never.
Although never is often better than *right* now.
If the implementation is hard to explain, it's a bad idea.
If the implementation is easy to explain, it may be a good idea.
Namespaces are one honking great idea -- let's do more of those!
```

Comment: Hidden? OTOH, This is one of the selling points of Python.

Comment: I like the syntax coloring, esp. for `Dutch`.

Comment: Duplicate of a previous answer

Comment: Duplicate of a previous answer

Answer (score 10):

Changing function label at run time:

```
>>> class foo:
...   def normal_call(self): print "normal_call"
...   def call(self): 
...     print "first_call"
...     self.call = self.normal_call

>>> y = foo()
>>> y.call()
first_call
>>> y.call()
normal_call
>>> y.call()
normal_call
...
```

Answer (score 10):

**`string-escape` and `unicode-escape` encodings**

Lets say you have a string from outer source, that contains `\n`, `\t` and so on. How to transform them into new-line or tab? Just decode string using `string-escape` encoding!

```
>>> print s
Hello\nStack\toverflow
>>> print s.decode('string-escape')
Hello
Stack   overflow
```

Another problem. You have normal string with unicode literals like `\u01245`. How to make it work? Just decode string using `unicode-escape` encoding!

```
>>> s = '\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442, \u0441\u0432\u0456\u0442!'
>>> print s
\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442, \u0441\u0432\u0456\u0442!
>>> print unicode(s)
\u041f\u0440\u0438\u0432\u0456\u0442, \u0441\u0432\u0456\u0442!
>>> print unicode(s, 'unicode-escape')
Привіт, світ!
```

Answer (score 9):

[unzip un-needed in Python](http://paddy3118.blogspot.com/2007/02/unzip-un-needed-in-python.html)

Someone blogged about Python not having an unzip function to go with zip(). unzip is straight-forward to calculate because:

```
>>> t1 = (0,1,2,3)
>>> t2 = (7,6,5,4)
>>> [t1,t2] == zip(*zip(t1,t2))
True
```

On reflection though, I'd rather have an explicit unzip().

Comment: def unzip(x): return zip(*x)  Done!

Comment: The solution is slightly subtle (I can understand the point of view of anyone who asks for it), but I can also see why it would be redundant

Comment: +1.  I was going to add this, but it seems I was beat to it.

Answer (score 9):

Creating dictionary of two sequences that have related data

```
In [15]: t1 = (1, 2, 3)

In [16]: t2 = (4, 5, 6)

In [17]: dict (zip(t1,t2))
Out[17]: {1: 4, 2: 5, 3: 6}
```

Answer (score 9):

**Top Secret Attributes**

```
>>> class A(object): pass
>>> a = A()
>>> setattr(a, "can't touch this", 123)
>>> dir(a)
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__', "can't touch this"]
>>> a.can't touch this # duh
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    a.can't touch this
                     ^
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> getattr(a, "can't touch this")
123
>>> setattr(a, "__class__.__name__", ":O")
>>> a.__class__.__name__
'A'
>>> getattr(a, "__class__.__name__")
':O'
```

Comment: AHHHH!  Bad, bad, bad!

Answer (score 9):

### namedtuple is a tuple

```
>>> node = namedtuple('node', "a b")
>>> node(1,2) + node(5,6)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
>>> (node(1,2), node(5,6))
(node(a=1, b=2), node(a=5, b=6))
>>>
```

Some more experiments to respond to comments:

```
>>> from collections import namedtuple
>>> from operator import *
>>> mytuple = namedtuple('A', "a b")
>>> yourtuple = namedtuple('Z', "x y")
>>> mytuple(1,2) + yourtuple(5,6)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
>>> q = [mytuple(1,2), yourtuple(5,6)]
>>> q
[A(a=1, b=2), Z(x=5, y=6)]
>>> reduce(operator.__add__, q)
(1, 2, 5, 6)
```

So, `namedtuple` is an *interesting* subtype of `tuple`.

Comment: At this point, you've lost all context. If you don't need the context, or the data isn't structured in a particular way, why a tuple at all? Surely you're just using it as a list?

Comment: @Samir Talwar The question/answer is about hidden features. Did you know about this one? I'm not defending one design or the other, but just pointing out what is there. When I first tried to use named tuples, I thought they woulnd't match as tuples do, but... Let me expand the example to show you.

Comment: @Apalala: I had assumed it, but never checked. You're right: it is an interesting and hidden feature. I guess *useful* is a different thing.

Comment: Also fun is that you can feed the result of a `namedtuple` call directly into a class definition, as in `class rectangle(namedtuple("rectangle", "width height")):` in order to add custom methods

Comment: @Samir Talwar I use `namedtuple`s as the representation for parse trees, and their behavior was useful in merging siblings so they looked more like lists. Imagine the typical grammar productions for a list...

Comment: @Apalala: OK, you've sold me. Can't say it's how I would approach the problem, but the feature is clearly useful.

Comment: @Ben Blank. I didn't understand your comment about feeding nametuples to classes.

Comment: @Apalala — Here's an example: http://pastebin.com/d6e5VMgb

Comment: @Ben Blank. Incredible! It merits its own answer.

Answer (score 9):

**Dynamically added attributes**

This might be useful if you think about adding some attributes to your classes just by calling them. This can be done by overriding the [`__getattribute__`](http://docs.python.org/reference/datamodel.html#object.__getattribute__) member function which is called when the dot operand is used. So, let's see a dummy class for example:

```
class Dummy(object):
    def __getattribute__(self, name):
        f = lambda: 'Hello with %s'%name
        return f
```

When you instantiate a Dummy object and do a method call you’ll get the following:

```
>>> d = Dummy()
>>> d.b()
'Hello with b'
```

Finally, you can even set the attribute to your class so it can be dynamically defined. This could be useful if you work with Python web frameworks and want to do queries by parsing the attribute's name.

I have a [gist](https://gist.github.com/792865) at github with this simple code and its equivalent on Ruby made by a friend.

Take care!

Answer (score 9):

### Flattening a [`list`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) with [`sum()`](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/functions.html#sum).

The [`sum()`](http://www.python.org/doc/current/library/functions.html#sum) built-in function can be used to [`__add__`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/reference/datamodel.html#object.__add__) [`list`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange)s together, providing a handy way to flatten a [`list`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange) of [`list`](http://www.python.org/doc//current/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-unicode-list-tuple-buffer-xrange)s:

```
Python 2.7.1 (r271:86832, May 27 2011, 21:41:45) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5664)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> l = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5], [6], [7, 8, 9]]
>>> sum(l, [])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
```

Answer (score 9):

### The Borg Pattern

This is a killer from [Alex Martelli](https://stackoverflow.com/users/95810/alex-martelli). All instances of `Borg` share state. This removes the need to employ the singleton pattern (instances don't matter when state is shared) and is rather elegant (but is more complicated with new classes).

The value of `foo` can be reassigned in any instance and all will be updated, you can even reassign the entire dict. Borg is the perfect name, read more [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/66531/).

```
class Borg:
    __shared_state = {'foo': 'bar'}
    def __init__(self):
        self.__dict__ = self.__shared_state
    # rest of your class here
```

This is perfect for sharing an eventlet.GreenPool to control concurrency.

Answer (score 8):

**pdb — The Python Debugger**

As a programmer, one of the first things that you need for serious program development is a debugger. Python has one built-in which is available as a module called pdb (for "Python DeBugger", naturally!).

http://docs.python.org/library/pdb.html

Answer (score 8):

threading.enumerate() gives access to all Thread objects in the system and sys._current_frames() returns  the current stack frames of all threads in the system, so combine these two and you get Java style stack dumps:

```
def dumpstacks(signal, frame):
    id2name = dict([(th.ident, th.name) for th in threading.enumerate()])
    code = []
    for threadId, stack in sys._current_frames().items():
        code.append("\n# Thread: %s(%d)" % (id2name[threadId], threadId))
        for filename, lineno, name, line in traceback.extract_stack(stack):
            code.append('File: "%s", line %d, in %s' % (filename, lineno, name))
            if line:
                code.append("  %s" % (line.strip()))
    print "\n".join(code)

import signal
signal.signal(signal.SIGQUIT, dumpstacks)
```

Do this at the beginning of a multi-threaded python program and you get access to current state of threads at any time by sending a SIGQUIT. You may also choose signal.SIGUSR1 or signal.SIGUSR2.

[See](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/132058/getting-stack-trace-from-a-running-python-application/2569696#2569696)

Answer (score 7):

...that `dict.get()` has a [default value](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#dict.get) of None, thereby avoiding KeyErrors:

```
In [1]: test = { 1 : 'a' }

In [2]: test[2]
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>              Traceback (most recent call last)

&lt;ipython console&gt; in <module>()

<type 'exceptions.KeyError'>: 2

In [3]: test.get( 2 )

In [4]: test.get( 1 )
Out[4]: 'a'

In [5]: test.get( 2 ) == None
Out[5]: True
```

and even to specify this 'at the scene':

```
In [6]: test.get( 2, 'Some' ) == 'Some'
Out[6]: True
```

And you can use `setdefault(`) to have a value set and returned if it doesn't exist:

```
>>> a = {}
>>> b = a.setdefault('foo', 'bar')
>>> a
{'foo': 'bar'}
>>> b
'bar
```

Answer (score 7):

[inspect](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html?highlight=inspect#retrieving-source-code) module is also a cool feature.

Answer (score 7):

Reloading modules enables a "live-coding" style. But class instances don't update. Here's why, and how to get around it. Remember, everything, yes, *everything* is an object.

```
>>> from a_package import a_module
>>> cls = a_module.SomeClass
>>> obj = cls()
>>> obj.method()
(old method output)
```

Now you change the method in a_module.py and want to update your object.

```
>>> reload(a_module)
>>> a_module.SomeClass is cls
False # Because it just got freshly created by reload.
>>> obj.method()
(old method output)
```

Here's one way to update it (but consider it running with scissors):

```
>>> obj.__class__ is cls
True # it's the old class object
>>> obj.__class__ = a_module.SomeClass # pick up the new class
>>> obj.method()
(new method output)
```

This is "running with scissors" because the object's internal state may be different than what the new class expects. This works for really simple cases, but beyond that, `pickle` is your friend. It's still helpful to understand why this works, though.

Comment: +1 for suggesting `pickle` (or `cPickle`). It was really helpful for me, some weeks ago.

Answer (score 7):

Backslashes inside raw strings can still escape quotes. See this:

```
>>> print repr(r"aaa\"bbb")
'aaa\\"bbb'
```

Note that both the backslash and the double-quote are present in the final string.

As consequence, you can't end a raw string with a backslash:

```
>>> print repr(r"C:\")
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
>>> print repr(r"C:\"")
'C:\\"'
```

This happens because raw strings were implemented to help writing regular expressions, and not to write Windows paths. Read a long discussion about this at [Gotcha — backslashes in Windows filenames](http://pythonconquerstheuniverse.wordpress.com/2008/06/04/gotcha-%E2%80%94-backslashes-in-windows-filenames/).

Comment: Note that the backslash is *still* part of the string afterwards... So one might not regard this as regular escaping.

Comment: You're probably better off just using single quotes `'` for the outer string.

Comment: Or just use (forward) slashes, as the Windows API will translate them automatically, then you can finally forget about DOS-style paths. (Though you _must_ use backslashes for "\\server\share\path\file" style resources)

Answer (score 7):

Operators can be called as functions:

```
from operator import add
print reduce(add, [1,2,3,4,5,6])
```

Comment: ? what did you think operators are?

Comment: sorry, i dont get your point..what do you think that we think operators are?

Comment: @Ant, if you were already aware of operators being functions, you can disregard this tip. Not all languages implement operators as functions, so a person coming from another language might not have known this.

Answer (score 7):

infinite recursion in list

```
>>> a = [1,2]
>>> a.append(a)
>>> a
[1, 2, [...]]
>>> a[2]
[1, 2, [...]]
>>> a[2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2][2] == a
True
```

Comment: i don't think it's a Python feature. nor it's hidden. where this can be used?

Answer (score 6):

Ability to substitute even things like file deletion, file opening etc. - direct manipulation of language library. This is a huge advantage when **testing.** You don't have to wrap everything in complicated containers. Just substitute a function/method and go. This is also called **monkey-patching.**

Comment: Creating a test harness which provides classes that have the same interfaces as the objects which would be manipulated by the code under test (the subjects of our testing) is referred to as "Mocking" (these are called "Mock Classes" and their instances are "Mock Objects").

Answer (score 6):

Builtin methods or functions don't implement the descriptor protocol which makes it impossible to do stuff like this:

```
>>> class C(object):
...  id = id
... 
>>> C().id()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: id() takes exactly one argument (0 given)
```

However you can create a small bind descriptor that makes this possible:

```
>>> from types import MethodType
>>> class bind(object):
...  def __init__(self, callable):
...   self.callable = callable
...  def __get__(self, obj, type=None):
...   if obj is None:
...    return self
...   return MethodType(self.callable, obj, type)
... 
>>> class C(object):
...  id = bind(id)
... 
>>> C().id()
7414064
```

Comment: It's simpler and easier to do this as a property, in this case: class C(object): id = property(id)

Comment: lambda is also a good alternative: `class C(object): id = lambda s, *a, **kw: id(*a, **kw)`; and a better version of bind: `def bind(callable): return lambda s, *a, **kw: callable(*a, **kw)`

Answer (score 6):

**Nested Function Parameter Re-binding**

```
def create_printers(n):
    for i in xrange(n):
        def printer(i=i): # Doesn't work without the i=i
            print i
        yield printer
```

Comment: it works without it, but differently. :-)

Comment: No, it doesn't work without it. Omit the i=i and see the difference between map(apply, create_printers(10)) and map(apply, list(apply_printers(10))), where converting to a list consumes the generator and now all ten printer functions have i bound to the same value: 9, where calling them one at a time calls them before the next iteration of the generator changes the int i is bound to in the outer scope.

Comment: I think what @kaizer.se is saying is that when you omit the `i=i` the `i` in the `printer` function references the `i` from the `for` loop rather than the local `i` that is created when a new `printer` function is created with the `i=i` keyword arg.  So it still does work (it yields functions, each with access to a closure) but it doesn't work in the way you'd expect without explicitly creating a local variable.

Answer (score 6):

You can override the mro of a class with a metaclass

```
>>> class A(object):
...     def a_method(self):
...         print("A")
... 
>>> class B(object):
...     def b_method(self):
...         print("B")
... 
>>> class MROMagicMeta(type):
...     def mro(cls):
...         return (cls, B, object)
... 
>>> class C(A, metaclass=MROMagicMeta):
...     def c_method(self):
...         print("C")
... 
>>> cls = C()
>>> cls.c_method()
C
>>> cls.a_method()
Traceback (most recent call last):
 File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'C' object has no attribute 'a_method'
>>> cls.b_method()
B
>>> type(cls).__bases__
(<class '__main__.A'>,)
>>> type(cls).__mro__
(<class '__main__.C'>, <class '__main__.B'>, <class 'object'>)
```

It's probably hidden for a good reason. :)

Comment: That's playing with fire, and asking for ethernal damnation. Better have good reason ;)

Comment: Does not work with python 2.x. Use `__metaclass__ = MROMagicMeta` instead.

Answer (score 6):

Objects of small intgers (-5 .. 256) never created twice:

```
>>> a1 = -5; b1 = 256
>>> a2 = -5; b2 = 256
>>> id(a1) == id(a2), id(b1) == id(b2)
(True, True)
>>>
>>> c1 = -6; d1 = 257
>>> c2 = -6; d2 = 257
>>> id(c1) == id(c2), id(d1) == id(d2)
(False, False)
>>>
```

Edit:
List objects never destroyed (only objects in lists). Python has array in which it keeps up to 80 empty lists. When you destroy list object - python puts it to that array and when you create new list - python gets last puted list from this array:

```
>>> a = [1,2,3]; a_id = id(a)
>>> b = [1,2,3]; b_id = id(b)
>>> del a; del b
>>> c = [1,2,3]; id(c) == b_id
True
>>> d = [1,2,3]; id(d) == a_id
True
>>>
```

Comment: This feature is implementation dependent, so you shouldn't rely on it.

Comment: As Denis said, do not rely on this behavior.  It doesn't work, for example, in PyPy, and your code will break miserably in that if you try to use it.

Answer (score 6):

You can decorate functions with classes - replacing the function with a class instance:

```
class countCalls(object):
    """ decorator replaces a function with a "countCalls" instance
    which behaves like the original function, but keeps track of calls

    >>> @countCalls
    ... def doNothing():
    ...     pass
    >>> doNothing()
    >>> doNothing()
    >>> print doNothing.timesCalled
    2
    """
    def __init__ (self, functionToTrack):
        self.functionToTrack = functionToTrack
        self.timesCalled = 0
    def __call__ (self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.timesCalled += 1
        return self.functionToTrack(*args, **kwargs)
```

Answer (score 6):

**Manipulating Recursion Limit**

Getting or setting the maximum depth of recursion with sys.getrecursionlimit() & sys.setrecursionlimit().

We can limit it to prevent a stack overflow caused by infinite recursion.

Answer (score 6):

**Slices & Mutability**

Copying lists

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x[:]
>>> y.pop()
3
>>> y
[1, 2]
>>> x
[1, 2, 3]
```

Replacing lists

```
>>> x = [1,2,3]
>>> y = x
>>> y[:] = [4,5,6]
>>> x
[4, 5, 6]
```

Answer (score 6):

Python 2.x ignores commas if found after the last element of the sequence:

```
>>> a_tuple_for_instance = (0,1,2,3,)
>>> another_tuple = (0,1,2,3)
>>> a_tuple_for_instance == another_tuple
True
```

A trailing comma causes a single parenthesized element to be treated as a sequence:

```
>>> a_tuple_with_one_element = (8,)
```

Comment: Python3 ignores them as well.

Answer (score 6):

Slices as lvalues. This Sieve of Eratosthenes produces a list that has either the prime number or 0. Elements are 0'd out with the slice assignment in the loop.

```
def eras(n):
    last = n + 1
    sieve = [0,0] + list(range(2, last))
    sqn = int(round(n ** 0.5))
    it = (i for i in xrange(2, sqn + 1) if sieve[i])
    for i in it:
        sieve[i*i:last:i] = [0] * (n//i - i + 1)
    return filter(None, sieve)
```

To work, the slice on the left must be assigned a list on the right of the same length.

Answer (score 6):

Rounding Integers:
Python has the function round, which returns numbers of type double:

```
 >>> print round(1123.456789, 4)
1123.4568
 >>> print round(1123.456789, 2)
1123.46
 >>> print round(1123.456789, 0)
1123.0
```

This function has a wonderful magic property:

```
 >>> print round(1123.456789, -1)
1120.0
 >>> print round(1123.456789, -2)
1100.0
```

If you need an integer as a result use int to convert type:

```
 >>> print int(round(1123.456789, -2))
1100
 >>> print int(round(8359980, -2))
8360000
```

Thank you [Gregor](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/tutor/2003-August/024395.html).

Answer (score 5):

**List comprehensions**

[list comprehensions](http://www.secnetix.de/olli/Python/list_comprehensions.hawk)

Compare the more traditional (without list comprehension):

```
foo = []
for x in xrange(10):
  if x % 2 == 0:
     foo.append(x)
```

to:

```
foo = [x for x in xrange(10) if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: In what way is list comprehensions a *hidden* feature of Python ?

Comment: They are probably "hidden" for former C & Java programmers who haven't seen such features before, don't think to look for it and ignore it if they see it in a tutorial.  OTOH a Haskell programmer will notice it immediately.

Comment: The question does ask for "an example and short description of the feature, not just a link to documentation".  Any chance of adding one?

Comment: List comprehensions were implemented by Greg Ewing, who was a postdoc at a department where they taught functional programming in a first-year paper.

Comment: If this was a hidden feature of python there would have been 40% more lines of code written in python today.

Comment: It took me _ages_ to find list comprehensions in Python. Can't live without them now, of course...

Comment: +1 I think that nested list comprehensions should also be mentioned: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198777/double-iteration-in-list-comprehension

Answer (score 5):

Too lazy to initialize every field in a dictionary? No problem:

In Python > 2.3:

```
from collections import defaultdict
```

In Python <= 2.3:

```
def defaultdict(type_):
    class Dict(dict):
        def __getitem__(self, key):
            return self.setdefault(key, type_())
    return Dict()
```

In any version:

```
d = defaultdict(list)
for stuff in lots_of_stuff:
     d[stuff.name].append(stuff)
```

**UPDATE:**

Thanks [Ken Arnold](https://stackoverflow.com/users/69707/ken-arnold). I reimplemented a more sophisticated version of defaultdict. It should behave exactly as [the one in the standard library](http://docs.python.org/library/collections.html#collections.defaultdict).

```
def defaultdict(default_factory, *args, **kw):                              

    class defaultdict(dict):

        def __missing__(self, key):
            if default_factory is None:
                raise KeyError(key)
            return self.setdefault(key, default_factory())

        def __getitem__(self, key):
            try:
                return dict.__getitem__(self, key)
            except KeyError:
                return self.__missing__(key)

    return defaultdict(*args, **kw)
```

Comment: You may be interested to learn about collections.defaultdict(list).

Comment: Thanks. Does not work on my production environment though. Python 2.3.

Comment: Careful, that `defaultdict` reimplementation ends up calling `type_` on every lookup instead of only when the item is missing.

Comment: Prior to python 2.2, you could not subclass `dict` directly, so you'd need to subclass from `UserDict.UserDict`.  Better still would be to upgrade.

Answer (score 5):

If you are using descriptors on your classes Python completely bypasses `__dict__` for that key which makes it a nice place to store such values:

```
>>> class User(object):
...  def _get_username(self):
...   return self.__dict__['username']
...  def _set_username(self, value):
...   print 'username set'
...   self.__dict__['username'] = value
...  username = property(_get_username, _set_username)
...  del _get_username, _set_username
... 
>>> u = User()
>>> u.username = "foo"
username set
>>> u.__dict__
{'username': 'foo'}
```

This helps to keep `dir()` clean.

Answer (score 5):

**__getattr__()**

`getattr` is a really nice way to make generic classes, which is especially useful if you're writing an API.  For example, in the [FogBugz Python API](http://support.fogcreek.com/default.asp?W1048), `getattr` is used to pass method calls on to the web service seamlessly:

```
class FogBugz:
    ...

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        # Let's leave the private stuff to Python
        if name.startswith("__"):
            raise AttributeError("No such attribute '%s'" % name)

        if not self.__handlerCache.has_key(name):
            def handler(**kwargs):
                return self.__makerequest(name, **kwargs)
            self.__handlerCache[name] = handler
        return self.__handlerCache[name]
    ...
```

When someone calls `FogBugz.search(q='bug')`, they don't get actually call a `search` method.  Instead, `getattr` handles the call by creating a new function that wraps the `makerequest` method, which crafts the appropriate HTTP request to the web API.  Any errors will be dispatched by the web service and passed back to the user.

Comment: You can also create semi-custom types in this manner.

Answer (score 5):

[import antigravity](http://xkcd.com/353/)

Comment: this answer was already given

Answer (score 5):

***Exposing Mutable Buffers***

Using the Python [Buffer Protocol](http://docs.python.org/c-api/buffer.html) to *expose mutable byte-oriented buffers* in Python (2.5/2.6).

(Sorry, no code here. Requires use of low-level C API or existing adapter module).

Answer (score 5):

The pythonic idiom `x = ... if ... else ...` is far superior to `x = ... and ... or ...` and here is why:

Although the statement

```
x = 3 if (y == 1) else 2
```

Is equivalent to

```
x = y == 1 and 3 or 2
```

if you use the `x = ... and ... or ...` idiom, some day you may get bitten by this tricky situation:

```
x = 0 if True else 1    # sets x equal to 0
```

and therefore is not equivalent to

```
x = True and 0 or 1   # sets x equal to 1
```

For more on the proper way to do this,
see [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/116480#116480).

Answer (score 5):

**Monkeypatching objects**

Every object in Python has a `__dict__` member, which stores the object's attributes. So, you can do something like this:

```
class Foo(object):
    def __init__(self, arg1, arg2, **kwargs):
        #do stuff with arg1 and arg2
        self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

f = Foo('arg1', 'arg2', bar=20, baz=10)
#now f is a Foo object with two extra attributes
```

This can be exploited to add both attributes and functions arbitrarily to objects. This can also be exploited to create a quick-and-dirty `struct` type.

```
class struct(object):
    def __init__(**kwargs):
       self.__dict__.update(kwargs)

s = struct(foo=10, bar=11, baz="i'm a string!')
```

Comment: except for the classes with `__slots__`

Comment: Except for some "primitive" types implemented in C (for performance reasons, I guess). For instance, after `a = 2`, there is no `a.__dict__`

Answer (score 5):

I'm not sure where (or whether) this is in the Python docs, but for python 2.x (at least 2.5 and 2.6, which I just tried), the `print` statement can be called with parenthenses. This can be useful if you want to be able to easily port some Python 2.x code to Python 3.x.

Example:
`print('We want Moshiach Now')` should print `We want Moshiach Now` work in python 2.5, 2.6, and 3.x.

Also, the `not` operator can be called with parenthenses in Python 2 and 3:
`not False`
and
`not(False)`
should both return `True`.

Parenthenses might also work with other statements and operators.

**EDIT**: NOT a good idea to put parenthenses around `not` operators (and probably any other operators), since it can make for surprising situations, like so (this happens because the parenthenses are just really around the `1`):

```
>>> (not 1) == 9
False

>>> not(1) == 9
True
```

This also can work, for some values (I think where it is not a valid identifier name), like this:
`not'val'` should return `False`, and `print'We want Moshiach Now'` should return `We want Moshiach Now`. (but `not552` would raise a NameError since it is a valid identifier name).

Comment: Side-effect of one of the basic design rules of the Python syntax. Parentheses and whitespace can be varied in pretty much any way that doesn't make the meaning ambiguous. (Which is why you get more freedom to word-wrap things like if/while statements if you put the test body in brackets.)

Comment: What ssokolow said is correct. In python 2.6 the language was updated to be (more) compatible with python 3. In python 3+ parenthesis are required to call print. see here for more information: http://docs.python.org/whatsnew/2.6.html#pep-3105-print-as-a-function

Answer (score 5):

In addition to this mentioned earlier by [haridsv](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/2582013#2582013):

```
>>> foo = bar = baz = 1
>>> foo, bar, baz
(1, 1, 1)
```

it's also possible to do this:

```
>>> foo, bar, baz = 1, 2, 3
>>> foo, bar, baz
(1, 2, 3)
```

Answer (score 5):

### `getattr` takes a third parameter

`getattr(obj, attribute_name, default)` is like:

```
try:
    return obj.attribute
except AttributeError:
    return default
```

except that `attribute_name` can be any string.

This can be really useful for [duck typing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing). Maybe you have something like:

```
class MyThing:
    pass
class MyOtherThing:
    pass
if isinstance(obj, (MyThing, MyOtherThing)):
    process(obj)
```

(btw, `isinstance(obj, (a,b))` means `isinstance(obj, a) or isinstance(obj, b)`.)

When you make a new kind of thing, you'd need to add it to that tuple everywhere it occurs. (That construction also causes problems when reloading modules or importing the same file under two names. It happens more than people like to admit.) But instead you could say:

```
class MyThing:
    processable = True
class MyOtherThing:
    processable = True
if getattr(obj, 'processable', False):
    process(obj)
```

Add inheritance and it gets even better: all of your examples of processable objects can inherit from

```
class Processable:
    processable = True
```

but you don't have to convince everybody to inherit from your base class, just to set an attribute.

Answer (score 5):

**Simple built-in benchmarking tool**

The Python Standard Library comes with a very easy-to-use benchmarking module called "timeit". You can even use it from the command line to see which of several language constructs is the fastest.

E.g.,

```
% python -m timeit 'r = range(0, 1000)' 'for i in r: pass'
10000 loops, best of 3: 48.4 usec per loop

% python -m timeit 'r = xrange(0, 1000)' 'for i in r: pass'
10000 loops, best of 3: 37.4 usec per loop
```

Answer (score 5):

Here are 2 easter eggs:

---

One in python itself:

```
>>> import __hello__
Hello world...
```

---

And another one in the `Werkzeug` module, which is a bit complicated to reveal, here it is:

By looking at `Werkzeug`'s source code, in `werkzeug/__init__.py`, there is a line that should draw your attention:

```
'werkzeug._internal':   ['_easteregg']
```

If you're a bit curious, this should lead you to have a look at the `werkzeug/_internal.py`, there, you'll find an `_easteregg()` function which takes a wsgi application in argument, it also contains some base64 encoded data and 2 nested functions, that seem to do something special if an argument named `macgybarchakku` is found in the query string.

So, to reveal this easter egg, it seems you need to wrap an application in the `_easteregg()` function, let's go:

```
from werkzeug import Request, Response, run_simple
from werkzeug import _easteregg

@Request.application
def application(request):
    return Response('Hello World!')

run_simple('localhost', 8080, _easteregg(application))
```

Now, if you run the app and visit http://localhost:8080/?macgybarchakku, you should see the easter egg.

Answer (score 5):

Dict Comprehensions

```
>>> {i: i**2 for i in range(5)}
{0: 0, 1: 1, 2: 4, 3: 9, 4: 16}
```

[Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comprehensions#dictionary-displays)

[Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Dictionary_comprehension)

Answer (score 5):

Set Comprehensions

```
>>> {i**2 for i in range(5)}                                                       
set([0, 1, 4, 16, 9])
```

[Python documentation](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html?highlight=comprehensions#set-displays)

[Wikipedia Entry](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_comprehension#Set_comprehension)

Comment: This is already covered in http://stackoverflow.com/a/224747/497043.

Answer (score 4):

**Special methods**

[Absolute power!](http://docs.python.org/ref/specialnames.html)

Comment: This is my favorite thing about Python. I especially **love** overloading operators. IMHO `object1.add(object2)` should always be `object1 + object2`.

Comment: I read object1.add() as a destructive operation and + as one that only returns the result without modifying object1.

Answer (score 4):

> Access Dictionary elements as
>   attributes (properties). so if an
>   a1=AttrDict() has key 'name' ->
>   instead of a1['name'] we can easily
>   access name attribute of a1 using ->
>   a1.name

---

```
class AttrDict(dict):

    def __getattr__(self, name):
        if name in self:
            return self[name]
        raise AttributeError('%s not found' % name)

    def __setattr__(self, name, value):
        self[name] = value

    def __delattr__(self, name):
        del self[name]

person = AttrDict({'name': 'John Doe', 'age': 66})
print person['name']
print person.name

person.name = 'Frodo G'
print person.name

del person.age

print person
```

Comment: no title or explanation? where is the hidden feature here?

Answer (score 4):

Tuple unpacking in for loops, list comprehensions and generator expressions:

```
>>> l=[(1,2),(3,4)]
>>> [a+b for a,b in l ] 
[3,7]
```

Useful in this idiom for iterating over (key,data) pairs in dictionaries:

```
d = { 'x':'y', 'f':'e'}
for name, value in d.items():  # one can also use iteritems()
   print "name:%s, value:%s" % (name,value)
```

prints:

```
name:x, value:y
name:f, value:e
```

Comment: This is also useful when `l` is replaced with `zip(something)`.

Answer (score 4):

The first-classness of everything ('everything is an object'), and the mayhem this can cause.

```
>>> x = 5
>>> y = 10
>>> 
>>> def sq(x):
...   return x * x
... 
>>> def plus(x):
...   return x + x
... 
>>> (sq,plus)[y>x](y)
20
```

The last line creates a tuple containing the two functions, then evaluates y>x (True) and uses that as an index to the tuple (by casting it to an int, 1), and then calls that function with parameter y and shows the result.

For further abuse, if you were returning an object with an index (e.g. a list) you could add further square brackets on the end; if the contents were callable, more parentheses, and so on. For extra perversion, use the result of code like this as the expression in another example (i.e. replace y>x with this code):

```
(sq,plus)[y>x](y)[4](x)
```

This showcases two facets of Python - the 'everything is an object' philosophy taken to the extreme, and the methods by which improper or poorly-conceived use of the language's syntax can lead to completely unreadable, unmaintainable spaghetti code that fits in a single expression.

Comment: why would you ever do this? it is hardly a valid criticism of a language to show how it can be intentionally abused. accidental abuse would be valid, but this would never happen by accident.

Comment: @Gorgapor: Python's consistency and lack of exceptions and special cases is what makes it easy to learn and, to me at least, beautiful. Any powerful tool, used abusively can cause 'mayhem'. Contrary to your opinion, I think the ability to index into a sequence of functions and call it, in a single expression is a powerful and useful idiom, and I've used it more than once, with explanatory comments.

Comment: @Don: Your use case, indexing a sequence of functions, is a good one, and very useful. Dan Udey's use case, using a boolean as an index into an inline tuple of functions, is a horrible and useless one, which is needlessly obfuscated.

Comment: @Gorganpor: Sorry, I meant to address my comment to Dan Udey, not you. I agree entirely with you.

Answer (score 4):

Taking advantage of python's dynamic nature to have an apps
config files in python syntax. For example if you had the following
in a config file:

```
{
  "name1": "value1",
  "name2": "value2"
}
```

Then you could trivially read it like:

```
config = eval(open("filename").read())
```

Comment: I agree.  I've started using a settings.py or config.py file which I then load as a module.  Sure beats the extra steps of parsing some other file format.

Comment: I can see this becoming a security issue.

Comment: It could be, but sometimes it's not.  In those cases, it's awesome.

Comment: Python can be a much more expressive configuration language than any amount of XML or INI files. I'm trying to avoid explicit config, with just an invoke script that does “import myapp; app= myapp.Application(...); app.run()”. Options default sensibly but can be changed using constructor args.

Comment: (This assumes that run-time configuration in the app itself is stored in a database. More significant configuration is possible through allowing the user to subclass Application and set properties/methods on the subclass.)

Comment: That's a bold action for even non-hostile environments. eval() is a loaded gun, that needs intensive caution while handling. On the other hand, using JSON (now in 2.6 stdlib) is much more secure and portable for carrying configuration.

Comment: I would never approve a code review which contained an `eval`.

Comment: @Richard Waite: It's usually a security issue if an adversary can modify your config file...

Comment: I agree, this is extremely useful in many quick'n'dirty scripts. But it's better to use execfile instead of eval+open+read.

Comment: Even in a trusted environment, this is an unacceptable security issue. If you need to parse config files, use `ConfigParser` - 10 lines of code give you a full blown mechanism for creating universally readable configuration file. Your approach is really not portable and not extensible.

Comment: Then why does Django store site settings in a .py file (including db password)? Are they out of their minds, are they not using eval(), or is there something I'm missing?

Comment: I personally don't like using `eval()` for anything, especially settings. I always wrap Django settings around `ConfigParser` and save actual information in a permission-guarded file. Like Rasmus Lerdorf said "If eval() is the answer, you’re almost certainly asking the wrong question."

Comment: eval() has the same security issues that import does, so denying a script that uses it for security issues doesn't make sense.  It is the usual issue of never evaling untrusted user input, but if the file ends in .py and gets imported, it still gets executed.  The reason to use import is because it puts your configuration into a different namespace cleanly.  You could also use execfile(ConfigFile,ConfigDict) to store the configuration files into a dictionary.

Comment: no need for eval, name your dict (config) and import it from your module… (from configfile import config)

Answer (score 4):

**Method replacement for object instance**

You can replace methods of already created object instances. It allows you to create object instance with different (exceptional) functionality:

```
>>> class C(object):
...     def fun(self):
...         print "C.a", self
...
>>> inst = C()
>>> inst.fun()  # C.a method is executed
C.a <__main__.C object at 0x00AE74D0>
>>> instancemethod = type(C.fun)
>>>
>>> def fun2(self):
...     print "fun2", self
...
>>> inst.fun = instancemethod(fun2, inst, C)  # Now we are replace C.a by fun2
>>> inst.fun()  # ... and fun2 is executed
fun2 <__main__.C object at 0x00AE74D0>
```

As we can `C.a` was replaced by `fun2()` in `inst` instance (`self` didn't change).

Alternatively we may use `new` module, but it's depreciated since Python 2.6:

```
>>> def fun3(self):
...     print "fun3", self
...
>>> import new
>>> inst.fun = new.instancemethod(fun3, inst, C)
>>> inst.fun()
fun3 <__main__.C object at 0x00AE74D0>
```

**Node:** This solution shouldn't be used as general replacement of inheritance mechanism! But it may be very handy in some specific situations (debugging, mocking).

**Warning:** This solution will not work for built-in types and for new style classes using slots.

Comment: I personally tend to prefer to leave `instancemethod` to classes; paticularly so that the binding behavior `foo.method` works normally.  If I'm binding self explicitly, I'll instead use `functools.partial`, which achieves the same effect, but makes it a bit clearer that the binding behavior is explicit.

Answer (score 4):

With a minute amount of work, the threading module becomes amazingly easy to use. This decorator changes a function so that it runs in its own thread, returning a placeholder class instance instead of its regular result. You can probe for the answer by checking placeolder.result or wait for it by calling placeholder.awaitResult()

```
def threadify(function):
    """
    exceptionally simple threading decorator. Just:
    >>> @threadify
    ... def longOperation(result):
    ...     time.sleep(3)
    ...     return result
    >>> A= longOperation("A has finished")
    >>> B= longOperation("B has finished")

    A doesn't have a result yet:
    >>> print A.result
    None

    until we wait for it:
    >>> print A.awaitResult()
    A has finished

    we could also wait manually - half a second more should be enough for B:
    >>> time.sleep(0.5); print B.result
    B has finished
    """
    class thr (threading.Thread,object):
        def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
            threading.Thread.__init__ ( self )  
            self.args, self.kwargs = args, kwargs
            self.result = None
            self.start()
        def awaitResult(self):
            self.join()
            return self.result        
        def run(self):
            self.result=function(*self.args, **self.kwargs)
    return thr
```

Comment: You may be interested in the concurrent.futures module added in Python 3.2

Answer (score 4):

There are no secrets in Python ;)

Answer (score 4):

You can assign several variables to the same value

```
>>> foo = bar = baz = 1
>>> foo, bar, baz
(1, 1, 1)
```

Useful to initialize several variable to None, in a compact way.

Comment: You could also do:  foo, bar, baz = [None]*3 to get the same result.

Comment: You can also compare multiple things at once, like `foo == bar == baz`. It's essentially the same thing as (what is right now) the top answer.

Comment: Also be aware that this will only create the value once, and all the variables will reference that one same value.  It's fine for `None`, though, since it is a singleton object.

Answer (score 4):

Combine unpacking with the print function:

```
# in 2.6 <= python < 3.0, 3.0 + the print function is native
from __future__ import print_function 

mylist = ['foo', 'bar', 'some other value', 1,2,3,4]  
print(*mylist)
```

Comment: I prefer something like `print(' '.join([str(x) for x in mylist]))`.  Using unpacking like this is too clever.

Comment: Performance wise I think the 'clever' version is faster (after doing some completely non-scientific tests). Plus you know `*` means you're unpacking a list or tuple, and you can use the `sep` keyword.

Comment: I find this clean and simple, but I always wonder why pylint insists there's too much magic in there ;)

Comment: @Paweł Prażak: I believe PyLint simply considers `*` and `**` to be too magical, period.

Comment: maybe some people are just allergic to * and ** because of pointer and double pointer resemblance ;)

Comment: @Brian I would drop the list and use generator `print(' '.join(word for word in mylist))`

Answer (score 4):

**insert vs append**

not a feature, but may be interesting

suppose you want to insert some data in a list, and then reverse it. the easiest thing is

```
count = 10 ** 5
nums = []
for x in range(count):
    nums.append(x)
nums.reverse()
```

then you think: what about inserting the numbers from the beginning, instead? so:

```
count = 10 ** 5 
nums = [] 
for x in range(count):
    nums.insert(0, x)
```

but it turns to be 100 times slower! if we set count = 10 ** 6, it will be 1,000 times slower; this is because insert is O(n^2), while append is O(n).

the reason for that difference is that insert has to move each element in a list each time it's called; append just add at the end of the list that elements (sometimes it has to re-allocate everything, but it's still much more fast)

Comment: Or you can use nums.reverse() and have it done by the core - without the need to use range()

Comment: i don't get your point, sorry..

Comment: The fact python lists are implemented with arrays is interesting; however, the example is not that useful, because the idiomatic way to reverse a list is to use reverse method, without any additional step.

Comment: And that would be why collections.deque exists - you can insert and pop entries from either end in O(1)

Answer (score 4):

**A module exports *EVERYTHING* in its namespace**

Including names imported from other modules!

```
# this is "answer42.py"
from operator import *
from inspect  import *
```

Now test what's importable from the module.

```
>>> import answer42
>>> answer42.__dict__.keys()
['gt', 'imul', 'ge', 'setslice', 'ArgInfo', 'getfile', 'isCallable', 'getsourcelines', 'CO_OPTIMIZED', 'le', 're', 'isgenerator', 'ArgSpec', 'imp', 'lt', 'delslice', 'BlockFinder', 'getargspec', 'currentframe', 'CO_NOFREE', 'namedtuple', 'rshift', 'string', 'getframeinfo', '__file__', 'strseq', 'iconcat', 'getmro', 'mod', 'getcallargs', 'isub', 'getouterframes', 'isdatadescriptor', 'modulesbyfile', 'setitem', 'truth', 'Attribute', 'div', 'CO_NESTED', 'ixor', 'getargvalues', 'ismemberdescriptor', 'getsource', 'isMappingType', 'eq', 'index', 'xor', 'sub', 'getcomments', 'neg', 'getslice', 'isframe', '__builtins__', 'abs', 'getmembers', 'mul', 'getclasstree', 'irepeat', 'is_', 'getitem', 'indexOf', 'Traceback', 'findsource', 'ModuleInfo', 'ipow', 'TPFLAGS_IS_ABSTRACT', 'or_', 'joinseq', 'is_not', 'itruediv', 'getsourcefile', 'dis', 'os', 'iand', 'countOf', 'getinnerframes', 'pow', 'pos', 'and_', 'lshift', '__name__', 'sequenceIncludes', 'isabstract', 'isbuiltin', 'invert', 'contains', 'add', 'isSequenceType', 'irshift', 'types', 'tokenize', 'isfunction', 'not_', 'istraceback', 'getmoduleinfo', 'isgeneratorfunction', 'getargs', 'CO_GENERATOR', 'cleandoc', 'classify_class_attrs', 'EndOfBlock', 'walktree', '__doc__', 'getmodule', 'isNumberType', 'ilshift', 'ismethod', 'ifloordiv', 'formatargvalues', 'indentsize', 'getmodulename', 'inv', 'Arguments', 'iscode', 'CO_NEWLOCALS', 'formatargspec', 'iadd', 'getlineno', 'imod', 'CO_VARKEYWORDS', 'ne', 'idiv', '__package__', 'CO_VARARGS', 'attrgetter', 'methodcaller', 'truediv', 'repeat', 'trace', 'isclass', 'ior', 'ismethoddescriptor', 'sys', 'isroutine', 'delitem', 'stack', 'concat', 'getdoc', 'getabsfile', 'ismodule', 'linecache', 'floordiv', 'isgetsetdescriptor', 'itemgetter', 'getblock']
>>> from answer42 import getmembers
>>> getmembers
<function getmembers at 0xb74b2924>
>>>
```

That's a good reason not to `from x import *` and to define `__all__ =`.

Comment: How is that a hidden feature? `__all__` exists to limit what's exported, and it's even in the tutorial.

Comment: @PiotrLegnica Did you know that a module exports _also_ what it imports unless \__all\__ is used? It is unlike most languages with modules, and I haven't read about the "feature" in the documentation, so, for me, it qualifies as _hidden_.

Comment: @Apalala: why shouldn't imported (sub)modules be exported given the fact they are in the namespace of the main module?

Comment: @Cristian Ciuptu. In most other languages a module (or its equivalent) exports only what it defines, plus, implicitly, what it's reachable from what it defines. It's traditionally part of separation of concerns and implementation hiding. A module may import, say, `math` to do its thing, and cope with standard arithmetic in a later version; importing modules should not know about that (traditionally).

Comment: IOW, if you want to use `math.sqrt()`, then you should import it from `math`, not from `answer42`.

Comment: @Apala: I got your point regarding other languages in the first place, but given Python's dynamic nature and object orientation, this behavior isn't quite a surprise.

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu. It is strictly a not-well-documented design choice that has nothing to do with the dynamics of the language. It is also so unusual, unexpected, and useless, that it might qualify as a design flaw.

Comment: @Apalala: how is a module different from a class or let's say a type like `int` or `float`? All of them are objects and all of them reside in the module's namespace. The design is consistent. It let's you do stuff like `def f(m, x): return m.sqrt(x); f(math, x)`, although this is not exactly a good coding style. The "feature" is unusual and unexpected only if you compare it with other languages (that are less "dynamic" whatever that means).

Comment: @Apalala: if you want to see a good use case checkout the source code of the `os` module. It does stuff like `import posixpath as path` or `import ntpath as path`, `posixpath` and `ntpath` being other modules, of course.

Comment: @Cristian Ciupitu I concede. It is useful, and consistently used. But I still don't like that is so undocumented.

Answer (score 4):

Unicode identifier in Python3:

```
>>> 'Unicode字符_تكوين_Variable'.isidentifier()
True
>>> Unicode字符_تكوين_Variable='Python3 rules!'
>>> Unicode字符_تكوين_Variable
'Python3 rules!'
```

Comment: Of course, using non-ascii characters in python source code for any reason except to spell contributor names in the header documentation is in violation of pep-8 code style rules.

Answer (score 4):

Python have exceptions for very unexpected things:

**Imports**

This let you import an alternative if a lib is missing

```
try:
    import json
except ImportError:
    import simplejson as json
```

**Iteration**

For loops do this internally, and catch StopIteration:

```
iter([]).next()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#4>", line 1, in <module>
    iter(a).next()
StopIteration
```

**Assertion**

```
>>> try:
...     assert []
... except AssertionError:
...     print "This list should not be empty"
This list should not be empty
```

While this is more verbose for one check, multiple checks mixing exceptions and boolean operators with the same error message can be shortened this way.

Answer (score 3):

**Everything is dynamic**

"There is no compile-time". Everything in Python is runtime. A module is 'defined' by executing the module's source top-to-bottom, just like a script, and the resulting namespace is the module's attribute-space. Likewise, a class is 'defined' by executing the class body top-to-bottom, and the resulting namespace is the class's attribute-space. A class body can contain completely arbitrary code -- including import statements, loops and other class statements. Creating a class, function or even module 'dynamically', as is sometimes asked for, isn't hard; in fact, it's impossible to avoid, since everything is 'dynamic'.

Comment: This gives Python the wonderful reload().

Comment: Everything is dynamic... Except classes and modules implemented in C, which are not as dynamic as everything else. (try something like `dict.x = 3`, and Python won't let you)

Comment: Yes, modules and types defined in C are defined at compiletime, but they're still *created* at runtime. Also, `dict.x = 3` has nothing to do with things being dynamic, but with the `dict` type not allowing attributes to be assigned. You can make your own classes, in Python, that don't allow that. You can make your own type, in C, that does allow it. It's unrelated.

Comment: How is this a hidden feature?

Comment: I frequently hear this, but it isn't quite true. When you import a module, the whole thing is compiled immediately. If there are any syntax errors anywhere in the module, nothing will execute. The big difference between Python and more traditionally compiled languages is that class and function definitions are statements that are executed at runtime (and hence can be skipped via if statements and exceptions, nested arbitrarily, etc).

Answer (score 3):

**Objects in boolean context**

Empty tuples, lists, dicts, strings and many other objects are equivalent to False in boolean context (and non-empty are equivalent to True).

```
empty_tuple = ()
empty_list = []
empty_dict = {}
empty_string = ''
empty_set = set()
if empty_tuple or empty_list or empty_dict or empty_string or empty_set:
  print 'Never happens!'
```

This allows logical operations to return one of it's operands instead of True/False, which is useful in some situations:

```
s = t or "Default value" # s will be assigned "Default value"
                         # if t is false/empty/none
```

Comment: actually this is discouraged, you should use the "new"  s = t if t else "default value"

Answer (score 3):

#### Private methods and data hiding (encapsulation)

There's a common idiom in Python of denoting methods and other class members that are not intended to be part of the class's external API by giving them names that start with underscores.  This is convenient and works very well in practice, but it gives the false impression that Python does not support true encapsulation of private code and/or data.  In fact, Python automatically gives you [lexical closures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lexical_closure), which make it very easy to encapsulate data in a much more bulletproof way when the situation really warrants it.  Here's a contrived example of a class that makes use of this technique:

```
class MyClass(object):
  def __init__(self):

    privateData = {}

    self.publicData = 123

    def privateMethod(k):
      print privateData[k] + self.publicData

    def privilegedMethod():
      privateData['foo'] = "hello "
      privateMethod('foo')

    self.privilegedMethod = privilegedMethod

  def publicMethod(self):
    print self.publicData
```

And here's a contrived example of its use:

```
>>> obj = MyClass()
>>> obj.publicMethod()
123
>>> obj.publicData = 'World'
>>> obj.publicMethod()
World
>>> obj.privilegedMethod()
hello World
>>> obj.privateMethod()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'privateMethod'
>>> obj.privateData
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'MyClass' object has no attribute 'privateData'
```

The key is that `privateMethod` and `privateData` aren't really attributes of obj at all, so they can't be accessed from outside, nor do they show up in `dir()` or similar.  They're local variables in the constructor, completely inaccessible outside of `__init__`.  However, because of the magic of closures, they really are per-instance variables with the same lifetime as the object with which they're associated, even though there's no way to access them from outside except (in this example) by invoking `privilegedMethod`.  Often this sort of very strict encapsulation is overkill, but sometimes it really can be very handy for keeping an API or a namespace squeaky clean.

In Python 2.x, the only way to have mutable private state is with a mutable object (such as the dict in this example).  Many people have remarked on how annoying this can be.  Python 3.x will remove this restriction by introducing the `nonlocal` keyword described in [PEP 3104](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3104/).

Comment: this is almost never a good idea.

Comment: "They're local variables in the constructor, completely inaccessible outside of __init__."  Not true: >>> [c.cell_contents for c in obj.privilegedMethod.func_closure] --> [{'foo': 'hello '}, <function privateMethod at 0x65530>]

Comment: The right way of preventing attribute access would be have a `__getattribute__` or `__getattr__` sentinal and route accepted calls accordingly. Again, secrecy and python isnt a good idea.

Answer (score 3):

**Functional support.**

Generators and generator expressions, specifically.

Ruby made this mainstream again, but Python can do it just as well.  Not as ubiquitous in the libraries as in Ruby, which is too bad, but I like the syntax better, it's simpler.

Because they're not as ubiquitous, I don't see as many examples out there on why they're useful, but they've allowed me to write cleaner, more efficient code.

Answer (score 3):

Simulating the tertiary operator using and and or.

and and or operators in python return the objects themselves rather than Booleans. Thus:

```
In [18]: a = True

In [19]: a and 3 or 4
Out[19]: 3

In [20]: a = False

In [21]: a and 3 or 4
Out[21]: 4
```

However, Py 2.5 seems to have added an explicit tertiary operator

```
    In [22]: a = 5 if True else '6'

    In [23]: a
    Out[23]: 5
```

Well, this works if you are sure that your true clause does not evaluate to False.  example:

```
>>> def foo(): 
...     print "foo"
...     return 0
...
>>> def bar(): 
...     print "bar"
...     return 1
...
>>> 1 and foo() or bar()
foo
bar
1
```

To get it right, you've got to just a little bit more:

```
>>> (1 and [foo()] or [bar()])[0]
foo
0
```

However, this isn't as pretty.  if your version of python supports it, use the conditional operator.

```
>>> foo() if True or bar()
foo
0
```

Comment: Careful with that:

>>> a and "" or ":("

you'll always get a frowny face back, no matter if a is true or false

Comment: Marius, Only, if a is false. Otherwise U'd want ":(" as "" is false.

Comment: `(falseValue, trueValue)[cond]` is a cleaner (IMO) way to simulate a ternary operator.

Answer (score 3):

If you've renamed a class in your application where you're loading user-saved files via Pickle, and one of the renamed classes are stored in a user's old save, you will not be able to load in that pickled file.

However, simply add in a reference to your class definition and everything's good:

e.g., before:

```
class Bleh:
    pass
```

now,

```
class Blah:
    pass
```

so, your user's pickled saved file contains a reference to Bleh, which doesn't exist due to the rename. The fix?

```
Bleh = Blah
```

simple!

Comment: A reasonable hack, but why has the class name changed? was it because it conflicts with something else? Doing this sort of negates any benefit you might have had from renaming the class in the first place.

Comment: I was modelling classes on "drawing" tools - pen, rectangle, select etc, and was using the class name as GUI button labels. I then changed to a class variable to represent the name, later.

Answer (score 3):

The fact that EVERYTHING is an object, and as such is extensible.  I can add member variables as metadata to a function that I define:

```
>>> def addInts(x,y): 
...    return x + y
>>> addInts.params = ['integer','integer']
>>> addInts.returnType = 'integer'
```

This can be very useful for writing dynamic unit tests, e.g.

Comment: Most things are objects; and some objects do not take property assignments so happily.

Answer (score 3):

Simple way to test if a key is in a dict:

```
>>> 'key' in { 'key' : 1 }
True

>>> d = dict(key=1, key2=2)
>>> if 'key' in d:
...     print 'Yup'
... 
Yup
```

Comment: This is hopefully not hidden for any non-new Python coder!

Comment: Or even new ones, since it's introduced in the tutorial.

Answer (score 3):

```
** Using sets to reference contents in sets of frozensets**
```

As you probably know, sets are mutable and thus not hashable, so it's necessary to use frozensets if you want to make a set of sets (or use sets as dictionary keys):

```
>>> fabc = frozenset('abc')
>>> fxyz = frozenset('xyz')
>>> mset = set((fabc, fxyz))
>>> mset
{frozenset({'a', 'c', 'b'}), frozenset({'y', 'x', 'z'})}
```

However, it's possible to test for membership and remove/discard members using just ordinary sets:

```
>>> abc = set('abc')
>>> abc in mset
True
>>> mset.remove(abc)
>>> mset
{frozenset({'y', 'x', 'z'})}
```

To quote from the Python Standard Library docs:

> Note, the `elem` argument to the `__contains__()`, `remove()`, and `discard()`
>       methods may be a set. To support searching for an equivalent frozenset, the 
>       `elem` set is temporarily mutated during the search and then restored. During 
>       the search, the `elem` set should not be read or mutated since it does not 
>       have a meaningful value.

Unfortunately, and perhaps astonishingly, the same is not true of dictionaries:

```
>>> mdict = {fabc:1, fxyz:2}
>>> fabc in mdict
True
>>> abc in mdict
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

Answer (score 3):

#### Python has "private" variables

Variables that start, but not end, with a double underscore become private, and not just by convention. Actually __var turns into _Classname__var, where Classname is the class in which the variable was created. They are not inherited and cannot be overriden.

```
>>> class A:
...     def __init__(self):
...             self.__var = 5
...     def getvar(self):
...             return self.__var
... 
>>> a = A()
>>> a.__var
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "", line 1, in 
AttributeError: A instance has no attribute '__var'
>>> a.getvar()
5
>>> dir(a)
['_A__var', '__doc__', '__init__', '__module__', 'getvar']
>>>
```

Comment: umm... not quite "real private variables". Nothing stops you from accessing _A__var...

Comment: Nothing stops you from accessing private memory locations in C++ programs to twiddle private variables either, but it's seriously frowned upon.

Comment: In C++, it's a limitation of how the language addresses memory. If you want to risk crashing your program or inducing someone less familiar with the code to do so, that can't be prevented without breaking the C-language compatibility. Python's "member name mangling" isn't intended for use as a private variable mechanism. It's intended for public members which need to opt out of the normal inheritance/override rules. Calling it "private variable support" because one popular language is unable to offer full variable isolation only devalues the concept.

Comment: You are right, I did not pick good words to describe the functionality - they are not real private variables. Edited as best as I could.

Comment: Who need private variables? When you're dumb nobody can prevent you from making dumb things in every programming language. When someone wants to change a constant (written in full upper case), he can do that, but he don't get his code through the code review.

Answer (score 3):

while not very pythonic you can write to a file using [`print`](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement)

`print>>outFile, 'I am Being Written'`

[Explanation](http://docs.python.org/reference/simple_stmts.html#the-print-statement):

> This form is sometimes referred to as
>   “`print` chevron.” In this form, the
>   first expression after the >> must
>   evaluate to a “file-like” object,
>   specifically an object that has a
>   `write()` method as described above.
>   With this extended form, the
>   subsequent expressions are printed to
>   this file object. **If the first
>   expression evaluates to `None`, then
>   `sys.stdout` is used as the file for
>   output.**

Comment: thanks for adding the explanation. I was sort of curious where I had seen that before, I've just been using it for awhile. Someone commented on it last night and I realized that others were probably unfamiliar with its usage.

Comment: This syntax saw some updating in Python 3, so you can now do `print('I am being writtten', file=outFile)`.  I was just reading about [the changes](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/linux/library/l-python3-1/).  So now it actually is much more pythonic.

Comment: very nice. I've been enjoying pypy lately, which may only delay my transition to python3.

Answer (score 3):

**Print multiline strings one screenful at a time**

Not really useful feature hidden in the `site._Printer` class, whose the `license` object is an instance. The latter, when called, prints the Python license. One can create another object of the same type, passing a string -- e.g. the content of a file -- as the second argument, and call it:

```
type(license)(0,open('textfile.txt').read(),0)()
```

That would print the file content splitted by a certain number of lines at a time:

```
...
file row 21
file row 22
file row 23

Hit Return for more, or q (and Return) to quit:
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use `exec` in a function the variable lookup rules change drastically.  Closures are no longer possible but Python allows arbitrary identifiers in the function.  This gives you a "modifiable locals()" and can be used to star-import identifiers.  On the downside it makes every lookup slower because the variables end up in a dict rather than slots in the frame:

```
>>> def f():
...  exec "a = 42"
...  return a
... 
>>> def g():
...  a = 42
...  return a
... 
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(f)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 ('a = 42')
              3 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
              6 DUP_TOP             
              7 EXEC_STMT           

  3           8 LOAD_NAME                0 (a)
             11 RETURN_VALUE        
>>> dis.dis(g)
  2           0 LOAD_CONST               1 (42)
              3 STORE_FAST               0 (a)

  3           6 LOAD_FAST                0 (a)
              9 RETURN_VALUE
```

Comment: Just to nitpick: that only applies to bare exec.  If you specify the namespace for it to use, eg "d={};  exec "a=42" in d" this won't happen.

Answer (score 2):

#### The `spam` module in standard Python

It is used for testing purposes.

I've picked it from [`ctypes` tutorial](http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html). Try it yourself:

```
>>> import __hello__
Hello world...
>>> type(__hello__)
<type 'module'>
>>> from __phello__ import spam
Hello world...
Hello world...
>>> type(spam)
<type 'module'>
>>> help(spam)
Help on module __phello__.spam in __phello__:

NAME
    __phello__.spam

FILE
    c:\python26\<frozen>
```

Comment: sorry, why and how would you use this?

Comment: @Casey: read "Accessing values exported from dlls" section from the `ctypes` tutorial http://starship.python.net/crew/theller/ctypes/tutorial.html#accessing-values-exported-from-dlls

Comment: Your example is unclear.

Answer (score 2):

**Memory Management**

Python dynamically allocates memory and uses garbage collection to recover unused space. Once an object is out of scope, and no other variables reference it, it will be recovered. I do not have to worry about buffer overruns and slowly growing server processes. Memory management is also a feature of other dynamic languages but Python just does it so well.

Of course, we must watch out for circular references and keeping references to objects which are no longer needed, but weak references help a lot here.

Answer (score 2):

The getattr built-in function :

```
>>> class C():
    def getMontys(self):
        self.montys = ['Cleese','Palin','Idle','Gilliam','Jones','Chapman']
        return self.montys


>>> c = C()
>>> getattr(c,'getMontys')()
['Cleese', 'Palin', 'Idle', 'Gilliam', 'Jones', 'Chapman']
>>>
```

Useful if you want to dispatch function depending on the context. See examples in Dive Into Python ([Here](http://diveintopython.net/power_of_introspection/getattr.html))

Answer (score 2):

**Classes as first-class objects (shown through a dynamic class definition)**

Note the use of the closure as well. If this particular example looks like a "right" approach to a problem, carefully reconsider ... several times :)

```
def makeMeANewClass(parent, value):
  class IAmAnObjectToo(parent):
    def theValue(self):
      return value
  return IAmAnObjectToo

Klass = makeMeANewClass(str, "fred")
o = Klass()
print isinstance(o, str)  # => True
print o.theValue()        # => fred
```

Answer (score 2):

Regarding Nick Johnson's implementation of a [Property class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/102062#102062) (just a demonstration of descriptors, of course, not a replacement for the built-in), I'd include a setter that raises an AttributeError:

```
class Property(object):
    def __init__(self, fget):
        self.fget = fget

    def __get__(self, obj, type):
        if obj is None:
            return self
        return self.fget(obj)

    def __set__(self, obj, value):
       raise AttributeError, 'Read-only attribute'
```

Including the setter makes this a data descriptor as opposed to a method/non-data descriptor. A data descriptor has precedence over instance dictionaries. Now an instance can't have a different object assigned to the property name, and attempts to assign to the property will raise an attribute error.

Answer (score 2):

Not at all a hidden feature but still nice:

```
import os.path as op

root_dir = op.abspath(op.join(op.dirname(__file__), ".."))
```

Saves lots of characters when manipulating paths !

Answer (score 2):

Ever used xrange(INT) instead of range(INT) .... It's got less memory usage and doesn't really depend on the size of the integer. Yey!! Isn't that good?

Comment: In Python 3, both are the same.

Answer (score 2):

Not really a hidden feature but something that might come in handy.

for looping through items in a list pairwise

```
for x, y in zip(s, s[1:]):
```

Answer (score 2):

```
>>> float('infinity')
inf
>>> float('NaN')
nan
```

More info:

- http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#float
- http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0754/
- [python nan and inf values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5438745/python-nan-and-inf-values)

Comment: People forget about these far too often. I've seen things like having a "count" argument to a function, which is then decreased by one until it gets to zero, defaulting to a special value which is made to mean not to stop, when `float('inf')` would do nicely, not requiring any special code at all (`inf - 1 == inf`).

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> x=[1,1,2,'a','a',3]
>>> y = [ _x for _x in x if not _x in locals()['_[1]'] ]
>>> y
[1, 2, 'a', 3]
```

"locals()['_[1]']" is the "secret name" of the list being created. Very useful when state of list being built affects subsequent build decisions.

Comment: Ew. This 'name' of the result list depends on too many factors to really consider it more than abuse of a specific implementation (and specific to a particular version, to boot.) On top of that it's an O(n^2) algorithm. Yuck.

Comment: Well, at least no one will claim this one isn't hidden.

Answer (score 1):

mapreduce using map and reduce functions

create a simple sumproduct this way:

```
def sumprod(x,y):
    return reduce(lambda a,b:a+b, map(lambda a, b: a*b,x,y))
```

example:

```
In [2]: sumprod([1,2,3],[4,5,6])
Out[2]: 32
```

Answer (score 1):

Not a programming feature but is useful when using Python with `bash` or `shell scripts`.

```
python -c"import os; print(os.getcwd());"
```

See the [python documentation here](http://docs.python.org/using/cmdline.html#cmdoption-unittest-discover-c). Additional things to note when writing **longer Python scripts** can be seen in [this discussion](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637020/long-programs-using-python-c-switch).

Answer (score 1):

Python's positional and keyword expansions can be used on the fly, not just from a stored list.

```
l=lambda x,y,z:x+y+z
a=1,2,3
print l(*a)
print l(*[a[0],2,3])
```

It is usually more useful with things like this:

```
a=[2,3]
l(*(a+[3]))
```

Answer (score 0):

You can construct a functions kwargs on demand:

```
kwargs = {}
kwargs[str("%s__icontains" % field)] = some_value
some_function(**kwargs)
```

The str() call is somehow needed, since python complains otherwise that it is no string. Don't know why ;)
I use this for a dynamic filters within Djangos object model:

```
result = model_class.objects.filter(**kwargs)
```

Comment: The reason is complains is probably because "field" is unicode, which makes the whole string unicode.

Answer (score 0):

**Multiply a string to get it repeated**

```
print "SO"*5
```

gives

```
SOSOSOSOSO
```

Comment: You can also do this with lists: `[3]*3 == [3, 3, 3]`

Answer (score 0):

**commands.getoutput**

If you want to get the output of a function which outputs directly to `stdout` or `stderr` as is the case with `os.system`, [`commands.getoutput`](http://docs.python.org/library/commands.html) comes to the rescue. The whole module is just made of awesome.

```
>>> print commands.getoutput('ls')
myFile1.txt    myFile2.txt    myFile3.txt    myFile4.txt    myFile5.txt
myFile6.txt    myFile7.txt    myFile8.txt    myFile9.txt    myFile10.txt
myFile11.txt   myFile12.txt   myFile13.txt   myFile14.txt   module.py
```

Comment: Given that it's basically a UNIX-only precursor to the `subprocess` module and has been removed in Python 3.0, shouldn't you be talking about `subprocess` instead of `commands`?

Comment: Touche! However, I'm using 2.7 on windows (not UNIX-only) at work. It works here and I just discovered it. Thus, I thought it was worth a mention.

Comment: specifically, `subprocess.check_output`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a helpful function I use when debugging type errors

```
def typePrint(object):
    print(str(object) + " - (" + str(type(object)) + ")")
```

It simply prints the input followed by the type, for example

```
>>> a = 101
>>> typePrint(a)
    101 - (<type 'int'>)
```

Answer (score 0):

**Interactive Debugging of Scripts (and doctest strings)**

I don't think this is as widely known as it could be, but add this line to any python script:

`import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`

will cause the PDB debugger to pop up with the run cursor at that point in the code.  What's even less known, I think, is that you can use that same line in a doctest:

```
"""
>>> 1 in (1,2,3)   
Becomes
>>> import pdb; pdb.set_trace(); 1 in (1,2,3)
"""
```

You can then use the debugger to checkout the doctest environment.  You can't really step through a doctest because the lines are each run autonomously, but it's a great tool for debugging the doctest globs and environment.

Answer (score 0):

In Python 2 you can generate a string representation of an expression by enclosing it with backticks:

```
 >>> `sorted`
'<built-in function sorted>'
```

This is gone in python 3.X.

Answer (score 0):

some cool features with reduce and operator.

```
>>> from operator import add,mul
>>> reduce(add,[1,2,3,4])
10
>>> reduce(mul,[1,2,3,4])
24
>>> reduce(add,[[1,2,3,4],[1,2,3,4]])
[1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> reduce(add,(1,2,3,4))
10
>>> reduce(mul,(1,2,3,4))
24
```

Answer (score -2):

```
is_ok() and "Yes" or "No"
```

Comment: That's strange. Interesting, but strange.

>>> True and "Yes" or "No"
'Yes'
>>> False and "Yes" or "No"
'No'
>>> x = "Yes"
>>> y = "No"
>>>
>>> False and x or y

Comment: The preferred way to accomplish this in Python 2.5 or up is " 'Yes' if is_ok() else 'No' ".

Comment: whether it is preferred or not, the way is correct and I use all the time and I think it is elegant. since this is hidden features question really interesting this post has been negatively voted,

Comment: "preferred" argument is open to discussion, becouse this way, the execution order is the same as the logical order, while "Yes" if True else "No" is not like that.

Comment: "Preferred" In this case means that the conditional operator works as expected for all possible operands.  Specifically, `True and False or True` is True, but `False if True else True` is false, which is almost certainly what you expected.  This is especially important where the operands have side effects, and the conditional operator will ***NEVER*** evaluate more than one of its conditional clauses.

Comment: This is a commonly used feature in many languages [especially bash, where the && || syntax is used to emulate ternary operator]

Answer (score -2):

```
for line in open('foo'):
    print(line)
```

which is equivalent (but better) to:

```
f = open('foo', 'r')
for line in f.readlines():
   print(line)
f.close()
```

Comment: That's not equivalent at all, because you can't predict when the file will be closed. That depends on the interpreter. As far as I know CPython garbage collects objects as soon as possible, but other interpreters might not.

Answer (score -5):

to activate the autocompletion in IDE that accepts it (like IDLE, Editra, IEP) instead of making:
"hi". (and then you hit TAB), you can cheat in the IDE, just make
hi". (and you heat TAB) (as you can see, there is no single quote in the beginning) because it will only follows the latest punctuation, it's like when you add : and hit enter, it adds directly an indentation, dont know if it will make change, but it's a tip no more :)

Comment: Can someone please clarify what this means?

Comment: that when you hit tab choices can be aviable even if it's not a string, just do this is IEP for example:
". and hit TAB, you'll get choices that offer them when dealing with strings...
or make this other hint:
: and hit enter, you'll get an identation :)

Comment: This seems to be just a common editor feature or two.

Answer (score -9):

**Braces**

```
def g():
    print 'hi!'

def f(): (
    g()
)

>>> f()
hi!
```

Comment: >>> def f(): (
...     g()
...     g()
  File "<stdin>", line 3
    g()
    ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Comment: I was trying to show that your feature doesn't work if you have more than one statement inside the "braces".

Comment: Everyone knows that Python uses `#{` and `#}` for braces. Subject to certain lexical constraints.