# What does ... mean in numpy code?

Tags: python, numpy

And what is it called? I don't know how to search for it; I tried calling it ellipsis with the Google.  I don't mean in interactive output when dots are used to indicate that the full array is not being shown, but as in the code I'm looking at,

`xTensor0[...] = xVTensor[..., 0]`

From my experimentation, it appears to function the similarly to `:` in indexing, but stands in for multiple `:`'s, making `x[:,:,1]` equivalent to `x[...,1]`.

Comment: Check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/772124/what-does-the-python-ellipsis-object-do  and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python

Comment: great, wasn't able to search for it.

Comment: Ha, but it's called "ellipsis," so I ought to have been able to.  I gave up early when "python numpy ..." didn't work.  Thanks sdolan.

Comment: Also, now I can't find a combination of sensible words to search for that doesn't bring up useful Google results for this topic, so apologies all.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you're right.  It fills in as many `:` as required.  The only difference occurs when you use multiple ellipses.  In that case, the first ellipsis acts in the same way, but each remaining one is converted to a single `:`.

Answer (score 3):

Although this feature exists mainly to support numpy and other, similar modules, it's a core feature of the language and can be used anywhere, like so:

```
>>> class foo:
...   def __getitem__(self, key):
...     return key
... 
>>> aFoo = foo()
>>> aFoo[..., 1]
(Ellipsis, 1)
>>>
```

or even:

```
>>> derp = {}
>>> derp[..., 1] = "herp"
>>> derp
{(Ellipsis, 1): 'herp'}
```

Answer (score 0):

Documentation here: http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

It does, well, what you describe it doing.