# Custom placeholder like None in python

Tags: python, metaclass

I'm using [argspec](http://docs.python.org/library/inspect.html#inspect.getargspec) in a function that takes another function or method as the argument, and returns a tuple like this:

```
(("arg1", obj1), ("arg2", obj2), ...)
```

This means that the first argument to the passed function is arg1 and it has a default value of obj1, and so on.

**Here's the rub**: if it has no default value, I need a placeholder value to signify this. I can't use None, because then I can't distinguish between *no default value* and *default value is None*. Same for False, 0, -1, etc. I could make it a tuple with a single element, but then the code for checking it would be ugly, and I can't easily turn it into a dict. So I thought I'd create a None-like object that isn't None, and this is what I've come up with:

```
class MetaNoDefault(type):
    def __repr__(cls):
        return cls.__name__
    __str__ = __repr__

class NoDefault(object):
    __metaclass__ = MetaNoDefault
```

Now `("arg1", NoDefault)` indicates arg1 has no default value, and I can do things like `if obj1 is NoDefault:` etc. The metaclass makes it print as just `NoDefault` instead of `<class '__main__.NoDefault'>`.

Is there any reason not to do it like this? Is there a better solution?

Comment: Is there any reason why you can not have tuple of just one element for no defaults? Something like: `(("arg1",), ("arg2", obj2), ...)` where "arg1" has no default. You can then do if `len(the_tuple) == 1` etc.

Comment: @FMc: In order to avoid mistakes coming from the accidental modification of the default arguments, it is better to never use mutable defaults.

Comment: @Fenikso I've covered this possibility in my question. In short, I find it inelegant, even though it _is_ intuitive.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My favourite sentinel is `Ellipsis`, and if I may [quote](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python/120055#120055) myself:

> it's there, it's an object, it's a singleton, and its name means "lack of", and it's not the overused None (which could be put in a queue as part of normal data flow). YMMV.

Comment: However, it's disappearing in Python 3. :-o

Comment: @Keith: citation, please. AFAIK in Python 3 you can even say `a = ...` (i.e. the `...` syntax can be used outside of slices), so I have the impression that it's not disappearing.

Comment: It seems I could quote myself from [even earlier](http://mail.python.org/pipermail/python-list/2004-August/273139.html) :)

Comment: @Keith: `Ellipsis` is still present in Python 3.  Just read the documentation for proof.

Comment: I could have swore I read that somewhere... but I guess not. I should stop writing here in the middle of the night when I'm tired.

Comment: This is what I ended up using, along with a comment explaining its purpose.

Comment: `Ellipsis` is however not great when you're using full type checking. 1. MyPy doesn't exclude Ellipsis from a type when it's been excluded with an if, as it does for None, or Enums per [PEP484](https://github.com/python/typing/pull/240). 2. `builtins.Ellipsis` is not valid as a type, so you can't really use it to type arguments.

Comment: @NavidKhan type checking can be an issue, yes, since type checkers tend to accept the instance`None` in place of its type `NoneType`; one can do something along the lines: `EllipsisType = type(Ellipsis)` and use that in type declarations.

Answer (score 5):

I had a similar situation some time ago. Here's what I came up with.

```
# Works like None, but is also a no-op callable and empty iterable.
class NULLType(type):
    def __new__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        return type.__new__(cls, name, bases, dct)
    def __init__(cls, name, bases, dct):
        super(NULLType, cls).__init__(name, bases, dct)
    def __str__(self):
        return ""
    def __repr__(self):
        return "NULL"
    def __nonzero__(self):
        return False
    def __len__(self):
        return 0
    def __call__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return None
    def __contains__(self, item):
        return False
    def __iter__(self):
        return self
    def next(*args):
        raise StopIteration
NULL = NULLType("NULL", (type,), {})
```

It can also act as a null callable and sequence.

Answer (score 4):

There isn't any reason to not use such sentinel objects for such purposes.  As an alternative to a class object, you could also create a singleton instance of a dynamically created type:

```
NoDefault = type('NoDefault', (object,), {
    '__str__': lambda s: 'NoDefault', '__repr__': lambda s: 'NoDefault'})()
```

Answer (score 0):

```
class Unset:
  pass

def my_method(optional_argument: str | None | Unset = Unset()):
  if not isinstance(optional_argument, Unset):
    ...
  ...
```

An implementation like this has the following benefits:

1. It allows you to use `None` as a valid value for `optional_argument`.
2. It allows for full type checking, as opposed to something like `Ellipsis` (...) that would throw `builtins.Ellipsis` is not valid as a type. (None is allowed to mean NoneType when used in type annotations)
3. MyPy excludes `Unset` from a type when it's been excluded with an if, as it does for None, or Enums per [PEP484](https://github.com/python/typing/pull/240).

Comment: The type of Ellipsis is `type(Ellipsis)` just like the type of None is `type(None)`. `None` is not a type but it gets preferential treatment in type checkers (ie when used in type declarations it is interpreted as `NoneType`).

Comment: Well, Ellipsis does not get preferential treatment, which makes it a bad replacement for None when using type checking.

Comment: Then you should accordingly amend the bullet 2 because as it is now you're saying the obvious (Ellipsis is not a type) while not mentioning the unobvious (None is allowed to mean NoneType when used in type annotations) and thus make your answer more helpful.