# Initialize parameter of method with default value

Tags: python

I would like to initialize a method's parameter with some default value if an explicit value was not passed into the method - something like this:

```
class Example
   def __init__(self, data = self.default_data()):
      self.data = data

   def default_data():
      # ....
      return something
```

I got the error:

```
NameError: name 'self' is not defined
```

How do I fix this?

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1132941/least-astonishment-in-python-the-mutable-default-argument

Answer (score 24, accepted):

The common idiom here is to set the default to some sentinel value (`None` is typical, although [some have suggested `Ellipsis`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185475/custom-placeholder-like-none-in-python/6186450#6186450) for this purpose) which you can then check.

```
class Example(object): #inherit from object.  It's just a good idea.
   def __init__(self, data = None):
      self.data = self.default_data() if data is None else data

   def default_data(self):  #probably need `self` here, unless this is a @staticmethod ...
      # ....
      return something
```

You might also see an instance of `object()` used for the sentinel.

```
SENTINEL = object()
class Example(object):
   def __init__(self, data = SENTINEL):
      self.data = self.default_data() if data is SENTINEL else data
```

This latter version has the benefit that you can pass `None` to your function but has a few downsides (see comments by @larsmans below).  If you don't forsee the need to pass `None` as a meaningful argument to your methods, I would advocate using that.

Comment: An `object()` as sentinel has the downside that it shows up really ugly in docstrings and the default behavior gets harder to obtain by explicit means, so passing `None` is the usual way of doing this (in the stdlib and most other Python libraries that I know).

Comment: @larsmans -- I prefer `None` as well, but if `None` happens to be something you want to pass, then `object()` is the next best thing.  If you really wanted, you could subclass object and just override `__repr__` to make `help` look nicer ... Also, if you import `Example`, you can also import `SENTINEL`.

Comment: If Python 3.x is used, inheriting from `object` is automatic.

Comment: @NoctisSkytower -- I'm well aware of that.  But, I find that it's of practical merit to attempt to write code which plays nicely with both python2.x and python3.x -- Also there's a script 2to3, but not a 3to2 ... It's an easy thing to do and makes the code more portable.  From that perspective, it just seems to make sense to inherit from `object` regardless.

Comment: I asked a related question a while ago and one of the [answers](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6186450/566644)  suggested using the built-in `Ellipsis` as sentinel. It doesn't have the disadvantages mentioned by @larsmans, I think.

Comment: @lazyr -- Yes and no.  You don't really see Ellipsis used except in the form `...` -- You couldn't call a function `foo(bar=...)` as that's a SyntaxError.  You'd have to call it `module.foo(bar=Ellipsis)`.  Personally, I'd rather have `module.foo(bar=module.SENTINEL)`.  It seems more explicit to me.  I suppose you could make `SENTINEL = Ellipsis` for the pretty printing ... Of course, these are all equivalent to `module.foo()`, but it matters in cases where you're packing `**kwargs` dynamically.

Comment: In 3.x, '...' compiles to the `Ellipsis` singleton, so you actually can use `foo(bar=...)`.

Comment: @eryksun -- Yeah, I just learned that from the comments on the link I reposted from lazyr.  That's pretty cool.