# Variable assignment inside a function argument

Tags: python, function

```
def auto_detect_serial_unix(preferred_list=['*']):
```

What happens to the argument when this function gets called?

Comment: You need to read [the Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#default-argument-values).

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Default Values for function parameters in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195989/default-values-for-function-parameters-in-python)

Answer (score 0):

If nothing is passed in to `auto_detect_serial_unix`, then preferred_list is set to `['*']`. Otherwise, what you pass in is set to `preferred_list`:

```
>>> def auto_detect_serial_unix(preferred_list=['*']):
...     print preferred_list
... 
>>> auto_detect_serial_unix()
['*']
>>> auto_detect_serial_unix(['new', 'list'])
['new', 'list']
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

If `auto_detect_serial_unix` is called with an argument, then `preferred_list` will have the value of that argument.

Otherwise, if `auto_detect_serial_unix` is called with no arguments, then `preferred_list` will have the given default value.