# Python pass variable by...?

Tags: python

I got this snippet of code from here:http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables

Its main idea is in Python, variables are name tags to objects. But then the author gives the following code, which I don't understand why they behave differently.

```
def bad_append(new_item, a_list = []):
    a_list.append(new_item)
    return a_list

bad_append(1)   # returns [1]
bad_append(2)   # returns [1, 2]
```

Another function:

```
def good_append(new_item, a_list = None):
    if a_list == None:
        a_list = []
    a_list.append(new_item)
    return a_list

good_append(1)    # returns [1]
good_append(2)    # returns [2]
```

This question might be relevant, but many concepts are mixed up (e.g mutable, reference, variables) and I'm still confused... 
[How do I pass a variable by reference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/986006/how-do-i-pass-a-variable-by-reference)

Thus, can I ask for some kind explanation on why the two functions above behave differently?

Comment: Please take a look at this thread explaining how default values for function parameters work: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195989/default-values-for-function-parameters-in-python

Comment: Thanks @cthulhu for the pointer! Yes that seems to be what I need.