# Django not recognizing files deleted/added

Tags: django, python-3.x

I have the following function that gives me the list of files(complete path) in a given list of directories:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join

# Returns a list of all the files in the list of directories passed
def get_files(directories = get_template_directories()):
    files = []
    for directory in directories:
        for dir, dirnames, filenames in walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                file_name = join(dir, filename)
                files.append(file_name)
    return files
```

I'am adding some files to the template directories in Django. But this function always return the same list of files even though some are added/deleted in the run time. These changes are reflected only when I do a server restart. Is that because of some caching that os.walk() performs or is it required that we need to restart the server after adding/removing some files ?

Comment: Actually, what are you trying to achieve here?

Comment: I'am adding/deleting some template files in django from my Django Applications. @JerinPeterGeorge

Comment: Ok, Is there any problem with *adding/deleting*?

Comment: I can see these changes in my file explorer. But not getting reflected in my Django app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not django problem, your behaviour is result of `python` interpreter specific:

> Default arguments may be provided as plain values or as the result of a function call, but this latter technique need a very big warning. Default values evaluated once at start application and never else.

I' m sure this code will solve your problem:

```
def get_files(directories = None):
    if not directories:
        directories = get_template_directories()
    files = []
    for directory in directories:
        for dir, dirnames, filenames in walk(directory):
            for filename in filenames:
                file_name = join(dir, filename)
                files.append(file_name)
    return files
```

You can find same questions on Stackoverflow [Default Values for function parameters in Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195989/default-values-for-function-parameters-in-python)

Comment: I never knew about this. I'am relatively new to python and lacks a strong base. Thanks a lot...@PavelMinenkov