# Make a variable update its value based on returns

Tags: python, function, return

I'm having an issue because i have to run the same function many times and want to record a total for every time it was run.

```
def add(word):
    total_hello=0
    total_world=0
    if word=="hello":
       total_hello+=1
    elif word=="world":
       total_world+=1

    print(total_hello)
    print(total_world)
    return total_hello, total_world

hello=0
world=0
hello, world+=add("hello")
hello, world+=add("world")
hello, world+=add("hello")
print(hello)
print(world)
```

Making hello a variable and trying to make it += the return doesn't work. Is there anything simple i can do to add the returns efficiently?

Comment: `hello, world` makes a tuple. You can't use `+=` like that to add from a tuple to a tuple.

Comment: if you redefine the `+=` then you can, but not in the vanilla form

Comment: Please add the traceback so we see the exact error. Also, what would you like to happen? Do you want to add the 2 output values to `hello` and `world`?

Comment: Use global variables or pass the variable reference to the function and update them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Making hello a variable and trying to make it += the return doesn't work. Is there anything simple i can do to add the returns efficiently?

You can't just add the elements of tuple returned by your function to the tuple's element on left-hand side. You have following options:

1. The variables (`total_hello` and `total_world`) are local to your function and they are reassigned every-time you call your function to `0`. Try moving them outside your function and make them global. They can be used to store the count of the variables.

```
# Code in Module 1:
total_hello=0
total_world=0

def add(word):
    global total_hello, total_world
    if word=="hello":
       total_hello+=1
    elif word=="world":
       total_world+=1

    return total_hello, total_world


# Code in Module 2:
# from Module1 import *
add("hello")
add("world")
hello, world = add("hello")
print(hello)
print(world)
```

2. See [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/279586/5735010) answer for a more Pythonic way.
3. Using [default arguments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13195989/default-values-for-function-parameters-in-python) in Python:

```
def add(word, total_world=[0], total_hello=[0]):
    if word == "hello":
       total_hello[0] += 1
    elif word == "world":
       total_world[0] += 1

    return total_hello[0], total_world[0]


add("hello")
add("world")
hello, world = add("hello")
print(hello)
print(world)
```

Comment: then it gives a "referenced before assignment" alert

Comment: I ran this code and it works for me. Point it out where it is failing for you1

Comment: Wasn't working on my code in the beginning but I figured it out thank you so much global helps

Answer (score 1):

You can directly use `hello` and `world` inside function.

```
hello=0
world=0
def add(word):
    global hello, world
    if word=="hello":
       hello+=1
    elif word=="world":
       world+=1

    print(hello)
    print(world)

add("hello")
add("world")
add("hello")

print(hello)
print(world)
```