# How do I set default parameters in a method?

Tags: python, oop, parameters, default

I want this method to update a certain value, unless passed another value, which it should update instead.  Here's an example of what I want to do:

```
def update_t(self,t=self.t):  
    "If nothing is passed, then the default parameter is the attribute self.t"
    t=t+1
```

I get "self is not defined"

This is a related question:[default value of parameter as result of instance method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13075044/default-value-of-parameter-as-result-of-instance-method)

...but since this value is updated, I can't have it be None.  I also cant have t be an object, because that would give me an error (can't add object and int).  Any ideas? Thanks.

Comment: Function calls don't work this way; you can't pass in a variable or attribute and have assignments to the function's argument affect the variable or attribute or list item or whatever that the function was called with.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use an object that *can* be resolved. Such as `None`.

```
def update_t(self, t=None):  
  "If nothing is passed, then the default parameter is the attribute self.t"
  if t is None:
    self.t += 1
  else:
    t += 1
```

Note that this may not change the value passed to it since the local name may be rebound if the object doesn't have a `__iadd__()` method.