# Other unique-instance objects besides None in python?

Tags: python, built-in

The python language reference mentions three objects which have a single, unique instance: `None`, `NotImplemented`, and `Ellipsis` ([section 3.2 "The Standard Type Hierarchy"](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#the-standard-type-hierarchy)).  The test `x is None` is a common idiom made possible by the guaranteed uniqueness of `None`.  I cannot find any other mention of unique-instance objects, either in python documentation or on stack overflow.  A few questions, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185475/custom-placeholder-like-none-in-python) have interesting suggestions for ways to construct such objects, but what I want to know is whether there are any beyond these three built-ins that I've missed.

For example, `()` appears to be unique (in admittedly very limited testing in CPython), so is the test `x is ()` safe?  Or is `x == ()` mandatory for this case?

Comment: It makes no sense to test for `x is ()`,  `if x` would achieve the same. Why are you actually asking?

Comment: There are many possible values for which `bool(x)` is `False`.  I needed to check whether `x` was actually `()`, not one of the other possibilities, for exactly the same reason that you use `x is None`.

Comment: not if  x is a tuple, `isinstance(x, tuple)` would also explicitly allow you to check that x was in fact a tuple

Comment: It was helpful to see this and realize that I could also return NotImplemented instead of None (and test it using 'is')  when I want to signal that something doesn't really exist when None is a valid value (i.e. the object being requested from a function/method exists, but it can have the value of None   vs the object not existing)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nope, there are no other built in types that have single values. The only relative of these singletons is the `bool` type which allows for two values (namely `True` and `False`)*.

In `Python 2.x` (I cannot find them in `3.x`) you can see this limitation by importing `NotImplementedType, EllipsisType, NoneType` from the **[`types`](https://docs.python.org/2.7/library/types.html)** module and realize that it is explicitly not with it's fancy custom `TypeError`:

```
In [13]: from types import NoneType

In [14]: n = NoneType()
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-14-b386f51143fb> in <module>()
----> 1 n = NoneType()

TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

`()` is unfortunately not unique, it represents an empty tuple, if the type `Tuple` was unique in the sense that `NoneType` is unique then all its instances would require to have **the same value**.

---

If you want to take a closer look at these, they are located in **[`Objects/object.c`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c)** in lines **[`1351`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c#l1351)** and **[`1473`](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/tip/Objects/object.c#l1473)** for `None` and `NotImplemented` respectively. Ellipsis is yet to be found.

---

*Update: Apparently, `True` and `False` are **also** singletons, according to **[`PEP 285 - Adding a bool type`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0285/)**:

> The values False and True will be singletons, like None.  Because
>       the type has two values, perhaps these should be called
>       "doubletons"?  The real implementation will not allow other
>       instances of bool to be created

Answer (score 2):

Well... you can think of any global object as being "unique" in the sense that it is always the same object.

For example:

```
>>> x = file
>>> x is file
True
>>> x = True
>>> x is True
True
>>> x = ZeroDivisionError
>>> x is ZeroDivisionError
True
```

There is nothing special about:

```
>>> x = None
>>> x is None
True
```

What you are probably wondering is why you should test `x is None` rather than `x == None`.

The answer is: `x == None` will call `x.__eq__(None)` which may return `True` in all sorts of situations where `x` is not actually `None` (although in reality that is not very common).

**Instance?**

Well, you may say there is a difference: `None` is an instance.

Well, the truth is, everything in Python is an object, which means everything is an instance. In my examples, `file` and `ZeroDivisionError` are instances of `type`, `True` is instance of `bool` and `None` is instance of `NoneType` (note that `type` is an instance of `type`, so there are no exceptions to the rule).

There is one special thing about `None` - it is the only instance of `NoneType` and you cannot make others (unless there is some good trick?)

But that is actually a property of `NoneType` - it does not let you make new instances:

```
TypeError: cannot create 'NoneType' instances
```

But that is not really essential for the whole story.

**EDIT**  These "*unique-instance objects*" are called singletons. You can make some of yours, of course.

Answer (score 1):

For what is worth, `()` is not unique in PyPy 4.0.1:

```
>>>> x = ()
>>>> x is ()
False
```

Comment: He mentioned CPython specifically.