# What does [...] (an ellipsis) in a list mean in Python?

Tags: python

I just got some weird output of a python script:

```
[[(7, 6), (6, 4), (7, 2)], [...], [...], [...], [(7, 6), (8, 4), (7, 2)], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...], [...]]
```

The output should be a list of lists of tuples. But I have no idea why [...] appears.

What does [...] mean?

I don't think its an empty list, as an empty list were []. Are these perhaps duplicates?

Comment: This might help - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python

Comment: @arunkumar: The `repr` of `Ellipsis` is `"Ellipsis"`.

Comment: See also: [What is \[…\] in Python 2.7?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/17160162/562769)

Comment: Please note that I have asked this question two years before the question came up that I've linked to. So the duplicate is rather the new question than my question.

Comment: not a duplicate, this question is way older than http://stackoverflow.com/q/17160162/2932052

Comment: Duplicates are not [necessarily the newest one](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10841/148169). The goal is to keep the best answers and [this is a *far* better answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/17163521/344286) than any answer here.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

It is a recursive reference. Your list contains itself, or at least there is some kind of cycle.

Example:

```
x = []
x.insert(0, x)
# now the repr(x) is '[[...]]'.
```

The built-in `repr` for lists detects this situation and does not attempt to recurse on the sub-list (as it normally would), because that would lead to infinite recursion.

Note that `...` doesn't necessarily tell you which list is referred to:

```
y, z = [], []
x = [y, z]
y.insert(0, z)
z.insert(0, y)
# looks the same as it would if y contained y and z contained z.
```

so `repr` is not really a complete serialization format for lists.

As to why you're getting them: we're not psychic, and can't fix the problem with your code unless we see the code.