# Why does appending a list to itself show [...] when printed?

Tags: python, list, python-2.7, python-3.x

When I appended the list in itself using the following code.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
print a

a.append(a)
print a
```

I was expecting the output to be...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

But it was something like this...

```
[1, 2, 3, 4]
[1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]
```

**WHY?**

Comment: Try printing `a[4]` and see what you get ;)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7223222/what-does-an-ellipsis-in-a-list-mean-in-python

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are adding `a` to `a` itself. The second element of `a` is `a` only. So, if it tries to print `a`, as you wanted

- it would print the first element `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
- it would print the second element, which is actually `a`

  - it would print the first element `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
  - it would print the second element, which is actually `a`

    - it would print the first element `[1, 2, 3, 4]`
    - it would print the second element, which is actually `a` ...

you see how it is going, right? It will be doing it infinitely. So when there is a circular reference like this, Python will represent that as an ellipsis within a pair of square brackets, `[...]`, only.

If you want to insert a copy of `a` as it is, then you can use [slicing](https://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116) to create a new list, like this

```
>>> a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
>>> a.append(a[:])
>>> a
[1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: Does it mean that it is something like [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, [1, 2, 3, 4, [...]]]] ? and can I use loop in it to get 'my expected results'?

Comment: @Myni The solution I suggested in my answer will give you the expected results.

Comment: What does " (a[:]) " do, @thefourtheye ?

Comment: @Myni It will create a copy of the list `a`. It is called [slicing notation](http://stackoverflow.com/a/509295/1903116)

Comment: I know that it is slicing notation, but what I meant was, what is ' a[:] ' exactly doing?

Comment: @Myni Normally slicing notations create a new list and return the sliced list. In this case, since the starting, ending and step are not mentioned, it will create a copy of the entire list.

Answer (score 0):

You could also add them using a for loop, But you end up with one big list.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

lengthOfA = len(a)

for x in range(0, lengthOfA):
    item = a[x]
    a.append(item)

print a #Answer is [1, 2, 3, 4, 1, 2, 3, 4]
```

I like this answer because it dosent create a nested list, But if that's not what you want please discard this answer.

If you want a list inside a list, You can use thefourtheye's awnser.

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]

a.append(a[:])

print a #Answer is [1, 2, 3, 4 [1, 2, 3, 4]]
```

Comment: There's an easier way to do that: `a.extend(a)`. BTW, the word is "answer" not "awnser".

Comment: Yes @Jammeh I wanted a list inside a list, is there a way?

Comment: @Myni: thefourtheye showed you how to append a copy of the list `a` to `a`. What's wrong with his answer?

Comment: Spelling mistakes fixed and edited answer to include thefourtheye's awnser