# What does this Slicing and Ellipse index operations result in?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, indexing, operators

I try to understand what happens with this code using ndarrays:

```
max_evecs = evecs[..., :, 0]
```

where evecs is of type ndarray. So far I know that ':' is a slicing operator, and '...' is a so called Ellipse. So far ':' means all elements and '...' refers to as many as needed. I investigated the arrays with shape:

```
>>> max_evecs.shape
(128, 128, 72)
>>> evecs.shape
(128, 128, 72, 3)
```

I could imagine that, it is tried to convert a 3D array into an array of triples (x,y,z). But I am not sure about that.

For those who care: its from the dipy software package: function `quantize_evecs` inside https://github.com/nipy/dipy/blob/ff75b192f694cdb62cc11310159cdb652ce62073/dipy/reconst/dti.py line around 1663

Comment: If you simply want to get a handle on the entire array (e.g. in order to assign to value in a for loop), you can use either `A[:]` or `A[...]`

Answer (score 4):

From http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html

> Ellipsis expand to the number of : objects needed to make a selection
>   tuple of the same length as x.ndim. Only the first ellipsis is
>   expanded, any others are interpreted as :.

So in your example, `evecs` has `ndim` equal to 4, and the following are equivalent:

```
evecs[..., :, 0]
evecs[:, :, :, 0]
```

It is also helpful to try things out interactively to get a feel for it. With some simple data, for example `a = np.random.rand(3, 3, 2)`, try printing out `a` and various slices of it like `a[..., 0]` and `a[1, ...]` and similar and see how they are related.

Comment: I looked into the doc, there they have a `x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])` and then run: `x[...,0]` which should result in `array([[1, 2, 3],[4, 5, 6]])` However I get `array(0)` for this example. This does not make sense to me.

Comment: For this example, `x.ndim` is 1. So `x[..., 0]` is the same as `x[0]` (there are no dimensions/axes remaining after specifying the 0).

Comment: An alternate explanation from [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/118508/553404). The ellipsis means "at this point, insert as many full slices (:) to extend the multi-dimensional slice to all dimensions."

Comment: Thanks, to all of you. The python doc, just uses another x array than I thought:  `x = np.array([[[1],[2],[3]], [[4],[5],[6]]])`