# How does one index a numpy array using another numpy array that holds the indices?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

This should be simple task but I am ashamed to admit I'm stuck.

I have a numpy array, called `X`:

`X.shape` is `(10,3)`and it looks like

```
[[  0.   0.  13.  ]
 [  0.   0.   1.  ]
 [  0.   4.  16.  ]
 ..., 
 [  0.   0.   4.  ]
 [  0.   0.   2.  ]
 [  0.   0.   4.  ]]
```

I would like to select the 1, 2 and 3rd row of this array, using the indices in this other numpy array, called `idx`:

`idx.shape` is `(3,)` and it looks like `[1 2 3]`

When I try
`new_array = X[idx]`  or variations on this, 
I get errors.

How does one index a numpy array using another numpy array that holds the indices?

Apologizes for such a basic question in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I do it like this:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> x = np.arange(30).reshape((10, 3))
>>> x
array([[ 0,  1,  2],
       [ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14],
       [15, 16, 17],
       [18, 19, 20],
       [21, 22, 23],
       [24, 25, 26],
       [27, 28, 29]])
>>> idx = np.array([1,2,3])
>>> x[idx, ...]
array([[ 3,  4,  5],
       [ 6,  7,  8],
       [ 9, 10, 11]])
```

Note that in this case, the ellipsis could be replaced by a simple slice if you'd rather:

```
x[idx, :]
```

Comment: I haven't seen something like `x[idx, ...]` before.  What are three dots doing in an array index??  I obviously need to spend a weekend studying numpy.

Comment: @MattO'Brien -- `...` is the python Ellipsis object.  See this post for some links.  http://stackoverflow.com/a/118395/748858

Comment: Err... apparently those links are broken.  check [this](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/arrays.indexing.html) one instead.