# Difference between arr[..., 0] and arr[:, 0]

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

What is the difference between the two notations for 'slicing' an array?

```
from numpy import ones

arr = ones((3,3))
arr[:, 0] += 1
arr[..., 1] += 2

#arr
#array([[2, 3, 1],
#       [2, 3, 1],
#       [2, 3, 1]])
```

Are they interchangeable?

Comment: What about this answer? http://stackoverflow.com/a/118508/1447225

Comment: Thank you, I guess I didn't find any answers because I didn't know what it was called