# What is the difference between numpyArr[:,:,:,c] and numpyArr[...,c]?

Tags: python, numpy, multidimensional-array, slice, numpy-ndarray

I've beeen taking deep learning course on coursera. While I was doing my assignment I saw one piece of code on the github.

```
1. numpyArr[...,c]
2. numpyArr[:,:,:,c]
```

What is the difference between these slicing methods?

Comment: Not valid syntax – make sure that `mylist` really **is** a `list`.

Comment: Could you link to the specific Github page where you saw the piece of code?

Comment: The second is about multidimensional arrays, right? `mylist [:,:,:,c]` is actually a 4D array, not a list.

Comment: https://github.com/Kulbear/deep-learning-coursera/blob/master/Convolutional%20Neural%20Networks/Convolution%20model%20-%20Step%20by%20Step%20-%20v1.ipynb

Comment: @meowgoesthedog The *syntax* is perfectly fine. The *meaning* doesn't work for `list` though.

Comment: yes, multidimensional arrays

Comment: It's specific to [tag:numpy] then.

Comment: @ömerbeden: actually **numpy's ndarrays**, not Python's native multidimensional arrays.

Comment: ok, I got  that's specific for numpy then, Is there any difference ?

Comment: The second syntax `[:,:,:,c]` is the more commonly used, I am seeing the other syntax for the first time

Comment: @anand_v.singh Thanks a lot. Actually I 'm seeing the other syntax first ,too. In the practice I can't find any difference between those methods.

Comment: Also using the first syntax `[…,c]` I was unable to figure out a way to select a certain value from an intermediate dimension, I am now sure if it exists, hence I am not going to add an answer. i.e. I was unable to find an equivalent of `[:,:,c,:]`

Comment: @anand_v.singh it is `arr[...,c,:]`

Comment: @oekopez so you can get till one dimension by `,:` and use elipses to include all the remaining dimensions on either side but only one side, is my understanding correct?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If  both arrays have 4 dimensions there is no difference in the result. However, if you do not really care about the number of dimensions, using the Ellipsis (...) just indicates any number of dimensions. So the first version means:

"get all dimensions but from the last one (whatever the last is) only entry `c` "

and the second means

"get dimensions 0, 1, 2 complete and from dimension 3 only entry `c`.

Which is the same for a 4-d array but different for a 5d array.

For an array with many dimensions even more fun is possible:

```
arr = np.random.uniform(size=(3, 3, 3, 3, 3))
print(arr[1, ..., 2, 3].shape)
```

Which means: get the second entry on the first dimension and of that entry 2 and 3 of the two last dimensions with everything in between.

[Some years ago, this has already been asked](https://stackoverflow.com/a/118395/3032680), but one needs to know that `...` is the Ellipsis.