# Adding a new dimension to a Numpy array

Tags: python, numpy

I'm newbie with Python.

I have found this code:

```
array = FLAIR_array[..., np.newaxis] # FLAIR_array is a Numpy array.
```

FLAIR_array shape is `(960, 200, 200)` and array shape is `(960, 200, 200, 1)`.

`np.newaxis` has added a new dimension to the array, but I don't know what value is in that new dimension (this is a question, but I think I can't ask more than one thing on the same question).

My question is: What does `...` mean in `FLAIR_array[..., np.newaxis]`?

Comment: Is the question about the new axis or about the ellipsis (=`...`)?

Comment: Yes. The problem is that I don't know how to name that, `...`, in English.

Comment: There are no "new values" in the new dimension, it's just a different shape, the same as if you go from `[1, 2, 3]` (shape `(3,)`) to `[[1], [2], [3]]` (shape `(3, 1)`). The ellipsis is kind of a wildcard for "as many dimensions as I am not explicitly giving", see (possible dupe) [How do you use the ellipsis slicing syntax in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/118370/1782792).

Comment: Also, see [NumPy's documentation on indexing](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html)

Comment: @VansFannel the three dots are called "ellipsis" ;)

Comment: @GPhilo, thanks!! You are great!

Comment: Inside the `FLAIR_array` there are grey images. I think they are only a new dimension to denote that the images have only one channel. What do you think?