# What is the use of Ellipsis in Python?

Tags: python, python-3.x, ellipse

Could someone please help, what is the use of Ellipse in Python with some examples and when to use it?

I have done some search on this it can be used with a function :

```
 def add():
     ...
```

and with slicing in the list.

```
import numpy
n = numpy.arange(16).reshape(2, 2, 2, 2)

print(n)

print('----------------')
print(n[1,...,1])

[[[[ 0  1]
   [ 2  3]]

  [[ 4  5]
   [ 6  7]]]


 [[[ 8  9]
   [10 11]]

  [[12 13]
   [14 15]]]]
----------------
Ellipsis:[[ 9 11]
 [13 15]]
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do you use the ellipsis slicing syntax in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python)

Answer (score 6):

Originally the ellipsis literal (that's what `...` is) was very restricted, in Python 2 it could essentially only be used as a sentinel when slicing, and *what* it would do specifically was not prescriptive and was entirely defined by how the *container* would react (I don't think any of the standard library containers handled ellipsis, so it was mostly for numpy).

In Python 3 the ellipsis operator was relaxed somewhat, the old usage stays but it has also gained a new use as a less verbose version of `pass`, which is also a traditional "longhand" use of ellipsis, when you either don't care what a function body is or haven't come to fill it yet, you can just put in `...` instead of `pass`, it's basically a no-op but it looks a bit better / less noisy:

```py
def do_foo():
    pass
```

versus

```py
def do_foo():
    ...
```

Comment: could you please help me with the list example also

Comment: That's the first part, it's a slice and what happens is whatever numpy wants to do with it, [which numpy documents](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/arrays.indexing.html#basic-slicing-and-indexing) "Ellipsis expand to the number of : objects needed to make a selection tuple of the same length as x.ndim.". See also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/118370/how-do-you-use-the-ellipsis-slicing-syntax-in-python

Comment: Although some are doing this, it's probably better to just use `pass` since there is no official documentation around using `Ellipsis`.

Comment: a complete answer should also address numpy's m[..., 0] for instance, and also what is means in an import statement (which is what I came here looking for).