# numpy: how to change row array into column array

Tags: python, python-3.x, numpy

This seems quite difficult for me. I have tried multiple solution but it didn't  worked

my original array is in this form:

```
arr = np.array([
    [
        [1, 3, 9, 1],
        [2, 2, 9, 1],
        [1, 1, 6, 4],
    ],
    [
        [3, 3, 3, 4],
        [0, 9, 2, 6],
        [7, 6, 6, 1],
    ]
])
```

Where as my expected output is:

```
    arr = np.array(
        [
            [
                [
                    [1],
                    [2],
                    [1],
                ],
                [
                    [3],
                    [2],
                    [1],
                ],
                [
                    [9],
                    [9],
                    [6],
                ],
                [
                    [1],
                    [1],
                    [4],
                ],
            ],


            [
                [
                    [3],
                    [0],
                    [7],
                ],
                [
                    [3],
                    [9],
                    [6],
                ],
                [
                    [3],
                    [2],
                    [6],
                ],
                [
                    [4],
                    [6],
                    [1],
                ],
            ],
   ]
)
```

How can I achieve above output, i have tried `np.reshape(arr, (len(arr[0][0]), len(arr[0]), 1))` and many more but failed to obtain my expected output. Please suggest changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Transpose and then expand the axis:

```
>>> arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)[..., None]
array([[[[1],
         [2],
         [1]],

        [[3],
         [2],
         [1]],

        [[9],
         [9],
         [6]],

        [[1],
         [1],
         [4]]],


       [[[3],
         [0],
         [7]],

        [[3],
         [9],
         [6]],

        [[3],
         [2],
         [6]],

        [[4],
         [6],
         [1]]]])
```

The shape of the original array is `(2, 3, 4)`, and the shape of the expected array is `(2, 4, 3, 1)`, `arr.transpose(0, 2, 1)` will swap the lengths of the last two axes (because the positions of the last two numbers of `(0, 1, 2)` are exchanged here):

```
>>> arr.transpose(0, 2, 1).shape
(2, 4, 3)
```

A more intuitive example might be using `swapaxes`:

```
>>> arr.swapaxes(1, 2).shape
(2, 4, 3)
```

Slicing is used to expand the axis, where `[..., None]` is equivalent to `[:, :, :, None]` (the number of `:` depends on your array dimension), which will expand the shape of the array from `(a, b, c)` to `(a, b, c, 1)`.

Comment: What are 3 dots in `[..., None]`?

Comment: @AzharKhan https://stackoverflow.com/a/118508/17980931

Comment: it worked thanks, can you also please explain what is (0, 2, 1) in here and does [..., None] will make any difference if i make array length changes

Comment: @Mogli141 I updated my answer. Is there anything else to explain?

Comment: well explained. thanks