# What is the regular expression for /urlchecker/http://www.google.com

Tags: python, regex, django

I'm writing a url rewrite in django that when a person goes to http://mysite.com/urlchecker/http://www.google.com   it sends the url: http://ww.google.com to a view as a string variable.

I tried doing:

```
(r'^urlchecker/(?P<url>\w+)/$', 'mysite.main.views.urlchecker'),
```

But that didn't work. Anyone know what I'm doing wrong?

Also, generally is there a good resource to learn regular expressions specifically for python/django?

Thanks guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this instead:

`(r'^urlchecker/(?P<url>.+)$', 'mysite.main.views.urlchecker'),`

This differs from yours in that:

- It will take anything after 'urlcheck/', not just "word" characters.
- It does not force the url to end in a slash.

Answer (score 0):

I just learned something while grazing the Hidden Features of Python thread.
[Python's re compiler has a debug mode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#143636)! (Who knew? Well, apparently someone did :-) Anyway, it's worth a read.