# Scripting inside a Python application

Tags: python, scripting

I'd like to include **Python scripting** in one of my applications, that is written in Python itself.

My application must be able to call external Python functions (written by the user) as **callbacks**. There must be some control on code execution; for example, if the user provided code with syntax errors, the application must signal that.

What is the best way to do this?

Thanks.

*edit*: question was unclear. I need a mechanism similar to events of VBA, where there is a "declarations" section (where you define global variables) and events, with scripted code, that fire at specific points.

Comment: Out of interest, what kind of application is it?

Comment: I'm developing a log analysis tool that would be extendable/scriptable (actions are made as the logfiles are read).

The principle is: "every application in an enterprise has its own logfile format, so give the user the flexibility to define its own monitoring rules".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `__import__` to import the files provided by the user. This function will return a module. Use that to call the functions from the imported file.

Use `try..except` both on `__import__` and on the actual call to catch errors.

Example:

```
m = None
try:
    m = __import__("external_module")
except:
    # invalid module - show error
if m:
    try:
        m.user_defined_func()
    except:
        # some error - display it
```

Answer (score 8):

If you'd like the user to interactively enter commands, I can highly recommend the [code](http://docs.python.org/library/code.html) module, part of the standard library. The InteractiveConsole and InteractiveInterpreter objects allow for easy entry and evaluation of user input, and errors are handled very nicely, with tracebacks available to help the user get it right.

Just make sure to catch SystemExit!

```
$ python
Python 2.5.1 (r251:54863, Jan 17 2008, 19:35:17) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> shared_var = "Set in main console"
>>> import code
>>> ic = code.InteractiveConsole({ 'shared_var': shared_var })
>>> try:
...     ic.interact("My custom console banner!")
... except SystemExit, e:
...     print "Got SystemExit!"
... 
My custom console banner!
>>> shared_var
'Set in main console'
>>> shared_var = "Set in sub-console"
>>> sys.exit()
Got SystemExit!
>>> shared_var
'Set in main console'
```

Answer (score 4):

[RestrictedPython](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/RestrictedPython) provides a restricted execution environment for Python, e.g. for running untrusted code.

Answer (score 0):

"My application must be able to call external Python functions (written by the user) as callbacks".

There's an alternative that's often simpler.

Define classes which call method functions at specific points.  You provide a default implementation.

Your user can then extended the classes and provide appropriate method functions instead of callbacks.

This rarely requires global variables.  It's also simpler to implement because your user does something like the following

```
import core_classes
class MyExtension( core_classes.SomeClass ):
    def event_1( self, args ):
        # override the default behavior for event_1.

core_classes.main( MyExtension )
```

This works very smoothly, and allows maximum flexibility.  Errors will always be in their code, since their code is the "main" module.