# Python shortcuts

Tags: python, shortcut, refactoring

Python is filled with little neat shortcuts.

For example:

```
self.data = map(lambda x: list(x), data)
```

and (although not so pretty)

```
tuple(t[0] for t in self.result if t[0] != 'mysql' and t[0] != 'information_schema')
```

among countless others.

In the irc channel, they said "too many to know them all".

I think we should list some here, as i love using these shortcuts to shorten & refctor my code. I'm sure this would benefit many.

Comment: duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python

Comment: Voted duplicate as well. It's also not a real question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
self.data = map(lambda x: list(x), data)
```

is dreck -- use

```
self.data = map(list, data)
```

if you're a `map` fanatic (list comprehensions are generally preferred these days). More generally, `lambda x: somecallable(x)` can **always** be productively changed to just `somecallable`, in **every** context, with nothing but good effect.

As for shortcuts in general, my wife and I did our best to list the most important and useful one in the early part of the Python Cookbook's second edition -- could be a start.

Comment: Amazing. Thank you. This is the beauty of refactoring in python. Just when i thought i had refactored it to as simple and short as possible, i was wrong. :)  Thanks again

Answer (score 3):

Alex Martelli provided an even shorter version of your first example.  I shall provide a (slightly) shorter version of your second:

```
tuple(t[0] for t in self.result if t[0] not in ('mysql', 'information_schema'))
```

Obviously the in operator becomes more advantageous the more values you're testing for.

I would also like to stress that shortening and refactoring is good only to the extent that it improves clarity and readability.  (Unless you are code-golfing. ;)

Comment: Ah thanks for this. Feel free to contribute to this thread if you know other neat shortcuts =]

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure if this is a shortcut, but I love it:

```
>>> class Enum(object):
        def __init__(self, *keys):
            self.keys = keys
            self.__dict__.update(zip(keys, range(len(keys))))
        def value(self, key):
            return self.keys.index(key)          

>>> colors = Enum("Red", "Blue", "Green", "Yellow", "Purple")
>>> colors.keys
('Red', 'Blue', 'Green', 'Yellow', 'Purple')
>>> colors.Green
2
```

(I don't know who came up with this, but it wasn't me.)

Comment: and why would you need it? doesn't list solve it the same way?

Comment: This lets you use enumerated constants in a language that doesn't formally support them.  There's a pretty wide range of use cases for those.

Comment: Built into the standard library as of Python 3.4

Answer (score 1):

I always liked the "unzip" idiom:

```
>>> zipped = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('c', 3)]
>>> zip(*zipped)
[('a', 'b', 'c'), (1, 2, 3)]
>>> 
>>> l,n = zip(*zipped)
>>> l
('a', 'b', 'c')
>>> n
(1, 2, 3)
```