# What's the meaning of '@' in python code?

Tags: python, syntax

Reading some Python (PyQt) code, I came across as follows.

```
@pyqtSignature("QString")
def on_findLineEdit_textEdited(self, text):
    self.__index = 0
    self.updateUi()
```

How does this `@pyqtSignature` work? How Python treat this `@`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [What does `@` mean in Python?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053732/what-does-mean-in-python)

Comment: Look at this article: https://dzone.com/articles/understanding-python

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is the decorator syntax, simply it is equivalent to this form:

```
on_findLineEdit_textEdited = pyqtSignature("Qstring")(on_findLineEdit_textEdited)
```

Really simple.

A typical decorator takes as the first argument the function that has to be decorated, and perform stuff/adds functionalities to it. A typical example would be:

```
def echo_fname(f):
    def newfun():
       print f.__name__
       f()
    return newfun
```

The steps are:

- define a new function that add functionalities to `f`
- return this new function.

Comment: No it isn't equivalent to that. It is equivalent to:
`on_findLineEdit_textEdited = pyqtSignature("QString")(on_findLineEdit_textEdited)`

So in this case `pyqtSignature` is a function that returns a decorator rather than being a decorator itself.

Answer (score 2):

It is a syntax for [function decorators](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator).