# Python lines beginning with '@'?

Tags: python, syntax, functional-programming

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What does `@` mean in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1053732/what-does-mean-in-python)

Here is the code I don't understand:

```
def coroutine(func):
   def start(*args,**kwargs):
      cr = func(*args, **kwargs)
       #cr.next()
       next(cr)
       return cr
   return start

@coroutine #<<<----- HERE
def detectChange(value):
   old_value = value
    while True:
       new_value = (yield)
       if new_value != old_value:
          print ("Ouch!")
          old_value = new_value
```

What does the @coroutine means syntax wise?

Comment: http://www.dabeaz.com/coroutines/ You could look here

Comment: You should also post real code. This code has invalid indentation. Use copy/paste.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a [function decorator](http://docs.python.org/glossary.html#term-decorator).

Answer (score 0):

It's a decorator: http://www.artima.com/weblogs/viewpost.jsp?thread=240808

Answer (score 0):

Decorators wrap functions: http://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonDecorators