# nested list comprehension with os.walk

Tags: python, list-comprehension

Trying to enumerate all files in a certain directory (like 'find .' in Linux, or 'dir /s /b' in Windows).

I came up with the following nested list comprehension:

```
from os import walk
from os.path import join
root = r'c:\windows'      #choose any folder here
allfiles = [join(root,f) for f in files for root,dirs,files in walk(root)]
```

Unfortunately, for the last expression, I'm getting:

`NameError: name 'files' is not defined`

Related to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1198777/341971) question, which (although working) I can't understand the syntax of the nested list comprehension.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You need to reverse the nesting;

```
allfiles = [join(root,f) for root,dirs,files in walk(root) for f in files]
```

See the [list comprehension documentation](http://docs.python.org/reference/expressions.html#list-displays):

> When a list comprehension is supplied, it consists of a single expression followed by at least one `for` clause and zero or more `for` or `if` clauses. In this case, the elements of the new list are those that would be produced by considering each of the `for` or `if` clauses a block, nesting from left to right, and evaluating the expression to produce a list element each time the innermost block is reached.

In other words, since you basically want the moral equivalent of:

```
allfiles = []
for root, dirs, files in walk(root):
    for f in files:
        allfiles.append(f)
```

your list comprehension should follow the same ordering.

Answer (score 5):

it is:

```
allfiles = [join(root, f) for _, dirs, files in walk(root) for f in files]
```

Comment: Actually you want to use the `root` from each iteration of the `walk` or it won't handle child folders properly. So it's more like `allfiles = [join(folder, f) for folder, dirs, files in walk(root) for f in files]`

Answer (score 0):

> A different option, remove .replace() if you want absolute path.*

```
import os

working_dir = os.getcwd()
file_list = [os.path.join(
dirpath, file).replace(
    working_dir, "") for (
        dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(
            working_dir) for file in filenames]
print(file_list)
```

Python 3 Version.