# How to define duplicate items in a Python tuple?

Tags: python, python-3.x, indexing, tuples

What are some good ways to define a tuple consisting of integers where the number of occurrences of each item is known ?

For example,

I want to define a tuple with 3 2's, 2 4's and 1, 3, 5 occur once.

For this, I can always go the manual way :

```
foo = (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

However, this becomes a bit messy when the number of items in the list is large. 
So, I want to know what are some ways to automate the task of generating the desired number of duplicates of each item.

Comment: How will the number of repetitions be determined?

Comment: @vaultah They are known beforehand. I have stated this in the question itself.

Comment: You also implied that the number of items may change.

Answer (score 6):

You can do it like this:

```
>>> (1,) * 1 + (2,) * 3 + (4,) * 2 + (5,) * 1
(1, 2, 2, 2, 4, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use sequence multiplication. Here's a simple version that makes no attempt to avoid creating unnecessary intermediate objects:

```
accumulator = ()
for (val, count) in some_data_structure:
    accumulator += (val,) * count
```

That can be improved, the main point is to demonstrate that `(1,) * 5` gives you `(1, 1, 1, 1, 1)`. Note that this copies the object reference - that's fine for integers, but can cause confusion if you're trying to multiply a sequence of mutable objects.

Answer (score 2):

If you have a tuple of tuples denoting the value and frequency, you can do the following:

```
tuples = ((1,1), (2,3), (3,1), (4,2), (5,1))

tuple(i for i, n in tuples for _ in range(n)) # Use xrange in Python 2.X
# (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Or, if you know that the values are always going to be 1, 2, 3, ..., n, you can use `enumerate` with a tuple of the frequencies.

```
freqs = (1, 3, 1, 2, 1)

tuple(i for i, n in enumerate(freqs, 1) for _ in range(n))
# (1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

If you're curious about the use of the double comprehension in the generator expression, you may want to check out [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198777/double-iteration-in-list-comprehension).

Comment: I wasn't the downvoter, but maybe a little explanation of what's going on would help? This is basically the same idea as in my answer, making one of the improvements I alluded to to avoid creating some of the unnecessary intermediate tuples.

Comment: This is an overkill for such a simple task. The complexity of `sum(..., [])` is quadratic.

Comment: @vaultah Fair enough, it does generalize the problem though. The nested  generators should avoid the extra complexity. I'll remove the `sum` approach.

Answer (score 2):

If your tuple has not many number, you can do it in the simplest way.

```
(1,)+(2,)*3+(3,)+(4,)*2+(5,)
```

Otherwise, just turn it into a function.

```
def myTuple(*val):
    return sum(((i,) * n for i, n in val), ())

myTuple((1,1),(2,3),(3,1),(4,2),(5,1))
>>>(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

you can also call it with:

```
val = ((1,1),(2,3),(3,1),(4,2),(5,1))
myTuple(*val)
>>>(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

Something like this could work:

```
>>> result = tuple()
>>> for item, repeat in ((1, 1), (2, 3), (3, 1), (4, 2), (5, 1)):
...    result = result + (item,) * repeat
>>> result
(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Answer (score 0):

So you want the inverse function of `collections.Counter`. Here is how you could do it,

```
# make a dict of counts (list of tuples is better)
counts = {1: 1, 2: 3, 4: 2, 3:1, 5: 1}
t = tuple(k for k,v in sorted(counts.items()) for _ in range(v))
(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
# for k,v in list_of_tuples, for a list of tuples
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define the following function

```
def a_tuple(*data):
    l = []
    for i, cnt in data: l.extend([i]*cnt)
    return tuple(l)
```

and use it like this

```
print(a_tuple((1,1), (2,3), (3,1), (4,2), (5,1)))
```

to produce the following output

```
(1, 2, 2, 2, 3, 4, 4, 5)
```

Have a look to the [`.extend()` method of list](https://docs.python.org/3.5/tutorial/datastructures.html#more-on-lists) if you don't understand how the function works.