# Hypothesis (Python): Omit argument

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-hypothesis

I have a function like so (it's actually a class, but that's not relevant given Python's duck typing):

```
def myfunc(a=None, b=None):
    <snip>
```

Now I want to write a Hypothesis test which always supplies `a`, but only sometimes `b`.

I tried

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as strat

@given(a=strat.booleans())
@given(b=strat.integers(min_value=1) | strat.nothing())
def test_model_properties(self, **kwargs):
    myval = myfunc(**kwargs)
    <snip>
```

But it seems that when it gets `strat.nothing()` just skips that test run (I get `hypothesis.errors.FailedHealthCheck: It looks like your strategy is filtering out a lot of data.` when using that as the sole strategy for `b`).

How can I only sometimes supply an argument with a Hypothesis test? Do I need to write two tests, one with `b` and one without?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[jacq's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47055352/1441523) put me on the right track - the selection of keywords needs to be its own strategy.

With the standard dictionary

```
std = {'a': strat.booleans()}
```

and the optional dictionary

```
opt = {
    'b': strat.integers(),
    'c': strat.integers(),
}
```

I can then use [chained list comprehension](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1198794/1441523) for all the possible "optional argument combinations":

```
# chain.from_iterable may or may not be faster; it doesn't matter for me.
optional = [combo
            for n in range(len(opt.items()))
            for combo in itertools.combinations(opt.items(), n+1)]
```

That generates the key-value tuples for `b`, `c`, and `(b, c)`.

In order to draw a set of values, we need to get one of those options, which can be done with `sampled_from(optional)`. With the obtained tuples, we must draw from the strategies within, in addition to those in the `std` dictionary.

```
strat.sampled_from(optional).flatmap(
    lambda x: strat.fixed_dictionaries(
        {**std, **dict(x)}
    )
)
```

This can all be wrapped in a function, let's call it `valid_values()`. You can't use `@given(valid_values())` if you specify `*args` or `**kwargs` in the signature of the wrapped function.

As a result, `test_model_properties(self, **kwargs)` becomes `test_model_properties(self, kwargs)` (and you can use `@given(kwargs=valid_values())`) - by calling the dictionary `kwargs`, the rest of the function remains unchanged.

Note: This will not include an empty tuple if you want the possibility of no optional parameters, but that can be appended to the `optional` list easily. Alternatively, have `range(n+1)` instead of `combinations(..., n+1)`, hence including a length of 0.

Answer (score 2):

Your approach is guaranteed to fail, because, as the [hypothesis docs](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/data.html) imply

```
hypothesis.strategies.nothing()[source]

    This strategy never successfully draws a value and will always reject on an attempt to draw.
```

your attempt not to provide a value for `b` will always fail.

How about this:

```
from hypothesis.strategies import tuples, integers, booleans, one_of
B = booleans()
I = integers(min_value=0, max_value=10)
one_of(tuples(B), tuples(B, I)).example()
```

which, over a bunch of trials, gave me outputs such as `(True,)`, `(False, 9)`, `(False, 4)`, `(True, 5)` and `(False,)`.

You would, of course, use this with `*args` rather than `**kwargs`.

Comment: Unfortunately, because I have more than 1 "optional" argument (I simplified it for the question), keyword arguments are necessary. Also, if the function accepts `*args` or `**kwargs`, then you can't supply positional arguments to `@given` [(see `is_invalid_test` in these docs)](http://hypothesis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/_modules/hypothesis/core.html) - you'd need function parameters of `(self, args)` - note no `*`. Thanks for the suggestions though - they did put me on the right track.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you want `none()` instead of `nothing()`:

```
from hypothesis import given, strategies as strat

@given(a=strat.booleans(), b=strat.none() | strat.integers(min_value=1))
def test_model_properties(self, **kwargs):
    myval = myfunc(**kwargs)
    ...
```

This is simpler than generating dictionaries to use as **kwargs and a little more efficient too.  Ordering of the strategies for `b` is also important - putting `none()` first ensures that the minimal example will be `a=False, b=None` instead of `a=False, b=1`.

Also note that applying `@given` multiple times is very inefficient compared to a single use, and actually deprecated since version 3.34.0.

Answer (score -1):

How about:

```
def myfunc(a=None, b=None):
    if b is None:
        b=strat.nothing() 
        # Or whatever you would like b to be when you don't supply an argument
    else:
        <snip>
```

So you let `b` being the default value (in this case, `None`) trigger an 'if' condition inside `myfunc()` that sets it to something else.

Comment: I want to test the default values of `myfunc`, so I actually have that code in place already - I need the test to sometimes call with `b` set, and sometimes not.