# Combinations for three numbers to sum up to 1000

Tags: python, algorithm

I need every combination of three **positive integers** with the sum of 1000.

This was my attempt but I'm unsure if this is correct since I have no way to validate it.

```
def getSum():
    l = []
    for x in range(1, 999):
        total = 1000-x
        for y in range(1, 999):
            total = total-y
            if total>0:
                l.append([x, y, total])
    return l

print len(getSum())
```

I get 28776 different combinations. Is that correct?

Comment: There are infinite ways to sum 3 numbers to 1000.  What are the restrictions on the numbers you can use?

Comment: i think he means two three digit numbers, but his question is not clear

Comment: Think about upper limit of the second loop

Comment: I am sorry. Of course there are restrictions. They must be three integers. I edited the question. I hope it is clear now.

Comment: why only loop twice then?

Comment: 3 unique integers?  and are 1,2,997 and 997,2,1 both counted?

Comment: @NemoMeMeliorEst Because the third number is 1000 minus the first two, no need for another loop

Comment: `1+1+998` and `1+998+1` are different combinations?

Comment: @DAIe Yes they are.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `1+998+1` and `1+1+998` are *not* the same thing, there are some incredible amount of combinations:

This line can generate them all:

```
[(i, 1000-i-k, k) for i in range(1,999) for k in range(1,1000-i)]
```

Results:

```
[...
(1, 4, 995),
(1, 3, 996),
(1, 2, 997),
(1, 1, 998),
(2, 997, 1),
(2, 996, 2),
...]
```

The length of this list is:

```
498501
```

Comment: This works flawlessly. Unfortunately, I've never seen this syntax. Could you might explain this to me or give me a hint for what I should search for? Thanks for your answer!

Comment: This is list comprehension: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python. In this specific case, there are a double loop within this line: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1198777/double-iteration-in-list-comprehension

Comment: Alternatively, using itertools: `[(a, b-a, 1000-b) for a, b in itertools.combinations(range(1000), 2)]`. That generalises more easily if you want partitions with more elements.

Comment: Makes more than sense and is incredible fast. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @Dave range(1, 999) goes up to 998.

Comment: @rici: That approach should also be faster, since it doesn't need to generate 998 custom `range`s, and has all sorts of optimizations built-in to make it hard to beat with any Python level code (especially since you unpack the results; one of the optimizations is to reuse the same `tuple` each time if no references to the `tuple` remain when the next value is requested).

Comment: @RockyLi Thanks! I don't use Python much. This answer is right. The length should be choose(999,2) == 498501 == all ways to put 2 'barriers' in the 1-1000 range excluding endpoints.

Answer (score 2):

No, that number is not correct. The problem with your code is this line:

```
        total = total-y
```

Here, you decrease `total` further and further with each value of `y` that you try, never resetting it to the value after just subtracting `x`. To fix it, create a new variable, e.g. `total2`, and use that in the inner loop.

```
        total2 = total-y
```

This way, you get `498501` combinations.  Also, you can `break` from the inner loop as soon as `total2 < 0`.

---

If you need just the *number* of combinations: Note that there are `N-1` combinations to sum two numbers to `N`, e.g. for `N==4`: `1+3`, `2+2`, `3+1` (assuming you consider `1+3` and `3+1` different). You can extend this to the case of three numbers as partitioning the number in two parts two times. This way, you only need a single loop. And this can be simplified further to an O(1) formula.

Example, with naive approach using `product` as reference:

```
>>> N = 100  # to make reference faster
>>> sum(1 for t in product(range(1, N+1), repeat=3) if sum(t)==N)
4851
>>> sum(N-1-i for i in range(1, N-1))
4851
>>> ((N-2)*(N-1))//2
4851
```

Of course, also works for `N = 1000` (or much, much larger):

```
>>> N = 1000
>>> sum(N-1-i for i in range(1, N-1))
498501
>>> ((N-2)*(N-1))//2
498501
```

Answer (score 0):

If you treated [1,1,998] and [1,998,1] the same (no unique integers):

```
def getSum():
    l = []
    for x in range(1, 999):
        total = 1000-x
        for y in range(1, 999):
            total = total-y
            if total>0:
                z = [x, y, total]
                z.sort()
                if z not in l:
                    l.append(z)
return l

a = getSum()
print(len(a))
```

If you want 3 **unique** integers:

```
def getSum():
    l = []
    for x in range(1, 999):
        total = 1000-x
        for y in range(1, 999):
            total = total-y
            if total>0:
                z = [x, y, total]
                z.sort()
                if (z not in l) and (not((len(set(z)) < len(z)))):
                    l.append(z)
    return l

a = getSum()
print(len(a))
```

Otherwise your code is (in my sense) ok. I haven't check your answer yet...

EDIT : I have checked it using brutal force. The correct answer is actually 498501 if you treated (1,1,998) and (998,1,1) differently. Currently I don't know why...

Comment: Look very carefully at the line `total = total - y`. What does that do the second time through the inner loop?

Comment: @rici: Mind you, it's a problem with the OP's code as well.

Comment: @shadow: yes, it's not a criticism. Rather, a suggestion for the last sentence of this answer.

Comment: @rici oh gosh thank you! I'm not very familiar with catching bugs, especially when I'm lazy and not trying to check the answer. I'm also unfamiliar to reading other people code, especially functions =( Thanks again  ...                                                               **P.S : What is OP? I'm not English-speaker...**

Comment: @hungnguyen "Original Post" (or Original Poster)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
def getSum():
    l = []
    for x in range(1, 6):
        for y in range(1, 6):
            total = 6-(y+x)
            if total>0:
                s = set([x, y, total])
                if s not in l:
                    l.append(s)
                    print(x, y, total)
    return l

print (len(getSum()))
```

This is my algorithm, Although there is better ways. In this case I wrote code for number 6 and printed all combinations to show how it works. You can set 1000 or any number instead of 6 in this code(in 3 position) and ignore print() line.

Comment: You could avoid the `if total > 0:` test completely (and save a lot of looping) by just adjusting the end point of your inner loop such that the condition is never violated.