# python How to query all Booleans in two dimensional list

Tags: python, dictionary, while-loop

So I want to create a while loop that will stop once all the Booleans inside a two dimensional list are true (a dictionary specifically).

This is the dictionary I am trying to query.

```
tasks = {'bathroom':
         {'linus':False, 
         'ola': False, 
         'lex': False, 
         'lotte': False, 
         'yoan': False, 
         'daan': False}, 
    'kitchen':
         {'linus':False, 
         'ola': False, 
         'lex': False, 
         'lotte': False, 
         'yoan': False, 
         'daan': False},
    'garbage':
         {'linus':False, 
         'ola': False, 
         'lex': False, 
         'lotte': False, 
         'yoan': False, 
         'daan': False},
    'recycling':
         {'linus':False, 
         'ola': False, 
         'lex': False, 
         'lotte': False, 
         'yoan': False, 
         'daan': False},
    'corridors':
         {'linus':False, 
         'ola': False, 
         'lex': False, 
         'lotte': False, 
         'yoan': False, 
         'daan': False}}
```

This is what I have tried to come up with but it doesn't seem to work

```
while not all(done == true for done in names.values() for names in tasks.values())
```

Comment: I think your statement should work except that the ordering is wrong. It should be `while not all(done for names in tasks.values() for done in names.values())`.
Check out https://stackoverflow.com/a/36734643/12345551

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What He3lixxx said is correct; the comprehension was in the wrong order.

```
while not all(done for names in tasks.values() for done in names.values())
```

Think of it in terms of normal Python workflow, except that the value is at the top, instead of inside the nested loop

```
while not all(done                             # value
              for names in tasks.values()      # outer loop
                  for done in names.values()   # inner loop
             )
```

But if all values are actually boolean, you can shorten it to

```
while not all(all(task.values()) for task in tasks.values())
```

---

If you were to write out the second approach, it would

```
while not all(all(subtask for subtask in task.values()) for task in tasks.values())
```

Which is similar to the ordering you had, but you have to remember the `all(...)` part is a single value. So you're only doing "value-outer loop", regardless of whether the "value" is another comprehension list itself.

Answer (score 0):

hi there green i paste you're code in my ide and getting some errors, the first problem i found is that your true boolean isn't suposed to be types with a capital T so it's not "true" but "True", and the second problem i see is that you're trying to solve the problem in 1 line with a while loop, while loops usualy need a ":" and can't be used in 1 line, sadly i didn't find a way to mutate your data, but i did find a way to access it, here's the code you can delete the comments later:

```
finished = True
while finished:
    
    '''
    access the first dict that is the task's dict 
    aka kitchen, corridors, bathroom, ect, but it haven't find the names
    '''
    # this comment on top of this comment is for the first for loop
    for task in tasks.values():
        '''
        find the names in every task and prints them, 
        you can change the print statement to a line that mutates the data
        '''
        # this comment is for the second for loop
        for names in task.values():
            print(names)  # prints the data that got access, you can change this later

    print(tasks)  # prints the whole dict
    finished = False
```

hoped i helped you a bit and delete the trouble of getting access to the data ^w^