# How to edit string letters in a for loop

Tags: python

I'm new with python and I really cannot find a way to do this.

I want to change the letters of a string based on some criteria. Here is the code:

```
for c in text:
    ordChar=ord(c)
    if ordChar>=65 and ordChar<=90:
        ordChar=ordChar+13
        if ordChar>90:
            ordChar=ordChar-90+64
        c=chr(ordChar)
    else:
        if ordChar>=97 and ordChar<=122:
            ordChar=ordChar+13
            if ordChar>122:
                ordChar=ordChar-122+96
            c=chr(ordChar)
return text
```

The returned `text` value is the same as the parameter value. I thought variables were pointers, so editing `c`, it should edit `text`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: In Python, Strings are **immutable**. That means that you can not edit a single part of a string as you're attempting to here. You're merely setting `c` to a different value

Comment: Are you trying to implement rot13? Have a look at some nice/clean ways to do it instead: http://stackoverflow.com/q/3269686/298479

Comment: @Josh: Even if they were mutable, the method used here wouldn't work. `a = [1,2,3]; for c in a:\n c = None` won't change `a`. (of course you need

Comment: @TimPietzcker +1, you're right, but even if he fixed that, the deeper issue is the immutability

Comment: As a side note, you can just write `if 65 <= ordChar <= 90:`. But it's a lot more readable, and harder to get wrong, if you write `if 'A' <= c <= 'Z':`. An off-by-one error is obvious when comparing to `'Z'`; it's not obvious against `90` unless everyone who reads your code has the ASCII chart memorized. (You may also want to use `ord('Z')` instead of `90`, etc., within the body of the `if` statement, for similar reasons.)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're not "editing" `c`, you're assigning it to something else. One alternative is to build a new string instead of trying to mutate the old one (which is impossible), then instead of `c=...` you would have `newstr += ...`.

Answer (score 2):

As I explained in my comment, Strings in Python are **immutable**, so you'll need to make a new string, you cannot simply edit the old one. Your code can become:

```
new_text = ""
for c in text:
    ordChar=ord(c)
    if ordChar>=65 and ordChar<=90:
        ordChar=ordChar+13
        if ordChar>90:
            ordChar=ordChar-90+64
        c=chr(ordChar)
    else:
        if ordChar>=97 and ordChar<=122:
            ordChar=ordChar+13
            if ordChar>122:
                ordChar=ordChar-122+96
            c=chr(ordChar)
    new_text += c
return new_text
```

Answer (score 2):

Either build a new string as in arshajii's and Josh's answers, or use `map` or a list comprehension to apply the conversion character-by-character. (Either way, you are making a new string rather than converting the original.)

```
def convert_char(c):
    code = ord(c)
    if 65 <= code <= 90:
        code += 13
        if code > 90:
            code -= 26
    elif 97 <= ord(c) <= 122:
        code += 13
        if code > 122:
            code -= 26
    return chr(code)

 print ''.join(map(convert_char, "Testing"))
```

There are several nicer ways of doing this such as:

```
def convert_char(c):
    if 'a' <= c <= 'z':
        return chr(97 + (ord(c) - 6) % 26)
    elif 'A' <= c <= 'Z':
        return chr(65 + ord(c) % 26)
    return c
```

or

```
from string import lowercase, uppercase
def convert_char(c):
    if c in lowercase:
        return lowercase[(lowercase.index(c) + 13) % 26]
    if c in uppercase:
        return uppercase[(uppercase.index(c) + 13) % 26]
    return c
```

(The link in the comments to an earlier answer has more.)