# how do i use rot 13 on a file in python

Tags: python

im trying to rewrite every character in a file with rot 13 and im stuck, im not sure how to go through the file and look at every character and not worry about the spaces between paragraphs

```
# [import statements]
import q2fun
# [constants]

# [rest of program code]
f = open("rot-13.txt", "w", encoding="utf-8")
result = q2fun.rot13(f)

def rot13(f):

    f.seek(0)
#   y = 0
    result = ""
    for char in f:
        x = ord(char)
        if 97 <= x < 110 or 65 <= x < 78:
#           string[y]=char.replace(char, chr(x+13))
            char = char.replace(char, chr(x + 13))
            result = result + char
            print(char)
            continue
#           y+=1
        elif x >= 110 or 78 <= x < 91:
#           string[y]=char.replace(char, chr(x-13))
            char = char.replace(char, chr(x - 13))
            print(char)
            result = result + char
            continue
#           y+=1
        result = result + char
    return result
```

Comment: Are you trying to learn how to do this manually, or just looking for the easiest way to do it?

Comment: Well, you're already pretty close; your `rot13` algorithm is actually correct, it's just that you're not reading files correctly. So, it's worth learning how to fix it. But it's also worth learning how to use the "batteries included" in Python, and if you need this for a real use rather than just for learning, it's better to use the batteries. So, without knowing which one you want, the question really needs two answers…

Comment: What's the difference between writing it yourself and using something that's already built in? Using something built in means less work for you. It means you get code that's been debugged in various edge cases you didn't think about, and sometimes optimized as well. It means someone reading your code can look up the function you call in the docs instead of having to find and read the implementation. But writing it yourself means you get to learn how it works and what it really does.

Comment: ill like the second option

Answer (score 2):

```
import codecs


with open("plaintext.txt") as f_in, open("rot-13.txt", "w") as f_out:
    f_out.write(codecs.encode(f_in.read(),"rot_13"))

with open("rot-13.txt") as encoded:
    print (codecs.decode(encoded.read(),"rot_13"))
```

See the documentation on the [`codecs`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html) module, or the built-in `help` in the interactive interpreter, for an explanation of these functions. See the documentation on the [Standard Encodings](http://docs.python.org/3/library/codecs.html#standard-encodings) (and following sections), or import the `encodings` module and use the built-in `help`, to see a list of encodings you can use with these functions.

Comment: they got rid of rot13 builtin encoding?

Comment: is there a way to do it on python 3.x

Comment: @JoranBeasley yes! I don't know why, it was a great feature.

Comment: It was eliminated because it doesn't `encode` from `str` to `bytes`, so therefore there's no way to access it from `str.encode` (which is guaranteed to return a `bytes`). You have to use the codec explicitly. There' been some talk of coming up with easier ways to use "transformer" codecs that convert str->str or bytes->bytes or bytes->str (like `hex`), but so far no concrete proposals have come out.

Comment: @user2980776: For Python 3.x compatibility, use `import codecs; codecs.encode(f_in.read(), 'rot_13')` instead.

Comment: can i see it in a example?

Comment: there noow it will work in python 3 :) .. and it will work just as well for rot15 ;P

Comment: @JoranBeasley: No. According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269686/short-rot13-function, string.maketrans was removed in Python 3.2. It only works if directly applied to a string object.

Comment: I see ... ok :P I will fix with your suggestion :)

Comment: i keep getting an erro when i try to do it that says   FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'plaintext.txt'

Comment: @user2980776: Obviously you have to have a file named `plaintext.txt` in your current working directory if you want to encode a file named `plaintext.txt`. If you want to use a different file, use a different filename.

Comment: It would be better to show this using a `with` statement. Besides being a good habit to instill in novices, it also turns this from four lines of file management plus one line of actual work into one line of file management plus one line of actual work, making it clearer what's important here.

Comment: I agree , however I dont use python 3 and always screw up the `with x as y, z as a` syntax( is that right?)

Comment: i got it do run but the rot-13.txt file is not changing

Comment: @JoranBeasley: Yes, it's right. And it's also right in Python 2, so I don't know why you don't understand it.

Comment: @user2980776 its still not working tells me nothing ... it should work fine assuming plaintext.txt is in the same directory as the script ... or is it a different error? ... it also needs to have plaintext in the file

Comment: @abarnert Im pretty sure its not in 2.6

Comment: @JoranBeasley: No, it was added in 2.7. But so what? Not teaching people 3.x features because a lot of people are still using 2.7, and will be for a few more years, is one thing; not teaching people 2.7 features is another…

Comment: when i run the function nothing happens to the rot-13.txt fie, its stil using the regular alphabet

Comment: no I agree I just didnt wnat to get that syntax wrong ... im editing it now that you told me that was right :P

Comment: @user2980776 put `hello world` into the "plaintext.txt" file, after you run this it will be encoded and written into rot-13.txt ...

Comment: i try to do it but it just deletes all i have in there

Comment: what? ... it will overwrite whatever is in rot-13.txt with the encoded text from plaintext.txt

Answer (score 2):

If you just want to do this as easily as possible, use the `rot_13` codec, as described in Joran Beasley's answer.

If you want to know how to do it manually, or what was wrong with your existing code, I can explain. You're actually very close.

If `f` is a file, `for char in f:` iterates over the *lines* of the file, not the *characters*. If you want to iterate over the characters one by one, either loop around `f.read(1)`, or read the whole thing into a string with `s = f.read()` and then iterate over `s`.

If you fix that, your program now works as written. However, it's more complicated than necessary.

First, `char = char.replace(char, chr(x + 13))` is unnecessary. `str.replace` searches the string, substitutes the replacement character for all instances of the search character, and returns the resulting string. But you don't need any of that—you're searching all one character, replacing the one instance of the search character with the resulting character, and returning the resulting character as a one-character string—in other words, the same string you already had. All you want to do here is `char = chr(x + 13)`.

Also, you can remove the three separate `result = result + char` and `continue`; all three conditions lead to the same thing.

Also, instead of comparing `x` to ordinal values (which are hard to read, and easy to get wrong), you can just compare `char` to character values. So:

```
def rot13(f):
    s = f.read()
    result = ""
    for char in s:
        x = ord(char)
        if 'a' <= char <= 'm' or 'A' <= char <= 'M':
            char = chr(x + 13)
        elif 'n' <= char <= 'z' or 'N' <= char <= 'Z':
            char = chr(x - 13)
        result = result + char
    return result
```

You can simplify your comparisons further by using `str.lower`:

```
        if 'a' <= char.lower() <= 'm':
```

(This replaces the `if 'a'…` line in the above code, and you do the same thing for the `elif 'n'…` line.)

You can simplify things even further by using the collections in the `string` class:

```
        if char in string.ascii_letters:
            if char.lower() <= 'm':
                char = chr(x + 13)
            else:
                char = chr(x - 13)
```

(This replaces the whole `if`/`elif` block.)

Or, if you know that the `%` (mod/remainder) operator does, you can simplify it even further: `rot13(ch)` is just `(ch+13) % 26` (where `ch` is a letter number from `0` to `25`, which you can get with `ord(char) % 32`). The usual C implementations take advantage of this, and you can write them more clearly with the `divmod` function in Python. But I'll leave that as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: meh you have more patience than me :) great answer

Comment: so isthe third one like the first one or do you need both

Comment: @user2980776: The simplifications don't replace the entire function; they just replace part of the code. I've added comments in parentheses to explain exactly what parts you replace.

Comment: i did it and it says that s=f.read() is io.UnsupportedOperation: not readable

Comment: @user2980776: Well, what `f` are you passing it? It has to be an open, readable file object. In your original code, you're passing it a file opened in write-only mode (`'w'`), which will raise this exception. You may need to go over [Reading and Writing Files](http://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#reading-and-writing-files) in the tutorial to get the basics.

Answer (score 0):

An old-school implementation with python3

```py
def ROT_13(realText):
    outText = ""
    cryptText = []
    step = 13
    uppercase = ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'E', 'F', 'G', 'H', 'I', 'J', 'K', 'L', 'M', 'N', 'O', 'P', 'Q', 'R', 'S', 'T', 'U', 'V', 'W', 'X', 'Y', 'Z']
    lowercase = ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f', 'g', 'h', 'i', 'j', 'k', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o', 'p', 'q', 'r', 's', 't', 'u', 'v', 'w', 'x', 'y', 'z']
    puncuation = [",","'",":","!","~","`","@","#","$","%","^","&","*","(",")","-","_","+","=","<",">","/","?",";","\\","|","{","}","[","]"]

    for eachLetter in realText:
        if eachLetter in uppercase:
            index = uppercase.index(eachLetter)
            crypting = (index + step) % 26
            #print("{}  index={} Crypt={}".format(eachLetter,index,crypting))
            cryptText.append(crypting)
            newLetter = uppercase[crypting]
            outText += (newLetter)
        elif eachLetter in lowercase:
            index = lowercase.index(eachLetter)
            crypting = (index + step) % 26
            #print("{}  index={} Crypt={}".format(eachLetter,index,crypting))
            cryptText.append(crypting)
            newLetter = lowercase[crypting]
            outText += (newLetter)
        elif eachLetter in puncuation:
          outText += eachLetter 
        else:
          outText += " "
    return outText
```

You may call it like this

```py
code = ROT_13("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz")
print(code)
```

to get the result

```
NOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMnopqrstuvwxyzabcdefghijklm
```

it even handles spaces, special characters as , # and CAPS

```py
code2 = ROT_13("it even handles spaces, special characters as , # and CAPS")
```

to get

```py
"vg rira unaqyrf fcnprf, fcrpvny punenpgref nf , # naq PNCF"
```