# Caesar Cipher-Python

Tags: python

I recently did an assignment and my professor stated how it's not 100% correct but i'm not sure how else to fix this. His reply to my hw was "Try a key of 29 or 55.  Instead of using ord, use the index of the letter in the ALPHABET string." Now I am very new to programming so any piece of advice would help. Need Help figuring out what to do.

Code:

```
def circularShift(text, key):
    ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    text = text.upper()
    shiftedTextSoFar =" "
    for letter in text:
        shifted = ord(letter) + key
        if (shifted < 65):
            shifted += 26
        if (shifted > 90):
            shifted -= 26
        shiftedTextSoFar +=chr(shifted)
    return shiftedTextSoFar
print (circularShift("MOLLOY", 3)) #SHOULD PRINT PROORB
print (circularShift("PROOB", - 3)) # SHOULD PRINT MOLLOY
```

Comment: Here's a [short ROT-13 implementation](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3270252/2629998) in Python 3 (also look at the other answers with not-so-short implementations that'll help you troubleshoot your own code)

Comment: A shift of 29 or 55 positions is kinda useless, but if this input is legitimate, then you need to use the modulo: `key = key % 26`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an improved version of your code, which using `index` as suggested:

```
def circularShift(text, key):
    ALPHABET = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ"
    shiftedTextSoFar =" "
    # you can also change text to upper during for/loop
    for letter in text.upper():
        # should do a try/except here really in case user input invalid text
        # using string index to return index value
        # using (key % len(ALPHABET)) will reduce key length of any 26's multiples
        shifted = ALPHABET.index(letter) + (key % len(ALPHABET))

        # if after adjusting shifted is out of index, reduce by 26 i.e len(ALPHABET)
        if shifted > len(ALPHABET):
            shifted -= len(ALPHABET)
        # Python already has -ve index taken care, ie. ALPHABET[-1] = 'Z'
        shiftedTextSoFar += ALPHABET[shifted]
    return shiftedTextSoFar

print (circularShift("MOLLOY", 29)) #SHOULD PRINT PROORB
print (circularShift("PROOB", 55)) # SHOULD PRINT MOLLOY
 PROORB
 SURRE
```

Comment: @NicoleArnone, then you can remove the `try/except` block, I will update the answer.

Comment: sorry to be an annoyance, but it doesn't seem to be working, I'm trying to figure out what the problem is but once I run the program, It's empty.

Comment: @NicoleArnone, right I have accidentally removed the `shiftedTextSoFar += ALPHABET[shifted]` line when I removed the `try/except`. Now updated

Comment: odd behavior with text = z, key = 1, results in IndexError: string index out of range.  z with key = 2 results in 'b', z with key = 0 results in 'z'.  New to python so I'm not sure whats going on with that.  (edit) I think the error is in '''if shifted > len(ALPHABET)''' should be >=  ?