# New line issue in rot-13

Tags: python

I'm trying to implement [Rot-13](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) function, but stuck with, I assume, new lines.

Here's my code:

```
import cgi, string
def convert():
    lower = string.ascii_lowercase
    upper = string.ascii_uppercase
    punctuation = string.punctuation + ' '      
    with open('data.txt', 'r') as myfile:
        s = myfile.read()
    s = '%(pre_b)s%(s)s%(pre_e)s' % {'pre_b': '<pre>', 's': s, 'pre_e': '</pre>'}
    s = ''.join(map(lambda x: shift(x, lower, upper, punctuation), s[5:-6]))
    return cgi.escape(s, quote= True)

def shift(x, lower, upper, punctuation):
    if x in punctuation:
        return x
    elif x.istitle():
        return upper[(upper.index(x) + 13) % 26]
    try:
        return lower[(lower.index(x) + 13) % 26]
    except:
        print x
print convert()
```

One-line sentences are being processed OK, but when input contains new line, python says `TypeError: expected string, NoneType found`

Contents of the data.txt file is following:

```
test

test test
```

Please help.

Comment: The error is more than that, it will usually give you a line as well to help narrow it down.

Comment: Also, give examples of what fails. Because I managed to run your code without error, but I also managed to get an exception that is different than what you are stating in your question with another input.

Comment: On further inspection, your code is a hot mess.

Comment: Lego Stormtroopr: your comments regarding ugliness of my code (but not containing any clues) are highly valuable

Comment: I'm sure it could be made more constructive, but when asking for help, it would be useful to remove the warts which are not central to your problem. Straightening out what this code is supposed to do is a challenge, which reduces the chance that anybody will actually be able to help you.  For some vague hints, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for a start.

Comment: Here is a cute implementation: https://gist.github.com/gpiancastelli/806851

Comment: Unless this is homework or something, then this is related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3269686/short-rot13-function

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your error is related to newlines, but not restricted only to them. Basically, for any character in `punctuation`, `lower` and `upper`, your `shift()` function returns something back. For everything else, it ends up here

```
except:
    print x
```

where the function returns nothing, i.e., the value `None`. And when you try to join a list where some elements aren't strings, you get the error you got.

```
>>> ''.join(['a', 'b', None])

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#19>", line 1, in <module>
    ''.join(['a', 'b', None])
TypeError: sequence item 2: expected string, NoneType found
```

In summary, you need to return something even for characters not in your `punctuation`, `lower` and `upper` sets. Pseudocode for returning `x`:

```
if x in lower
    return something
elif x in upper
    return something else
else
    return x
```

And pseudocode for returning `''`.

```
if x in lower
    return something
elif x in upper
    return something else
elif x in punctuation
    return x
else
    return ''
```

Comment: Thanks, you totally answered my question. Me so silly %)