# Creating an encryption in MySQL

Tags: mysql, replace

I am trying to create a an encryption in MySQL.
Lets say there is a string of characters.

"I can run for as many".

I want to replace each letter with its fourth letter.
For example,

```
'a' replaced with 'e'
'b' replaced with 'f'
and so on.
```

The Final output of the above would look something like this.
"M gen vyr jsr ew qerc"

The best I could come up is the below.
Since it is a nested function, it is not giving me the right result.
The below function replaces 'a' with 'e' and then again replaces 'e' with 'i'
until it reaches the end.

```
select messagetext, 
replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace
(replace(replace(replace(replace(messagetext,'a','e'),
'b','f'),'c','g'),'d','h'),'e','i'),'f','j'),'g','k'),
'h','l'),'i','m'),'j','n'),'k','o'),'l','p'),'m','q'),
'n','r'),'o','s'),'p','t'),'q','u'),'r','v'),'s','w'),
't','x'),'u','y'),'v','z'),'w','a'),'x','b'),'y','c'),
'z','d')
from chat;
```

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: This would not be a very good encryption, it's a simple caesar's cipher which can be broken immediately.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Caesar_cipher

Comment: I agree, I need it to complete a project work. I am not able to figure out how to do in Mysql

Comment: Related: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41727434/rot13-function-on-mysql

Answer (score 1):

Reached partial solution, now stuck.

Putting it here so that others can work on this.

**Query**:

```
SELECT UNHEX(HEX(val) + REPEAT('04', LENGTH(val))) AS rot4 FROM caeser;

+--------+
| rot4   |
+--------+
| efghip |
| aq??   | <-- Need to rotate / mod hex value for this. (Stuck here)
+--------+
```

Table create queries:

```
CREATE TABLE caeser (val VARCHAR(255));
INSERT INTO caeser ('abcdef');
INSERT INTO caeser VALUES ('uvwxyz');
```

**PS**: will convert to community wiki, if others also contribute.

Comment: Use `REPLACE` to replace values beyond 'z'.