# Using an import and a for loop when passing a program as a string to Python

Tags: python

A colleague recently sent me a bash script that included some inline Python. The command he used was of the form:

```
$ echo -e 'from foo import bar\nfor i in range(10):\n   bar(i+1).thing = "something"\n\n' | python
```

The command worked just fine, but I asked why he didn't use `python -c`. On further investigation, we were unable to translate this to a form that `python -c` would accept as it appears that Python disallows statements prior to a for loop even when delimited by a semicolon.

The first example below shows that you can import, and print out the imported object. The second example shows that you can use a for loop and print from the for loop. The third example combines the first two, and results in a `SyntaxError`. And finally, the forth example shows the `SyntaxError` results when using an expression prior to the for loop:

```
$ python -c "from sys import argv; print argv"
['-c']
$ python -c "for v in [1,2,3,4]: print v"
1
2
3
4
$ python -c "from sys import argv; for v in argv: print v"
  File "<string>", line 1
    from sys import argv; for v in argv: print v
                            ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
$ python -c "x = 5; for i in [1,2,3]: print i"
  File "<string>", line 1
    x = 5; for i in [1,2,3]: print i
         ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

In hindsight, the `SyntaxError` is not that surprising given that the code is not valid when saved in a script, and that the grammar for statements combined with whitespace restrictions can impose this type of limitation. That being said, is there a way to allow a statement prior to a compound statement through `python -c`?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

To clarify CDspace's answer, note that in Bash, unlike Python, newlines do not terminate string literals. So you can do the following:

```
$python -c 'import sys
for i in range(10):
  print(i)

'
```

Comment: Excellent! Thank you :) Will accept the answer once the time limit goes away

Comment: Neat, I didn't know this! You still have to escape all the single quotes in your Python though.

Comment: Or use double quotes. Just be aware of the difference between single and double quotes in bash.

Answer (score 4):

Another option:

```
python -c "exec(\"x = 5\nfor i in [1,2,3]:\n\tprint(i)\")"
```

## Edit:

Tested and Works for both windows CMD, and Bash.

Comment: @Bob, on the fence as to if that's a +1... if Microsoft would actually adopt (and stick to) standards then life would be much easier cross platform

Comment: @daniel Im not sure if this is a standard.

Comment: Windows treatment of \n is non-standard

Answer (score 3):

From the [docs](https://docs.python.org/2.7/using/cmdline.html#interface-options) (emphasis added), try it with newlines instead of semi-colons.

> When called with -c command, it executes the Python statement(s) given
>   as command. Here command may contain multiple statements **separated by
>   newlines**. Leading whitespace is significant in Python statements!

Comment: Ah, classic RTFM :) I just tried it without success: `$ python -c "from sys import argv\nfor v in argv: print v"`.

Comment: @asmeurer got it, didn't realize the nastiness of bash

Comment: Yeah, posted this before trying it, not working on Windows CMD

Comment: Windows command prompts make me feel dirty every time I use one

Comment: Looks like windows can't do it, see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3637020/long-programs-using-python-c-switch#comment3825042_3637207

Comment: I wouldn't call it nastiness. I often wish Python worked like this. I don't see the point in distinguishing `"` and `"""`.

Answer (score 3):

You already have an answer regarding `-c` but for your use case, a *here document* has the advantage of not having string quoting issues as does a `-c` parameter wrapped in `''` or `""`, because you can use any unique delimiter that you want that will not appear in your script anywhere.

```bash
python <<'PYSCRIPT'
for i in range(10):
    print(i)
PYSCRIPT
```

(Single quotes around the initial delimiter if you *don't* want expansion of shell variables, no quotes if you *do*.)