# python date interval intersection

Tags: python, datetime, intersection

As a matter of general interest I'm wondering if there's a more elegant/efficient way to do this. I have a function that compares two start/end tuples of dates returning true if they intersect.

```
from datetime import date
def date_intersection(t1, t2):
    t1start, t1end = t1[0], t1[1]
    t2start, t2end = t2[0], t2[1]

    if t1end < t2start: return False
    if t1end == t2start: return True
    if t1start == t2start: return True
    if t1start < t2start and t2start < t1end: return True
    if t1start > t2start and t1end < t2end: return True
    if t1start < t2start and t1end > t2end: return True
    if t1start < t2end and t1end > t2end: return True
    if t1start > t2start and t1start < t2end: return True
    if t1start == t2end: return True
    if t1end == t2end: return True 
    if t1start > t2end: return False
```

so if:

```
d1 = date(2000, 1, 10)
d2 = date(2000, 1, 11)
d3 = date(2000, 1, 12)
d4 = date(2000, 1, 13)
```

then:

```
>>> date_intersection((d1,d2),(d3,d4))
False
>>> date_intersection((d1,d2),(d2,d3))
True
>>> date_intersection((d1,d3),(d2,d4))
True
```

etc.

I'm curious to know if there's a more pythonic/elegant/more efficient/less verbose/generally better, way to do this with maybe mxDateTime or some clever hack with timedelta or set()?

An alternative and useful form would be for the function to return a start/end tuple of the intersection if one is found

Thanks

Comment: You should use timedeltas for representing the durations of `t1 ⇔ t2` and I'm thinking on the next bit. http://docs.python.org/library/datetime.html#datetime.timedelta

Answer (score 30, accepted):

It's not really more Pythonic, but you can simply the logic to decide on an intersection somewhat. This particular problems crops up a lot:

```
return (t1start <= t2start <= t1end) or (t2start <= t1start <= t2end)
```

To see why this works think about the different possible ways that the two intervals can intersect and see that the starting point of one must always be within the range of the other.

Comment: yes! very nice. It still makes me go a little cross-eyed, but you've collapsed my exhaustive case analysis into a very clean expression. Thanks a lot, this helps clarify my thinking.

Comment: According to my unit test, it does not work if the end of `t1` is the start of `t2`.

Comment: When t2start <= t1end? I think you should check your unit test again.

Answer (score 20):

An alternative and hopefully more intelligible solution:

```
def has_overlap(a_start, a_end, b_start, b_end):
    latest_start = max(a_start, b_start)
    earliest_end = min(a_end, b_end)
    return latest_start <= earliest_end
```

We can get the interval of the overlap easily, it is `(latest_start, earliest_end)`. Note that latest_start can be equal to earliest_end.

It should be noted that this assumes that `a_start <= a_end` and `b_start <= b_end`.

Comment: This one is the most readable. Also, you can easily return (earliest_end-latest_start) to get a measurement of the total amount of overlap.

Comment: That's the best answer!

Answer (score 7):

Here's a version that give you the range of intersection.  IMHO, it might not be the most optimize # of conditions, but it clearly shows when t2 overlaps with t1.  You can modify based on other answers if you just want the true/false.

```
if (t1start <= t2start <= t2end <= t1end):
    return t2start,t2end
elif (t1start <= t2start <= t1end):
    return t2start,t1end
elif (t1start <= t2end <= t1end):
    return t1start,t2end
elif (t2start <= t1start <= t1end <= t2end):
    return t1start,t1end
else:
    return None
```

Comment: FYI... chaining comparison operators:  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/101945#101945

Comment: Thanks much for the link to chaining operators, that's very helpful.

Comment: This can be prettified using min on the end dates. e.g. if start1 <= start2 <= end1: return (start2, min(end1, end2))

Answer (score 4):

```
intersection_length = min(t1end, t2end) - max(t1start, t2start)
return intersection_length >= 0
```

This will accept an intersection consisting of a single point; otherwise use `> 0`.

The intuition is that an intersected interval, if it exists, starts at the highest start and ends at the lowest end. There are two possibilities:

1. It is a correct interval, possibly of length zero.
2. The start and end points end up being switched. This means there is a gap between the two intervals, which you might call a "negative intersection".

Answer (score 3):

```
Final Comparison: start <= other_finish and other_start <= finish

# All of the conditions below result in overlap I have left out the non overlaps

start <= other_start | start <= other_finish | other_start <= finish | finish <= other_finish 

      0                        1                        1                        0                   
      0                        1                        1                        1
      1                        1                        1                        0          
      1                        1                        1                        1
```

Only the **start <= other_finish** and **other_start <= finish** need to be true to return an overlap.

Comment: A good answer would include some explanation as to why this would solve anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
if t1end < t2start or t1start > t2end: return False
if t1start <= t2end or t2start <= t1start: return True
return False
```

Won't that cover all intersecting sets?

Comment: Well, your code simplifies to return t1end >= t2start and t1start <= t2end

Answer (score 0):

Very late answer, but it seems to me that the simplest and least head-scratching solution is:

```
def date_intersection(t1, t2):
    t1, t2 = sorted([t1, t2], key=lambda t: t[0])
    t1end = t1[1]
    t2start = t2[0]
    return t1 end <= t2start
```

I would probably also be looking at expressing the idea of a "time interval" as a class, so I could do something more like:

```
def date_intersection(interval1, interval2):
    i1, i2 = sorted([interval1, interval2], key=lambda i: i.start)
    return i1.end <= i2.start
```