# Python ternary operator

Tags: python

How can I do something like `var foo = (test) ? "True" : "False";` in Python (specifically 2.7)?

Answer (score 94, accepted):

[PEP 308](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0308/) adds a ternary operator:

```
foo = "True" if test else "False"
```

It's been implemented since Python 2.5

Comment: Wow. You beat me by 12 seconds and have character for character the same answer I did.

Comment: Thanks, I will accept this answer as soon as SO allows it :)

Answer (score -1):

This one looks a bit more like original ternary:

```
foo=a and b or c
```

Comment: `f = a or b or c` works the same as in javascript (it returns the first truthy value).

Comment: -1 Beware, there is a case where this does not work: if the condition `a` is True and `b` is any false value, such as False, 0, None, [], {} and so on, then the result is `c`, which is wrong (it should be `b`). For example, (True and [] or [1,2,3]) is equal to [1,2,3], while ([] if True else [1, 2, 3]) is equal to [], as it should be.  I recommend sticking to the official ternary operator.