# Python IndexError when trying to go through a large list

Tags: python

I have a list of approximately 200 000+ objects, each one representing a file (but not actually holding the file's contents, just the full path name and date).

The program I am writing copies any subset of these files, depending on the user-provided date range. I first create a list of all of the files in the source directory (with the `glob` module), create an instance of my file-representation class and add that instance to a list, like so:

```
for f in glob.glob(srcdir + "/*.txt"):
    LOG_FILES.append(LogFile(f))
```

Now, to keep the copying of files quick and the block of code clean, I remove the LogFile objects that do not fit inside of the date range.

```
for i in xrange(0, len(LOG_FILES)):
    if LOG_FILES[i].DATE < from_date or LOG_FILES[i].DATE > to_date:
        del(LOG_FILES[i])
```

Afterwards, I can just copy the files that are left in the list:

```
for logfile in LOG_FILES:
    os.copy(logfile.PATH, destdir)
```

The issue occurs with the `for i in xrange...` example: I get thrown an IndexError when the value of `i` gets to 63792.

```
IndexError: list index out of range.
```

Any ideas?

**EDIT** Thank you very much for the quick responses! Now that I think about it, it was a silly oversight on my part. Again, thank you, everyone. :)

Comment: you are modifying the sequence you are iterating over.

Comment: Date ranges are easily queryable in SQL.  If the application is meant for distribution to users perhaps a database would be best.  Just an idea.

Comment: Thanks krs, but it's not meant for distribution - it just grabs sets of log files from an ancient, archaic system we are running (which I will eventually be re-writing) that creates logs on particular events.

Comment: I posted two rectifications concerning your problem

Comment: @eyquem: Thanks for that - I modified Cpfohl's example when I implemented it; I didn't use it directly. I would post what I did, but I do not have the code handy to post what worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**[EDIT]** Oops, I forgot to invert the "<" and ">" and add an 'equals' sign.

```
LOG_FILES = [LogFile(f) for f in glob.glob(srcdir + "/*.txt")
                        if from_date <= f.DATE <= to_date]
```

This can replace the whole initalization of LOG_FILES.  It's a list comprehension (if you wish you can make it a generator (which doesn't get evaluated until it's enumerated) by replacing the [ ] with ( ).  That might be more efficient depending on what you do with it.

You need to do this because editing a collection while enumerating it isn't allowed. (see above, [far more eloquent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4752866/python-indexerror-when-trying-to-go-through-a-large-list/4752910#4752910) answers).

You can read the expression above like this:

"create a list (or enumerable) of the result of LogFile, when it's handed 'f' for each f in 'glob.glob(...)' but only if the 'if' statement is true."

See: [The List Comprehension](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html) section of that link.

Comment: [one comparison too many](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/101945#101945)

Comment: Thanks for pointing that out.  I always lose that piece when I transition out of C++ or C# into Python... :)

Comment: you could also use `glob.iglob` to avoid creating unnecessary list.

Answer (score 7):

From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/controlflow.html):

> It is not safe to modify the sequence being iterated over in the loop (this can only happen for mutable sequence types, such as lists). If you need to modify the list you are iterating over (for example, to duplicate selected items) you must iterate over a copy.

For your case, I'd actually suggest looking into using generator expressions and [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter), to avoid making unnecessary copies of your big list of files.

Comment: The quoted comment from the docs here is correct, but I think a better explanation would include *why* it's not safe

Comment: You're right, and your answer is a good explanation, +1.  Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

The problem with your method is that [`del()`](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#the-del-statement) is removing the entry in the list at that index *and re-ordering the list*.

For example, if you have five items in a list and call del() on the third index, the contents of the list are shifted down so that a different element takes the third index.

```
list = [1,2,3,4,5]
del(list[2])
print list     # outputs [1, 2, 4, 5]
print list[2]  # outputs 4
```

Since you are looping from 0 to the original size of the list, even if you have removed just one item from the list, you will eventually arrive at indices which are no longer contained in the list.

A much simpler approach would be to filter the list as you add items to it.

```
for f in glob.glob(srcdir + "/*.txt"):
    lf = LogFile(f)
    if lf.DATE < from_date and lf.DATE > to_date:
        LOG_FILES.append(lf)
```

This could probably be made more pythonic but should be readable enough to get the point across.

Answer (score 1):

If you're looping over an array with a fixed upper limit and deleting elements at the same time you **will** generate index errors. Either you must loop over a copy or use a dynamic index. Since you stated the array is big we use the latter:

```
limit, i = len(LOG_FILES), 0
while i < limit:
    if LOG_FILES[i].DATE < from_date and LOG_FILES[i].DATE > to_date:
        del(LOG_FILES[i])
        limit -= 1
    else:
        i += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

You could also use [`filter`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter):

```
LOG_FILES = filter(lambda log_file: log_file.DATE < from_date and \
                                    log_file.DATE > to_date, LOG_FILES)
```

Answer (score 1):

There's a problem in the Cpfohl's answer:

```
LOG_FILES = [LogFile(f) for f in glob.glob(srcdir + "/*.txt")
             if f.DATE >= from_date and f.DATE <= to_date]
```

Since

```
for f in glob.glob(srcdir + "/*.txt"):
    LOG_FILES.append(LogFile(f))
```

therefore a LOG_FILES[i] is a LogFile(f)
and then a LOG_FILES[i].DATE is a LogFile(f).DATE, not a f.DATE

Answer (score 0):

1) deleting elements during the **iteration in a list from end to beginning of the list** dissolve problems

```
LOG_FILES = [ 1,2,30,2,5,8,30,3,2,37,22,30,27,30,4 ]

print LOG_FILES

L = len(LOG_FILES)-1
for i,x in enumerate(LOG_FILES[::-1]):
    print i,L-i,' ',LOG_FILES[L-i],x
    if x>15:
        del LOG_FILES[L-i]

print LOG_FILES
```

result

```
[1, 2, 30, 2, 5, 8, 30, 3, 2, 37, 22, 30, 27, 30, 4]
0 14   4 4
1 13   30 30
2 12   27 27
3 11   30 30
4 10   22 22
5 9   37 37
6 8   2 2
7 7   3 3
8 6   30 30
9 5   8 8
10 4   5 5
11 3   2 2
12 2   30 30
13 1   2 2
14 0   1 1
[1, 2, 2, 5, 8, 3, 2, 4]
```

2) By the way

```
if LOG_FILES[i].DATE < to_date and LOG_FILES[i].DATE > from_date :
```

can be written

```
if from_date  < LOG_FILES[i].DATE < to_date:
```