# Laying out MVC classes in Python

Tags: python, model-view-controller

I'm working on a project in Python, and I'm trying to follow a somewhat-strict MVC pattern for practice. My idea was to separate things out into packages named `model`, `view` and `controller`, plus have a `Model`, `View` and `Controller` class for each. Each package would have the supporting files for each piece.

My problem is that I want to be able to use them like:

```
from controller import Controller
```

And then in the file with the Controller class I can:

```
from controller.someclass import SomeClass
```

But if I put them in packages with the same name, I get problems. I read up about how modules work, and realized I needed to name them `controller/__init__.py`, `model/__init__.py` and `view/__init__.py`, but it seems weird to put them in that file, and it's kind of annoying that all of them show up gedit as `__init__.py`

Is there any better way of doing this? Am I going about this the right way?

Comment: I think you're missing the point of python modules. Do you need to have classes? Why can't you have your logic in your controller package so you can just do `import controller` and then `controller.whatever()`

Comment: The problem would be the same if I was doing it that way. I'd still be putting a bunch of logic in files named `__init__.py`.

Comment: Yes, that's how python works.

Comment: See this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/4675525#4675525

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've seen some black magic in the django source that pulls classes from a `base.py` file into the `__init__.py` namespace. However I'm not sure how that's done. ( See comments for how to do this. )

From what I do know, you can do one of two things.

A - 
inside `bar/controller/__init__.py`

```
import os,sys
# Make sure the interpreter knows were your files are.
sys.path.append(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),'../')
from bar.controller import Controller
from bar.model import Model
from bar.view import View
class Controller(object):
 model = Model()
 view = View()
```

And now you make `bar/model/__init__.py` and `bar/view/__init__.py`

B -
inside `bar/controller/__init__.py`

```
class Model(object):
 pass
class View(object):
 pass
class Controller(object):
 model = Model()
 view = View()
```

Edit:...
After reading your comment, a third option comes to mind. A package doesn't litertly translate into a module in python. I think your desired result is to create a directory structure like this:

```
bar/
  __init__.py
  controller.py
  model.py
  view.py
```

Then inside `controller.py`

```
import os,sys
from bar.controller import Controller
from bar.model import Model
from bar.view import View
class Controller(object):
 model = Model()
 view = View()
```

This was a huge hurdle for me to get coming from java. Your class file names do not have to match the class name. Think of them as a step, you step into the folder(module) and then into the file(.py) and then you import your class.(Model(object))

Comment: The "black magic" is just something akin to `from base import *` in the `__init__.py` file.  +1 for the sane explanation.

Comment: Be careful about cyclical imports here

Comment: I realize I can put as much as I want in one file, I'm trying to separate it so it's easy to work with.

Answer (score 2):

If I understand correctly, all you're interested in doing here is having this happen:

```
from controller import Controller
```

without having the `Controller` class defined in `controller/__init__.py` is that right?

If so, then just do this:

In `controller/base.py`:  (notice there is a file called `base.py` or something else)

```
class Controller(BaseClass):
  # define Controller here
```

In `controller/__init__.py`:

```
from base import Controller
```

Now you can have the exact syntax you are looking for.