# Is it possible to convert a list-type into a generator without iterating through?

Tags: python, list, generator

I know that it's possible to convert generators into lists at a "low-level" (eg. `list(i for i in xrange(10))`), but is it possible to do the reverse *without* iterating through the list first (eg. `(i for i in range(10))`)?

**Edit:** removed the word `cast` for clarity in what I'm trying to achieve.

**Edit 2:** Actually, I think I may have misunderstood generators at a fundamental level. That'll teach me to not post SO questions before my morning coffee!

Comment: You shouldn't employ the word **cast** in Python since there is no variable in Python, but objects whose type can't change

Comment: @eyquem - AMEN! You shouldn't even *think* the word cast in Python - these are really instance constructors, creating a new object from the given argument, not reinterpreting the memory at some address as a different type.

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether you meant "into a generator" literally by its actual meaning, or else exactly what underlying problem you hoped to solve. If it was meant literally, then yes, the exact `(i for i in range(10))` syntax you propose does exactly that, and this could have been verified by **trying it**. Of course no iteration is required simply to *create* a generator, whether from a generator function or a generator expression; iteration is the process of yielding elements from the generator.

Answer (score 56):

Try this: `an_iterator = iter(a_list)` ... [docs here](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#iter). Is that what you want?

Comment: The questioner is asking about converting a list into a generator.  `iter()` returns an iterator which is not a generator.

Answer (score 15):

You can take a list out of an iterator by using the built-in function `list(...)` and an iterator out of a list by using `iter(...)`:

```
mylist = list(myiterator)
myiterator = iter(mylist)
```

Indeed, your syntax **is** an iterator:

```
iter_10 = (i for i in range(10))
```

instead of using `[...]` which gives a list.

Have a look at this answer [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)

Comment: I'm looking for a lower-level solution, that doesn't require iterating through the original list (eg, `range(10)` in my example).

Comment: So, you can use `iter(mylist)`, that takes an iterator out of your list.

Comment: You say "Indeed, your syntax is an iterator" but isn't it actually a generator. `myiterator` and `iter_10` are different types.

Answer (score 9):

Indeed it's possible a list possesses the iterator interface:

```
list_iter = list.__iter__() # or iter(list), returns list iterator
list_iter.__next__() # list_iter.next() for python 2.x
```

So,

```
lst_iter = iter(lst)
```

does the trick.

Though it makes more sense to use comprehensions and make a generator out of it: e.g.

```
lst_iter_gt_10 = (item for item in lst if item > 10)
```

Answer (score 4):

I'm not sure you mean, but what you typed is valid Python code:

```
>>> x = (i for i in range(10))
>>> x
<generator object at 0xb7f05f6c>
>>> for i in x: print i
0
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

Comment: The relevant link to the Python documentation is [here](http://docs.python.org/dev/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions): "A generator expression yields a new generator object. Its syntax is the same as for comprehensions, except that it is enclosed in parentheses instead of brackets or curly braces."

Answer (score 0):

next was key:

```py
next(iter([]), None)
```

where you can replace None with whatever default you want