# Ensure that an argument can be iterated twice

Tags: python

Suppose I have the following function:

```
def print_twice(x):
    for i in x: print(i)
    for i in x: print(i)
```

When I run:

```
print_twice([1,2,3])
```

or:

```
print_twice((1,2,3))
```

I get the expected result: the numbers 1,2,3 are printed twice.

But when I run:

```
print_twice(zip([1,2,3],[4,5,6]))
```

the pairs (1,4),(2,5),(3,6) are printed only once. Probably, this is because the `zip` returns a generator that terminates after one pass.

How can I modify the function `print_twice` such that it will correctly handle all inputs?

I could insert a line at the beginning of the function: `x = list(x)`. But this might be inefficient in case x is already a list, a tuple, a range, or any other iterator that can be iterated more than once. Is there a more efficient solution?

Comment: Does this look like it helps? https://stackoverflow.com/q/6416538/5763413

Comment: Hi erel, you could check if the Argument is of type`iterator` and if it is use `itertools.tee()`. Please have a look at [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1271320/resetting-generator-object-in-python)

Comment: @JonathanWeine is `iterator` the only thing that is exhausted? (i.e., if it is not an iterator, can I just iterate over it twice?)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why can't I iterate twice over the same data?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25336726/why-cant-i-iterate-twice-over-the-same-data) (use `iter` to ensure you can use `tee`, see also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5933966/is-it-possible-to-convert-a-list-type-into-a-generator-without-iterating-through).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I could insert a line at the beginning of the function: `x = list(x)`. But this might be inefficient in case x is already a list, a tuple, a range, or any other iterator that can be iterated more than once. Is there a more efficient solution?

Copying single-use iterables to a `list` is perfectly adequate, and reasonably efficient even for multi-use iterables.

The `list` (and to some extend `tuple`) type is one of the most optimised data structures in Python. Common operations such as copying a `list` or `tuple` to a `list` are internally optimised;<sup>1</sup> even for iterables that are not special-cased, copying them to a `list` is significantly faster than any realistic work done by two (or more) loops.

```py
def print_twice(x):
    x = list(x)
    for i in x: print(i)
    for i in x: print(i)
```

Copying indiscriminately can also be advantageous in the context of concurrency, when the iterable may be modified while the function is running. Common cases are threading and `weakref` collections.

---

In case one wants to avoid needless copies, checking whether the iterable is a [`Collection`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.abc.html#collections.abc.Collection) is a reasonable guard.

```py
from collections.abc import Collection

x = list(x) if not isinstance(x, Collection) else x
```

Alternatively, one can check whether the iterable is in fact an iterat*or*, since this implies statefulness and thus single-use.

```py
from collections.abc import Iterator

x = list(x) if isinstance(x, Iterator) else x
x = list(x) if iter(x) is x else x
```

Notably, the builtins `zip`, `filter`, `map`, ... and generators all are iterators.

---

<sup>1</sup>Copying a `list` of 128 items is roughly as fast as checking whether it is a `Collection`.

Comment: Regarding the first point: what if the list is very long (e.g. millions of items): is it still efficient to copy to another list?

Comment: @ErelSegal-Halevi In practice yes. Copying a list is a tight C-loop copying pointers and incrementing reference counts; the memory requirement is a precisely allocated pointer array. While both can still be a lot for millions of items, you have to weight that against your function *operating* on these millions of items anyway. Remember that you only need this if you are going to run over the entire list at least twice – adding a third run will in the *absolute worst case of doing absolutely nothing with the data* add 50% runtime.

Answer (score 8):

A simple test to see if `x` will be consumed when you iterate over it is `iter(x) is x`. This is reliable, since it's specified as part of the iterator protocol ([docs](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator)):

> Iterators are required to have an `__iter__()` method that returns the iterator object itself

Conversely, if `iter(x)` returns `x` itself then `x` must be an iterator, since it was returned by the `iter` function.

Some checks:

```py
def is_iterator(x):
    return iter(x) is x

for obj in [
    # not iterators
    [1, 2, 3],
    (1, 2, 3),
    {1: 2, 3: 4},
    range(3),
    # iterators
    (x for x in range(3)),
    iter([1, 2, 3]),
    zip([1, 2], [3, 4]),
    filter(lambda x: x % 2 == 0, [1, 2, 3]),
    map(lambda x: 2 * x, [1, 2, 3]),
]:
    name = type(obj).__name__
    if is_iterator(obj):
        print(name, 'is an iterator')
    else:
        print(name, 'is not an iterator')
```

Results:

```
list is not an iterator
tuple is not an iterator
dict is not an iterator
range is not an iterator
generator is an iterator
list_iterator is an iterator
zip is an iterator
filter is an iterator
map is an iterator
```

So, to ensure that `x` can be iterated multiple times, without making an unnecessary copy if it already can be, you can write something like:

```py
if iter(x) is x:
    x = list(x)
```

Comment: This explains how to test if something is an iterator, but how does it answer the question how to iterate twice over an iterator?

Comment: @mkrieger1 OP already knows that `x = list(x)` will ensure that `x` can be iterated over twice, as far as I can tell the question is how to only do that when necessary.

Comment: `x = itertools.repeat(None)` fulfills `iter(x) is x`, but I challenge you to exhaust it :-P

Comment: @KellyBundy Fair, but in response I challenge you to iterate over it twice :-p

Answer (score 1):

`zip` will return an iterator. Once unpacked, it cannot be unpacked again, it gets exhausted.

Maybe if you want to make sure that only `zip` objects get converted to `list` as you said it would work but it would not be efficient, you can check for it type:

```
if isinstance(x, zip):
  x = list(x)
```

Comment: It's better to use `isinstance(x, zip)` instead of `type(x) == zip`. See: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1549801/what-are-the-differences-between-type-and-isinstance

Comment: `zip` is only an example. What if it is a different thing that gets exhausted?

Comment: In this case maybe this post can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976269/how-can-i-get-generators-iterators-to-evaluate-as-false-when-exhausted but as I understand from it, it seems like you have to provide yourself the solution. So I guess, instead of checking most of the possible types and create a list when it is necessarry, you can simply create a list everytime. This will be useless if the object is already an iterator/list/etc but it's easier and at the end it doesn't add too much workload for the compiler.

Comment: @AlexandruDuDu It is not much workload for the compiler, but if the list is very long, it might be a lot of work for the computer.

Answer (score -4):

Modify your print_twice function

```
def print_twice(x):
    val = x
    for i in range(2):
        for i in val: print(i)
```

Comment: This doesn't give the same output.