# How can I create a 2-way table in python?

Tags: python

How can I create a 2-way table in python? I have 2 categorical variables in a data set and would like to look at the relationship between the 2 variables by creating a 2-way table. Thank you.

Comment: Possible Duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6129693/python-creating-a-table

Comment: Do you mean a bidirectional map?

Comment: Can you give us a sample data set?

Comment: will creating two dictionaries, each one the opposite of  the other, i.e. the key in one is the value in the other solve your problem?

Comment: I thought it was obvious what you wanted, but I was obviously wrong. Can you please elaborate on what you mean by "two-way table"? Do you mean a table where you look up a value by row and column, or a bidirectional mapping as brice suggested?

Comment: I'm voting to close as no-one can work out what the question means, and OP has refused to actually update the question, despite being repeatedly asked.

Comment: It's clear what's being asked here... This should not have been closed.  A two-way table is another name for a contingency table: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Contingency_table

Comment: as of pandas 0.17.0. you can use `pd.crosstab(df["column_1"], df["column_2"])`

Answer (score 6):

There's a [bidict package](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/bidict/0.1.1):

```
>>> from bidict import bidict
>>> husbands2wives = bidict({'john': 'jackie'})
>>> husbands2wives['john']  # the forward mapping is just like with dict
'jackie'
>>> husbands2wives[:'jackie']  # use slice for the inverse mapping
'john'
```

---

You can install it using *pip install bidict*.

---

**EDIT**: For your actual problem - if I understand you correctly - I would use [`pandas`](http://pandas.pydata.org/):

```
# data.csv
Gender Height GPA HS GPA Seat WtFeel Cheat 
Female 64 2.60 2.63 M AboutRt No 1 
Male 69 2.70 3.72 M AboutRt No 2 
Female 66 3.00 3.44 F AboutRt No 3 
Female 63 3.11 2.73 F AboutRt No 4 
Male 72 3.40 2.35 B OverWt No 0
```

---

```
In [1]: import pandas as pd

In [2]: df = pd.read_csv('data.csv', sep = '\s')

In [3]: grouped = df.groupby(['Gender', 'Seat'])

In [4]: grouped.size()
Out[4]: 
Gender  Seat   
Female  AboutRt    3
Male    AboutRt    1
        OverWt     1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: The 2 columns are Gender (M, F) and Body Figure (AboutRt, OverWt, UnderWt). All I want to do is count how many males are AboutRt, Overwt and underWt, and do the same for the females. I was hoping that there is a package in python similar to the gmodels library in R where you could create a cross table which is found in R. Thanks again.

Comment: @TarekDeeb -- please edit your question populating it with a small sample of your data...

Comment: @TarekDeeb -- You should probably take a look at `pandas`. Added an example...

Comment: data.head()
   Gender  Height   GPA  HS GPA Seat   WtFeel Cheat
  0  Female      64  2.60    2.63    M  AboutRt    No
  1    Male      69  2.70    3.72    M  AboutRt    No
  2  Female      66  3.00    3.44    F  AboutRt    No
  3  Female      63  3.11    2.73    F  AboutRt    No
  4    Male      72  3.40    2.35    B   OverWt    No

Comment: @TarekDeeb -- Please, update your question, with well formatted data - don't paste it in the comments. This makes it much easier for both the people who answer your questions and for further readers, who may have a similar problem.

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to use a `DoubleDict` as shown in [recipe 578224](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578224/) on the [Python Cookbook](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/langs/python/).

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you don't have to do any interpolation, you can use a dictionary. Use `(x, y)` tuples as the keys, and whatever your values are as the values. For instance, a trivial 2x2 table like this:

```
   ___0___1___
0 |   0   0.5
1 |   0.5 1
```

Would look like this in code:

```
two_way_lookup = {
                  (0, 0) : 0,
                  (0, 1) : 0.5,
                  (1, 0) : 0.5,
                  (1, 1) : 1
                 }
print(two_way_lookup.get((0, 1))) # prints 0.5
```

Comment: This doesn't look like it actually responds to the question.

Comment: Dicts provide only one way lookup, OP asked for 2-way table.

Comment: @Marcin (& Ashwini) I understand "2-way table" to mean "table where you look up `x` and `y` to get a value representing something about that combination of elements." It is not, at least in my mind, the same thing as 2-way lookup, where key/value pairs can be used in either direction.

Comment: "would like to look at the relationship between the 2 variables by creating a 2-way table. Thank you." Suggests that OP wants two-way lookup.

Comment: @Marcin That's exactly the line that I think supports my interpretation. The asker presumably has two keys already, and wants to look up the relationship between them.

Answer (score 0):

Probably the best solution in the standard library, if your data is moderately large, is to use `sqlite`, the in-memory database: http://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html

Answer (score 0):

You can create something like a two-level dict (that is, a dict which comprehends two dicts that map the same data in reverse order:

```
>>> mappings=[(0, 6), (1, 7), (2, 8), (3, 9), (4, 10)]
>>> view = dict(view1=dict(mappings), view2=dict(reversed(k) for k in mappings))
>>> view
{'view2': {8: 2, 9: 3, 10: 4, 6: 0, 7: 1},
'view1': {0: 6, 1: 7, 2: 8, 3: 9, 4: 10}}
```

Comment: This works well for a one-to-one function, but gets a bit tricky when you don't assume this condition. Ex: x = 4, y = (-2, 2).

Answer (score 0):

If you want a home-brewed, wonky solution, you could do something like this:

```
import collections

class BDMap:
    def __init__(self):
        self.x_table = {}
        self.y_table = {}

    def get(self, x = None, y = None):
        if (x != None) and (y != None):
            y_vals = self.x_table[x]
            if (y in y_vals):
                return (x, y)
        elif x != None:
            return self.x_table[x]
        elif y != None:
            return self.y_table[y]

    def set(self, x, y):
        if isinstance(x, collections.Hashable) and isinstance(y, collections.Hashable):
            self.x_table[x] = self.x_table.get(x, list()) + [y]
            self.y_table[y] = self.y_table.get(y, list()) + [x]
        else:
            raise TypeError("unhashable type")
```

For anything other than a one-off script with a small data set, you're undoubtedly better off with one of approaches mentioned, though :)