# Shuffling a list

Tags: python, list, swap

in this program I'm trying to shuffle a list by randomly choosing two items from a list and swapping them round, and then repeating this process several times.

The problem I have encountered is I don't know how I can swap the items round and print the shuffled list.

For instance if my two random values were a and b, if I were to just put:

```
a = b
b = a
```

then that would change the value of a to b, but when it tries to change b to a, no change would occur as a has already been changed to b.

The only way I can think that this would work is swapping them at the same time, but I do not know of a function/ way to swap them round.

Also if a, b were items of a list L, after I swapped them round if I used

```
print L
```

should it print the altered version? I only ask because from what I have tried it is not doing that.

NB I am trying to shuffle this list stage by stage by swapping, instead of using the shuffle function imported from random.

Comment: The classic way of swapping back when I were a lad, was to use a temporary variable: tmp=a, a=b, b=tmp - but python is smarter than BASIC was then! [too lame to deserve to be an answer]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use a temp variable for your first problem:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

In Python you can also do this:

```
a, b = b, a
```

I suspect your second problem is because you're changing things you got out of the list, instead of changing the list. Try this:

```
i, j = # two indexes to swap in the list
L[i], L[j] = L[j], L[i]
```

Answer (score 4):

In Python, you can swap two variables like this:

```
a, b = b, a
```

This is called multiple assignment, you can find more information about it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/102037#102037).

In other languages this is usually done by assigning a temporary variable:

```
tmp = a
a = b
b = tmp
```

Isn't Python great?

Answer (score 4):

The *random.shuffle* function uses swapping too.  It would be worthwhile to look at its [source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/random.py#l276):

```
def shuffle(self, x, random=None, int=int):
    """x, random=random.random -> shuffle list x in place; return None.

    Optional arg random is a 0-argument function returning a random
    float in [0.0, 1.0); by default, the standard random.random.
    """

    if random is None:
        random = self.random
    for i in reversed(xrange(1, len(x))):
        # pick an element in x[:i+1] with which to exchange x[i]
        j = int(random() * (i+1))
        x[i], x[j] = x[j], x[i]
```

Observe how the last line performs a swap using [tuple packing and unpacking](http://docs.python.org/tutorial/datastructures.html#tuples-and-sequences).

As an alternative to packing and unpacking, the traditional way to swap variables is to use a temporary variable:

```
t    = x[i]
x[i] = x[j]
x[j] = t
```

Answer (score 1):

Use a temporary variable:

```
temp = a
a = b
b = temp
```

Answer (score 0):

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Just swapping items is known to be bad.

Don't forget that if you have n items, there are n! arrangements. If your random number is 32 bits, there are 2^32 numbers.

It's hard then to shuffle a pack of cards with a 32 bit number as 52! is very much bigger than 2^32