# Python turning a list into a list of tuples

Tags: python, list

What I want to accomplish:

```
[a, b, c, d] -> [ (a, x), (b, x), (c, x), (d, x) ]
```

What I have thought of so far:

```
done = []

for i in [a, b, c, d]:
   done.append((i, x))
```

Is there a more Pythonic way of accomplishing this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
done = [(el, x) for el in [a, b, c, d]]
```

Answer (score 8):

Using `itertools.repeat`

```
>>> x = 'apple'
>>> a,b,c,d = 'a','b','c','d'
>>> from itertools import repeat    
>>> zip([a,b,c,d],repeat(x))
[('a', 'apple'), ('b', 'apple'), ('c', 'apple'), ('d', 'apple')]
```

Using `itertools.product`

```
>>> from itertools import product
>>> list(product([a,b,c,d],[x]))
[('a', 'apple'), ('b', 'apple'), ('c', 'apple'), ('d', 'apple')]
```

Comment: Interesting approach. I thought of using zip() with [x]*len([a, b, c, d]), but I didn't know about itertools.

Comment: >>> x = 'apple'
>>> y = [a,b,c,d]
>>> zip(y,[x]*len(y))

That also works, i was thinking of quick ways of doing it using the array directly without saving it to a varible.

Comment: I just read [this blog post about `repeat`](http://rhodesmill.org/brandon/2012/counting-without-counting/), it's very fast. I would guess one or both of these is faster than the other methods. The second one is very clever.

Comment: Maybe they are faster in other situations but I don't think these are any faster in this case. Not much can be done to speed up this process since it is so simple the list comprehension does the bare minimum i believe.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/101310/880248

This trick is relevant to not saving the values directly by instead saving a generator.

Answer (score 6):

Another way to accomplish the same result: list comprehensions

```
done = [(i,x) for i in [a,b,c,d]]
```