# Simplifying a list comprehension

Tags: python

How would I write the following more concisely?

```
    genres = ','.join([item for item in list((sheet.cell(n,18).value, 
                      sheet.cell(n,19).value, sheet.cell(n,20).value)) if item])
```

Comment: Btw, the `list()` call is useless, since you can use a generator expression. See @Julian answer.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
','.join(filter(None, (sheet.cell(n, i).value for i in (18, 19, 20))))
```

The `(sheet.cell(n, i).value for i in (18, 19, 20))` is a [generator expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python/101310#101310) replacing the `list(…)` part. You may replace the tuple `(18, 19, 20)` with a range or something else.

The `filter(None, iterable)` [is equivalent to](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#filter) `(x for x in iterable if x)`. (In Python 2.x you may want to use [itertools.ifilter](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) instead.)

---

Note also that, you can create a list using

```
[sheet.cell(n,18).value, sheet.cell(n,19).value, sheet.cell(n,20).value]
```

instead of the longer `list((sheet.cell(n,18).value, …))`.

Comment: Wouldn't [`itertools.ifilter`](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.ifilter) be more accurate equivalent of the generator expression? (in Python 2.x)

Comment: @Imran: Right. And in Python 3 `filter` is enough.

Answer (score 5):

On two lines. Readability trumps conciseness.

Your list comprehension is also unnecessary, a genexp will do fine.

```
genre_values = (sheet.cell(n, i).value for i in xrange(18, 21))
genres = ", ".join(value for value in genre_cells if value)
```

Comment: Don't you need a `.value` somewhere?