# How can i for loop in parallel in python

Tags: python, loops

I have two lists

```
l1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,66,]
```

I want to display them on same lines

```
"list1 text"  "list2 text"

l1-1   , l2-1
l1-2   , l2-2
```

and so on

so that if list elements finish then it should display blank `""` in front of it but other side shows its own elements like

```
for a,b in l1,l2
     <td>a</td><td> b </td>
```

Comment: http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip

Comment: BTW this is not called "looping in parallel". that word refers mainly to parallel computations.

Answer (score 4):

You can use [`izip_longest`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) with a `fillvalue` of whitespace,

```
>>> from itertools import izip_longest
>>> for a,b in izip_longest(l1,l2,fillvalue=' '):
...     print a,b
... 
1 1
2 2
3 3
4 4
5 5
6 6
7 7
  8
  9
  77
  66
```

Comment: I don't really know how is that possible. You have to show us your code.

Answer (score 3):

Something like this?

```
from itertools import izip_longest
l1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,66,]

for a,b in izip_longest(l1,l2, fillvalue=''):
    print '"'+str(a)+'"','"'+str(b)+'"'
```

Out:

```
"1" "1"
"2" "2"
"3" "3"
"4" "4"
"5" "5"
"6" "6"
"7" "7"
"" "8"
"" "9"
"" "77"
"" "66"
```

Answer (score 1):

[Itertools.izip_longest](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.izip_longest) can be used to combine the two lists, the value None will be used as a placeholder value for "missing" items in the shorter list.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>>l1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,66,]
>>>n = ((a,b) for a in l1 for b in l2)
>>>for i in n:
       i
```

for more details please go through this link:
    [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python)

Comment: This is nesting the two loops, which doesn't seem to be what is asked for. Incidentally, you can use `for i in itertools.product(l1, l2):` to do the same thing

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> l1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
>>> l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,66,]
>>> def render_items(*args):
...     return ''.join('<td>{}</td>'.format('' if i is None else i) for i in args)
... 
>>> for item in map(render_items, l1, l2):
...     print item
... 
<td>1</td><td>1</td>
<td>2</td><td>2</td>
<td>3</td><td>3</td>
<td>4</td><td>4</td>
<td>5</td><td>5</td>
<td>6</td><td>6</td>
<td>7</td><td>7</td>
<td></td><td>8</td>
<td></td><td>9</td>
<td></td><td>77</td>
<td></td><td>66</td>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,66]
maxlen = max(len(l1),len(l2))
l1_ext = l1 + (maxlen-len(l1))*[' ']
l2_ext = l2 + (maxlen-len(l2))*[' ']
for (a,b) in zip(l1_ext,l2_ext):
    print a,b
```

Answer (score 1):

```
l1= [1,2,3,4,5,6,7]
l2 = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,77,66]
for (a,b) in map(lambda a,b:(a or ' ',b or ' '), l1, l2):
    print a,b
```