# Sort a list of tuples with two tuple entries in opposite order

Tags: python

Hopefully this will make sense...

I have a list of tuples of the following form:

```
list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
```

The desired output is

```
sorted_list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 3)]
```

The issue is I want the second entry to be increasing, and the first entry to be decreasing.

```
import operator as op     
sorted_list_of_tuples = sorted(list_of_tuples, key=op.itemgetter(2, 0))
```

This, of course, sorts both fields to be increasing. I can't come up with a cute (i.e., couple of lines) way to do this. Does anyone have a way to accomplish this kind of sorting easily?

I seem to remember that you can reference elements of a list comprehension inside the brackets using `_`, so maybe that's a place to start?

---

Maybe I wasn't clear: the integer in this case is more important. It's order should be increasing across the list. When there's a tie (ie.., the second entry is equal), I want 'b' to occur before 'a'.

Comment: *I seem to remember that you can reference elements of a list comprehension inside the brackets using _, so maybe that's a place to start?* - I'm not sure what you are referring to, but `_` is nothing special in Python, just a variable name.

Comment: @Lattyware: I understand. What I recalled reading was in this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python See the entry titled "Referencing a list comprehension as it is being built..."

Comment: As noted there, that's an obscure implementation detail, and not something to be used in general. It's also not really relevant here.

Comment: @BenDundee: That's an undocumented implementation artifact of older versions of CPython. I'm pretty sure it doesn't even work in 2.7 or 3.x. EDIT: Verified that it does not work in CPython 2.7, 3.2, or 3.3, or PyPy 1.9 or 2.0. It does work in CPython 2.5 and 2.6.

Comment: @abarnert In sincerely doubt it would in 3.x, as list comps are now just syntactic sugar for `list()` wrapping a generator expression.

Comment: @Lattyware: Sure, but as I said, it's _also_ broken in 2.7 (and PyPy), where list comps are still semantically unchanged.

Comment: @abarnert Oh, I imagined so, I was just backing up the statement.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can describe the key in English, just translate that to a function.

> I want the second entry to be increasing, and the first entry to be decreasing.

So, the key is:

```
def make_key(my_tuple):
    return my_tuple[1], -my_tuple[0]
```

Except, of course, that `-` doesn't work that way on strings, so you need something fancier.

Or, maybe not… while the first element of each tuple is a string, the second is an integer, so, we can just negate the key function, and use `reverse` to un-negate it:

```
def make_key(my_tuple):
    return -my_tuple[1], my_tuple[0]

sorted_list_of_tuples = sorted(list_of_tuples, key=make_key, reverse=True)
```

---

If you want to save a few keystrokes:

```
sorted_list_of_tuples = sorted(list_of_tuples,
                               key=lambda x: (x[1], x[0]), reverse=True)
```

---

This isn't the only trick that would work here. For example, because all of your strings are 1-character strings, `ord(x) < ord(y)` iff `x < y`.

But sometimes you can't think of an easy trick—but you *can* think of an easy way to write a comparison function. If it's more readable, do it that way:

```
def compare_my_tuples(lhs, rhs):        
    if rhs[1] > lhs[0]: return 1
    elif rhs[1] < lhs[0]: return -1
    elif rhs[0] > lhs[0]: return -1
    elif rhs[0] < rhs[0]: return 1
    else: return 0

sorted_list_of_tuples = sorted(list_of_tuples, 
                               key=functools.cmp_to_key(compare_my_tuples))
```

---

Or, of course, you can split it into two sorts, as in steveha's answer. (Yes, it might take twice as long… but in most apps, that won't make any difference at all.)

Answer (score 2):

Sure.  Python's built-in sort is a "stable" sort.  So, pick which sort you want to be more important, and do that one *second*.  Do the less-important sort, then sort again by the more-important criteria.

Working code:

```
import operator as op

list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]

list_of_tuples.sort(key=op.itemgetter(0), reverse=True)
list_of_tuples.sort(key=op.itemgetter(1))

assert list_of_tuples == [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 3)]
```

I guess you can do the whole thing in one pass if you come up with a clever key function.  Maybe this:

```
def custom_key_fn(tup):
    ch, n = tup # unpack tuple
    return (n, -ord(ch))

list_of_tuples = [('a', 1), ('b', 3), ('b', 2), ('a', 3)]
list_of_tuples.sort(key=custom_key_fn)

assert list_of_tuples == [('a', 1), ('b', 2), ('b', 3), ('a', 3)]
```

Comment: You can't do it with a single sort?

Comment: @BenDundee: Sure you can, it just takes a more complex key function. It's a tradeoff.

Comment: +1 Using a 2-pass sort is much cleaner and easier to understand, it should scale pretty well with Timsort anyway.  Avoid the temptation to be clever unless it's performance critical code.