# Python class variable int vs array

Tags: python, class

I was playing around with Python classes and arrived at the following example in which two variables which appear to be static class variables have different behavior when modified.

What's going on here? My first instinct is that something tricky is going on with references.

```
class Foo:
    a = []
    n = 0
    def bar(self):
            self.a.append('foo')
            self.n += 1

x = Foo()
print x.a, x.n    ([] 0)
x.bar()
print x.a, x.n    (['foo', 1])
y = Foo()
print y.a, y.n    (['foo', 0])
y.bar()
print y.a, y.n    (['foo', 'foo'], 1)
```

Comment: here's a similar case to look out for in python http://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113198

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are correct - in the case of `Foo.a` accessing `self.a` actually accesses `Foo.a`, which is shared between all instances of `Foo`.  However, when you update `self.n` with `+=` you actually create an instance-level variable on `self` that shadows `Foo.n`:

```
>>> import dis
>>> dis.dis(Foo.bar)
  5           0 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
              3 LOAD_ATTR                0 (a)
              6 LOAD_ATTR                1 (append)
              9 LOAD_CONST               1 ('foo')
             12 CALL_FUNCTION            1
             15 POP_TOP             

  6          16 LOAD_FAST                0 (self)
             19 DUP_TOP             
             20 LOAD_ATTR                2 (n)
             23 LOAD_CONST               2 (1)
             26 INPLACE_ADD         
             27 ROT_TWO             
             28 STORE_ATTR               2 (n)
             31 LOAD_CONST               0 (None)
             34 RETURN_VALUE
```

In other words, when you do `self.a.append('some value')` the interpreter fetches `a` from memory via a name on `Foo` and then mutates the list that `Foo.a` points to.

On the other hand, when you do `self.n += 1` the interpreter:

- Fetches `n` from `Foo` (because it can't find `n` on `self`)
- Creates a new value `n + 1`
- Stores the new value in the attribute `n` on `self`

Comment: Gotcha. The assignment which causes the shadow was (for me) obfuscated behind the `+=`. Thanks!