# python: lambda, yield-statement/expression and loops (Clarify)

Tags: python, python-3.x, loops, lambda, generator

Can we implement `yield` or generator statement (with a loop) within a `lambda`?

My question is to clarify:

Whether the following simple loop function can be implemented with yield

```
def loopyield():
   for x in range(0,15):
      yield x
print(*loopyield())
```

Results in error:

```
lamyield=lambda x: yield x for x in range(0,15)
                       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Which looks like, it was expecting something as right operand for unwritten return statement but found the `yield` and getting confused.

Is there a proper legit way to achieve this in a loop?

Side note: `yield` can be statement/expression depending on who you ask: [yield - statement or expression?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20142450/yield-statement-or-expression)

**Final Answer :** yield can be used with lambda but the limitation(single-line) makes it useless.  `for/while` not possible in lambda because they are not expressions.  *-user2357112* implicit for loop is possible with list comprehension, and yield is valid within the list comprehension. -*wim*

**Verdict-** Explicit loops not possible because lambdas in python can only contain expressions, and to write an explicit loop you will need to use statements. *-wim*

Comment: "but you can also use a statement like `print()` as long as it is contained in a single line" - wrong! `print` is a function in Python 3, and `print` calls are ordinary expressions. You cannot use arbitrary single-line statements inside a `yield` call.

Comment: Trying to write this with a `lambda` is pointless. If you want to stuff it onto a single line, `(x for x in range(0, 15))` would be a direct genexp translation of your generator function.

Comment: I agree. I was trying to test a theory. On second thought, with the limitation of `lambda` having to fit into a single statement, I doubt I can achieve anything at all to have a loop within a `lambda`. But it will be good to finally clarify this because it has been bugging me.

Comment: So, no loop/or `yield` statement within a `lambda` ? Can we stay that for sure now?

Comment: Also, another thing that comes to mind, adding a yield statement to a fn makes it a generator obj. But looks like lambda creates/makes a regular function obj. (Please clarify if it can't be generator obj)

Comment: @MosesKoledoye: `yield` is an expression now..

Comment: While you can technically put a `yield` in a lambda function, the constraints of lambda functions make it essentially never a useful thing to do.

Comment: You'd have to parenthesise `(yield x)`. But the whole `for` loop syntax is not a valid expression anyway.

Answer (score 50, accepted):

The one-liner you seem to be trying to create is actually technically possible with a lambda, you just need to help the parser a bit more:

```
>>> lamyield = lambda: [(yield x) for x in range(15)]
>>> print(*lamyield())
0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14
```

This uses a for loop implicitly in a list comprehension.  It is not possible with an explicit `while` loop or `for` loop outside of a comprehension.  That's because lambdas in Python can only contain [expressions](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html), and to write an explicit loop you will need to use [statements](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/compound_stmts.html).

[**Note:  this syntax is deprecated in Python 3.7, and will raise `SyntaxError` in Python 3.8**](https://docs.python.org/3.7/whatsnew/3.7.html#deprecated-python-behavior)

Comment: Yeah. Like someone pointed out, it is basically a generator obj. Do you know if it can be done with `for`/`while`. Also, you can't really do anything with lambda one-line.

Comment: Note that the results are completely different on Python 2. This code depends in a really subtle way on the fact that on Python 3, the list comprehension is implemented with *another* anonymous function inside the anonymous function created by `lambda`.

Comment: Wow, what is going on here? Could you explain what `[(yield x) for x in range(15)]` does? What does the expression return?

Comment: It returns a generator object.  When you iterate the generator you will get the values yielded during the iteration of the  comprehension.  When the iteration is complete, the `StopIteration` exception instance will have a `value` attribute.  This will be the list comprehension result: it will be a list of length 15, and the elements of this list will be the items which were *sent* into the generator.

Comment: you can also do something like this-- which lazily evaluates each function, and will NOT be deprecated in 3.8: `lamyield = lambda: ((yield expensive_func1()), (yield expensive_func2()), (yield expensive_func3()))`

Comment: An alternative would be `lambda: (x for x in range(15))`

Answer (score 19):

Is it any necessity for using `yield` inside of `lambda` if you can rewrite it with generator such that?

```
In[1]: x = (i for i in range(15))
In[2]: x
Out[2]: <generator object <genexpr> at 0x7fbdc69c3f10>

In[3]: print(*x)
Out[3]: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 11 12 13 14

In[4]: x = (i for i in range(0, 15))
In[5]: x.__next__()
Out[5]: 0

In[6]: next(x)
Out[6]: 1
```

Answer (score 6):

You actually can loop through a lambda in useful ways, it's just that the example you provided isn't a great use case.

One instance where you might want to use `yield` inside a `lambda` might be to lazily execute expensive functions only when needed. Like so:

```py
def expensive_check1():
    print("expensive_check1")
    return True


def expensive_check2():
    print("expensive_check2")
    return True


def expensive_check3():
    print("expensive_check3")
    return True


def do_the_thing(*args):
    print(args)


if __name__=="__main__":
    for check, args in (lambda: (
                                (yield (expensive_check1(), ["foo", "bar"])), 
                                (yield (expensive_check2(), ["baz"])),
                                (yield (expensive_check3(), [])),
                        ))():
        if check:
            do_the_thing(*args)
            continue
        raise Exception("oh noes!!!")
    else:
        print("all OK!")
```

Output:

```
expensive_check1
('foo', 'bar')
expensive_check2
('baz',)
expensive_check3
()
all OK!
```

Note that the expensive checks only happen at the start of each loop, rather than all at once. Also note that this syntax will still work in Python 3.8+, since it is not using the `yield` inside of a comprehension.

Comment: interesting, I don't really think lambda is the most readable solution here though

Answer (score 3):

I have a simpler solution

```py
lmbdgen = lambda: (x for x in range(15))
lmbdgen
Out[40]: <function __main__.<lambda>()>
lmbdgen()
Out[41]: <generator object <lambda>.<locals>.<genexpr> at 0x00000171473D8D60>
list(lmbdgen())
Out[42]: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14]
```

This creates a function that returns a generator. This is a simpler way to access a generator multiple times.

For an alternative version

```py
def defgen_return():
    return (x for x in range(10000))

def defgen_yield():
    for x in range(10000):
        yield x
```

Here is the performance difference

```py
%timeit list(defgen_return())
613 µs ± 9.13 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit list(defgen_yield())
572 µs ± 20.5 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)

%timeit list(lmbdgen())
581 µs ± 22.9 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000 loops each)
```