# A function generates infinite nested lists

Tags: python-2.7, nested-lists

I was doing some experiments following this feature: [Hidden features of Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/101268/hidden-features-of-python#113198)

The used code is:

```
def f(x = []):
    x.append(x)
    return x
```

which output is:

```
>>> f()
[[...]]
```

I would like to understand what do `[...]` mean and why it an infinite nested list is produced.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to understand that function defaults are evaluated when the function is first created not when it is run. So to start with, your code is equivalent to this:

```
X = []
def f(x=X):
    x.append(x)
    return x
```

If you run it just once, then this is equivalent to this:

```
X = []
X.append(X)
```

Which is creating a list and then setting itself as the first element. So since `X == X[0]` then it follows that `X == X[0][0]` and `X == X[0][0]...[0]`.

Answer (score 1):

Appending a list to itself would make a loop structure, the `[...]` means repeating itself infinitely.